# Qual é a diferença entre C# e ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp

Qual a grande diferença sobre o ASP.Net e o C#? Eu programo em C# pra desktop, mas não consigo compreender.

C# pra desktop (Windows Forms Application) é idêntico ao C# utilizado na programação web? E o C# usado na programação web é igual ao ASP?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

O C# que você usa é sempre o mesmo, tanto pra desktop quanto pra web (Asp.Net).

O Asp.Net é a tecnologia da Microsoft que você usa para fazer a parte server-side de aplicações web.

Não confunda isso com o ASP (ASP clássico): Essa é uma tecnologia antiga e obsoleta da Microsoft que usava VBScript (ou Javascript) como linguagem, antes de existir o Framework .NET.

Comment: Como pode ser o mesmo C# no desktop e web? Por acaso no Web eu posso adicionar label, panel, textbox como na versão desktop? Existe formulários? Não consigo compreender...

Comment: @Lizard Não exatamente. O Asp.Net possui o Framework Web Forms que te permite trabalhar de forma semelhante ao Windows Forms (que te dá a ilusão de poder adicionar controles Label, Button, TextBox, etc.). O que eu quero dizer com "É sempre o mesmo C#" é porque a linguagem é a mesma, mas muda a biblioteca. Para desktop, por exemplo, você usa a biblioteca System.Windows.Forms, enquanto para o Asp.Net Web Forms, vocÊ usa a biblioteca System.Web.UI.

Comment: Acho que entendi, só abra minha mente... Se é web, funciona com o HTML, correto? Por fim, eu adicionando uma textbox, que efeito tem essa textbox (nesse web forms que você comentou) no código html?

Comment: A TextBox do Web Forms é uma "abstração". Ou seja, é um tipo de "ilusão". Pro C#, é uma TextBox. Como o Asp.Net sabe que o Html não sabe o que é uma TextBox, o Asp.Net transforma todas as suas TextBox em `<input type="text" />` na hora de "renderizar" a página pro cliente.

Comment: Compreendi, ele também faz isso a respeito de posicionamento e com todos os outros controles do C#?

Comment: O Web Forms não tem TODOS os controles do Windows Forms, mas tem a maioria, que se comportam de forma semelhante. A intenção do Web Forms é deixar o desenvolvimento web o mais próximo possível do desenvolvimento desktop com o Windows Forms. Ainda assim, ele não te impede de usar HTML puro, Javascript e CSS, então, quando ele não suprir alguma necessidade sua de posicionamento ou estilo, você pode ajustar como quiser.

Comment: Como nota, devo dizer que o nível de abstração apresentado pelo Web Forms é **prejudicial**. O fato é que a Microsoft tentou enfeitar tanto esse Framework que ele acabou se tornando pesado (por razões de ViewState, PostBack e afins). E como experiência própria, eu digo que fazer algo que o Web Forms não provê de princípio pode se tornar uma grande dor. Eu recomendo que, se te interessa fazer desenvolvimento Web com C#, use o Framework MVC, também oficial da Microsoft e com desenvolvimento mais ativo de um tempo pra cá.

Answer (score 21):

`ASP.NET` é uma coisa e `C#` é outra.

ASP.NET é um framework web da Microsoft, criado com o intuito de permitir aos desenvolvedores criarem páginas web de forma mais rápida e dinâmica.

O C# é uma linguagem de programação, também desenvolvida pela Microsoft, o qual pode ser utilizada para diversas finalidades, desde jogos e aplicações desktop, até como escrever aplicações para o ASP.NET.

Vale ressaltar que ASP.NET também aceita `Visual Basic` como linguagem para script de aplicações.

Esse [artigo da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asp.net) explana um pouco mais (e de forma mais concisa) o que eu escrevi nessa resposta.

Answer (score 16):

C# é uma **linguagem** (+compilador).

Ela define a sintaxe da linguagem (`for/foreach` loops, `switch`, declaração de classes, *generics*, etc.) e define alguns tipos nativos (`int`, `string`, etc).

.NET é uma **framework** e um **runtime** (para C# e VB.NET), um conjunto de classes que ajuda no desenvolvimento de qualquer aplicação: `List<T>`, Linq *extensions*, etc, geralmente debaixo do namespace `System.*`. Existem algumas versões diferentes de .NET especializadas para algumas plataformas: .NET for XNA, .NET for Windows Phone, .NET for Windows Store apps.

WinForms, ASP.NET, WinRT, WPF, WCF e tudo mais, sao outras **frameworks**. Cada uma ajuda no desenvolvimento de aplicações de uma área específica. WPF adiciona classes tipo `Label`, `TextBox`, etc - enquanto que ASP.NET adiciona `HttpContext`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 13):

[C#](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp) é a [linguagem de programação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Como é JavaScript, Java, C, PHP, etc. Ela é que permite escrever códigos que serão, de uma forma ou de outra, executados pelo computador. Existe uma sintaxe e semântica específicas definidas em especificação e implementadas em um compilador.

Esta linguagem foi criada para ser usada em cima de uma plataforma específica chamada [CLR](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime), que é uma máquina virtual. É um software que simula um computador e possui regras próprias de funcionamento. Com ela é possível controlar melhor o que os softwares que rodam em cima dela fazem. Fica mais fácil portar o código para plataformas físicas reais (outros processadores e arquiteturas de computadores). Com a CLR é mais fácil produzir código confiável e flexível e é possível dar mais segurança. As linguagens que rodam em cima da CLR compilam para uma linguagem montadora comum chamada [CIL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

A CLR normalmente roda em um [*framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) chamado [.NET](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_.NET), criado pela Microsoft. Mas pode rodar em outros compatíveis, como o [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), por exemplo. Hoje existem [diversas versões do .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101), cada uma com sua peculiaridade para melhor atender as necessidades do desenvolvedor e usuário da aplicação final (mas está [tudo sendo unificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101) em uma coisa só). Além do *runtime* que controla a máquina virtual, o coletor de lixo e outras funções da plataforma, existem as bibliotecas e *subframeworks* onde se encontra os diversos algoritmos e estruturas de dados usados pelo C#. Alguns destes *frameworks* internos ou acessórios ao .NET são bastante complexos e apesar de executar tarefas específicas, são bem grandes.

Este [*framework* não pode ser confundido com a linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58080/101). É claro que o C# foi usado para escrever a maior parte dele e ele é necessário para a linguagem funcionar, mas são coisas distintas, apesar da sua interdependência.

Sabendo o que é um *framework* fica mais fácil entender o que é o [ASP.NET](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET). Ele é um conjunto de códigos que executam uma tarefa específica de forma integrada. Ele é responsável por manipular páginas para web no .NET. Existem as variações ASP.NET clássico (ou WebForms) e o [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) que é mais moderno e preferido atualmente pela maioria dos desenvolvedores.

Outros *frameworks* são usados para outras tarefas, inclusive para o acesso ao *desktop* existem concorrentes dentro do próprio .NET, como o [WinForms](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), [WPF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) e [WinRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime), cada um com sua característica própria.

Vimos que o ASP.NET é apenas uma tecnologia usada no ecossistema da plataforma comumente chamada de .NET. Ela não pode ser confundida como uma linguagem de programação, como muitos o fazem. Ela não possui sintaxe própria. Apesar que tanto o ASP.NET clássico, como o ASP.NET MVC possuem *engines* de renderização de páginas que possuem uma sintaxe de marcação e inclusão de código, como o [Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine).

O ASP é uma tecnologia para criação de páginas web criado anates de existir o .NET. Ele não deveria ser mais usado por uma ´serie de razões, mas principalmente porque ele não possui suporte completo pelo fornecedor, a Microsoft.

Muitas vezes é chamado de ASP clássico para não confundir com ASP.NET, já que a confusão é comum.

Entre as muitas limitações:

- o ASP se utiliza do [Visual Basic](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) antigo em *scripts* não compilados, pré-[VB.NET](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) e não permite outra linguagem, como no .NET que permite, em tese, qualquer linguagem suportada na CLR
- diversas melhorias na manipulação de erros, eventos e outras técnicas de programação, como cache, não estão disponíveis
- a quantidade de bibliotecas disponíveis é bem mais limitada e as que existem não possuem a mesma qualidade
- metodologia de desenvolvimento considerada obsoleta e de difícil manutenção
- há problemas conceituais, de manipulação de memória e controle de sessões

Aconselho fortemente acompanhar todos os *links* acima e se possível ver as páginas em inglês da Wikipedia que são melhores. De lá continue seguindo os *links* mais relevantes. Tem muita coisa pra aprender.

Tudo se torna meio obsoleto. Estamos falando de tecnologias ultrapassadas, tem um *link* acima que mostra o caminho moderno do que deve seguir agora.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111209/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: o termo ASP.Net clássico o quer seria? WebForm? ASP Classic 3.0 ? Achei q essa parte ficou um pouco confuso.

Comment: Pode-se dizer que é o WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET é, resumidamente, um front-end para plataforma Web, da mesma forma que Windows Forms ou WPF também é uma plataforma front-end para plataforma desktop.

A linguagem usada no ASP.NET é apenas para design, enquanto pode ser usado VB.NET ou C# como code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net ou Active Server Pages .Net é a nova versão do ASP que atende o Microsoft Framework.
entretanto é possivel programar em vb.net juntamente ao asp.net. Não só C#.

C# é uma linguagem de programação desenhada para "rodar" sob o .net framework. O Framework também te possibilita escrever códigos VB.Net e F#, algumas versões mais antigas tinham até J# .

ASP Net veio para substituir o obsoleto ASP e surgiu junto com a nova proposta da Microsoft na época que era o .Net framework

Comment: No Asp net você também poderá adicionar label, textboxes e tudo mais, a unica diferença é que isso rodará na WEB, (a grosso modo) mas existe a mesma facilidade de se desenvolver Desktop... com algumas particularidades; Existe um conceito por trás mas isso você ir além, pesquisando e estudando sobre a área de desenvolvimento WEB

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET é uma linguagem de "molde" (template) que permite escrever uma pagina HTML com diretivas de substituição que serão pós-processadas gerando um programa C# ou VB.NET dependendo de como for configurado. Você poderia obter o mesmo resultado puramente escrevendo em C# ou VB.NET e usando as diretivas para emitir HTML mas ASP.NET torna esse processo mais fácil porque proporciona este processador (do qual você pode facilmente obter o arquivo .cs ou .vb quand executa o site).

C# é uma das linguagens de programação suportadas pelo .Net framework, somente isso.

Answer (score 1):

C#      => Linguagem de Programação.

ASP ~>  => Tecnologia.

ASP.Net => Tecnologia utilizando a Framework .Net.

.Net    => Framework.

Comment: Tecnologia de que? Falta detalhes