# Como utilizar o Materialize com o Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, framework, front-end, materialize

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto, mas mesmo importando todos os CDN, do angular e do materialize, o JavaScript do materialize não quer funcionar junto com o angular, exite algum tipo de conflito ?

Importação dos arquivos:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/an‌gular.min.js"/>
<script src="js/lib/angular-route.js"/>
<script src="js/lib/angular-resource.js"/>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/contatos-controller.js"/>
<script src="js/controllers/contato-controller.js"/>
<script src="js/directives/minhas-diretivas.js"/>
<script src="js/services/meus-servicos.js"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97‌​.6/js/materialize.mi‌​n.js"/>
```

No console ele apresenta somente o erro:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @materialize.min.js:6',..
```

**Observação:** Eu ja importei o cdn do jquery!

Comment: Algum erro é apresentado no console do navegador? Ou simplesmente não funciona? Chegou a verificar o [angular-materialize](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/)? Ele inclui uma série de diretivas que permite ao Angular lidar com a maioria dos componentes JS do Materialize.

Comment: No console ele apresenta o somente o erro  'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ materialize.min.js:6',.. mas o css aparece normalmente, só as açoes que não acontecem

Comment: Qual a ordem das tags scripts? Consegui reproduzir este mesmo erro quando declaro o **jQuery** depois do **materialize.min.js**. Tente alterar a ordem das tags. Deixe na ordem: Angular, JQuery e depois o materialize.

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"//>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-route.js"/>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-resource.js"/>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers/contatos-controller.js"/>
 <script src="js/controllers/contato-controller.js"/>
 <script src="js/directives/minhas-diretivas.js"/>
    <script src="js/services/meus-servicos.js"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"/>`

Comment: Quando estou utilizando somente o materialize sei que existe essa ordem,.. mas agora com o angular ja tentei de todas as formas mas a unica diferença é que tem hora que meu angular para de funcionar e nem consigo ver se o materialize voltou

Comment: edite a sua pergunta juntando o estado atual das requisicoes, tirando isso dos comentarios. Nem todo mundo necessariamente ira olha-los para tentar lhe ajudar.

Comment: Não sei se foi por que colou no comentário - mas aqui gerou erro. Tente desta http://pastebin.com/p2h438FP. Estava com algum caracter especial.

Comment: https://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/

Answer (score 1):

Não é indicado mesclar os [dois](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21482/quais-as-principais-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-jquery-e-angularjs) (jQuery e Angular) caso o desejo seja alterar o DOM via jQuery dentro de uma aplicação Angular, pois isso deve ser feito via diretivas, até porque o AngularJS vem com uma versão Lite integrada do jQuery.

O recomendado é usar bibliotecas do próprio AngularJS, como [Angular bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) ou [Angular Materialize](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/) no seu caso. Na maioria dos casos a documentação e exemplos são completos.

Comment: É o ideal, porém pode-se usar jQuery junto sim, especialmente para os casos em que a versão lite nao seja suficiente e algo/alguma lib dependa dele. No meu caso, achei que o Angular Material e o Angular Materialize vão muito além do que quero, entao apenas encapsulei os metodos nativos do materialize.js (que usa jquery) no angular

Answer (score 0):

O erro que você declarou é causado por não adicionar o Jquery na página antes de tentar usa-lo. A declaracao deveria funcionar como segue:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"/> 
    <script src="js/lib/angular-route.js"/> 
    <script src="js/lib/angular-resource.js"/> 
    <script src="js/main.js"/>
    <script src="js/directives/minhas-diretivas.js"/> 
    <script src="js/services/meus-servicos.js"/>
    <script src="js/controllers/contatos-controller.js"/> 
    <script src="js/controllers/contato-controller.js"/>
```

Isso acontece por que a cada biblioteca que você utiliza deve já ter suas dependências previamente declaradas, para que a biblioteca possa usa-las. Ou seja, para incluir o `angularJS` e o `materialize` seu projeto precisa de `jQuery`, para usar `route` e `resource` você precisa do `angularJS`, além para conseguir rodar seus `controllers` e `services` claro, você necessita dos itens anteriores.