# API o que é e como funciona?

Tags: api

O que é uma API, alguém poderia me explicar de forma simples e com exemplos, procurei na internet mas estava tudo muito confuso.

Comment: [qual a difrença de api, biblioteca e framework](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework)

Answer (score 1):

API quer dizer "Application Programming Interface". É basicamente a façada de métodos publicos oferecido por uma framework.

Comment: Você poderia explicar de um modo mais simples?, assim ainda ficou confuso, com algum exemplo simples.

Comment: Não vejo a razão de dar um downvote a esta resposta. Podia estar mais completa mas não está errada.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine um controle de televisão, você aperta os botões para acionar algumas ações (Os botões seriam os métodos públicos). A interface do controle é sua API, ou seja, você chama seus métodos, mas não conhece sua implementação. Por trás dela pode haver muitas outras camadas, mas a que te interessa é a API.