# O que seria Win32?

Tags: windows, api

Em muitos locais da internet, vejo a expressão Win32 mas nunca uma explicação sobre.

> Aplicações Win32, etc.

Sempre associei com 32 *bits*, mas acredito que não tem a ver. Um jogo do Windows que usa mais de 4 GB de RAM, por exemplo, seria uma aplicação Win64?

Comment: Eu pensei se respondia ou não. Se eu entendi o que você quer saber, a pergunta está no escopo, é sobre programação. Se eu entendi errado, a sua pergunta provavelmente será fechada por não estar dentro do escopo do nosso site definido em [help/on-topic]

Comment: É sobre programação. Tenho duvidas se pesquiso sobre programação win32 ou se existir,win64

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pode ter vários significados. Um dos mais comuns, provavelmente o mais correto e que é muito relacionado à programação é que Win32 é nome de uma [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101).

Obviamente é a [API do Windows](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) tá bem melhor). E ela se diferencia da API antiga do Windows que era 16 bits. Pode parecer estranho mas o Windows 64 bits também usa a mesma API, porque Win32 é mais um nome do que uma referência à quantidade bits real que a plataforma pode endereçar ou tamanho dos registradores do processador.

Normalmente usa-se o termo "aplicações Win32" àquelas aplicações que fazem uso direto à esta API. Não importa se a aplicação foi compilada e está rodando em um Windows 32 ou 64 bits. Claro que aplicações 64 bits podem fazer uso de uma API mais moderna, a Win64, que não é necessariamente substituta da Win32. Basicamente é a mesma API com tamanho de ponteiro diferente. E justamente por isto mesmo quando é compilado para rodar em 64 bits, dizemos que a aplicação faz uso da Win32.

No Windows é possível usar outras APIs, como [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) e [WinRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) (atualmente UWP), por exemplo. Todas elas acabam usando a Win32 indiretamente.

Então esse hipotético jogo que você está falando provavelmente usa a Win64 mas pode ser confundida como usar a Win32, já que na prática é a mesma API. Ela é uma aplicação 64 bits para rodar em Windows 64 bits. Não precisa bater em ninguém por dizer que ela é Win64 mas não é a nomenclatura mais correta.

---

Só um detalhe extra: aplicações 64 bits podem endereçar memória maior que 4GB, independente de ser RAM ou não (o mesmo vale para aplicações 32 bits, claro, só que neste caso o acesso estará limitado a 4GB ou 2GB). O acesso é referente à [memória virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214744/101). Mas aí já é outro assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Resposta exata sobre o que eu queria. obg

Answer (score -3):

**Diferenças 32 bits x 64 bits:**

> Aplicativos de 32 bits será executado em ambas as versões do Windows de 32 bits e de 64 bits enquanto aplicativos de 64 bits só funciona em versões de 64 bits.
>
> > Uma vantagem que aplicativos de 64 bits é um potencial de desempenho e processamento maior, e outra é que eles podem exceder o limite de memória de 32 bits, o que lhes permite usar mais de 4 GB (o limite varia dependendo do hardware e sistema operacional).

Comment: Não é totalmente verdadeira a afirmação de que aplicativos de 32 bits rodam em Windows versão 64 bits. O que acontece é que aplicativos de 32 bits são executados no emulador [WOW64](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)(Windows 32 On Windows 64) que acompanha a versão 64 bits do OS.