# Posso executar uma imagem do .NET Native diretamente?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, assembly

Compilei meu executável em C# para uma imagem .NET Native usando o `ngen.exe`, tenho o local do arquivo, mas quando vou executar o Windows diz que o executável é inválido.

Meu objetivo era tornar meu aplicativo escrito em C# independente do .NET Framework e/ou armazenar o .NET numa DLL próxima ao executável de saída. O executável de entrada é um simples "Hello World" sem nenhuma dependência.

Se não tiver como executar a imagem, posso descompilar seu código para recompilar para C++ e compilar em Windows32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [`ngen` e .NET Native são coisas completamente diferentes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/net-native-and-compilation#net-native-and-ngen?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), o que usou só pode rodar com o .NET Framework.

Não alcançará o objetivo com ele, não importa o que faça.

Imaginando que por Windows32 esteja falando da API [Win32](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34953/101), se fizer em .NET não acessa ela diretamente. Código nativo nada tem a ver com a API que acessa.

E me parece que deseja usar o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101). Existe uma possibilidade de tentar o Mono. Se não resolver e as limitações atuais do .NET Native não atendem seu problema, não vejo solução no momento.