# Diferença entre biblioteca e helper

Tags: mvc, terminologia, biblioteca

O que diferencia o **helper** de uma **biblioteca**? Por exemplo: vamos dizer que eu tenha uma classe para manipulação de URL. Eu a chamo e ela completa a URL com o caminho do site. Isso seria um *helper*?

Comment: Depende do que você está chamando de *helper*. Se for um *helper method*, não sei se tem uma relação direta entre os termos a não ser que uma biblioteca pode ser uma coleção de métodos auxiliares, entre outras coisas.

Comment: *Helper* é um padrão de design. *Biblioteca* é um conjunto de estruturas e funcionalidades comuns a um conjunto de aplicações. Não sei se vale muito a pena comparar coisas tão diferentes.

Comment: Não posso falar no contexto do CodeIgniter, se é sobre ele que você deseja, coloque a *tag* identificando isto. Se é em um contexto geral, é o que já comentamos.

Comment: Esse artigo é bacana: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/173/the-difference-between-helpers-and-functions-in-webmatrix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu nunca vi o termo [biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) (ou *library*) ser aplicado no contexto específico do MVC, mesmo uma tecnologia específica usando MVC. Já vi o termo ser usando em contextos genéricos, o que obviamente inclui o MVC. Uma biblioteca é uma solução de estruturas e algoritmos, um conjunto de *features* relacionadas. Sem dúvida ela pode conter *helpers*. Eventualmente uma biblioteca pode ser composta só de *helpers*.

No contexto do MVC o *helper* é algo que deve ser usado para organizar a aplicação. É uma forma de criar uma versão canônica do que precisa ser usado. É muito comum fazer um *helper* quando ele será usado diversas vezes na aplicação. Mas eventualmente pode ser usado unicamente e ele é criado para simplificar o seu uso abstraindo o conteúdo. Isto é importante quando vai criar *views*, que devem possuir bem pouca lógica, então você "esconde" esta lógica nestes *helpers*. O mesmo pode ser dito para *controllers*.

Pelo menos no contexto do MVC esses *helpers*, grosso modo, costumam funcionar como [*snippets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snippet_%28programming%29) para usar dentro de *views* e como serviços no *controller*.

O *helper* tem uma função mais bem definida, apesar dele ser usado essencialmente para organização. A biblioteca é um conceito e técnica de organização e esta é sua função principal: organizar. Muda pouco na aplicação se você não organizar bibliotecas. Mas muda bem mais se não usar *helpers*. Sem *helpers* você pode ter redundância, inconsistência, ilegibilidade, só para citar alguns problemas, além dos problemas específicos por falta de organização.

Pode ser que alguma tecnologia específica de MVC tenha um uso e uma definição mais especializada. Por exemplo:

No comentário do Daniel Omine tem [um artigo](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/173/the-difference-between-helpers-and-functions-in-webmatrix) mostrando a diferença entre um *helper* clássico usado exclusivamente em *view* do ASP.NET MVC ([Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine)) e uma função que até pode ser usada como se fosse um *helper*. Além de existir um motivo semântico para escolher cada um existe uma diferença no tipo de dado que cada um retorna. Certamente o *helper* tem um padrão mais estrito porque o *framework* sabe fazer alguma coisa específica com aquilo.

Não respondi exatamente sobre a diferença porque, até onde eu sei, estes conceitos não são comparáveis diretamente. No máximo um pode fazer parte do outro.

Acho que seu exemplo é um *helper* mas precisa ver como ele foi escrito, usado e em que tecnologia é usado. Embora ache improvável, pode ser que esta classe não tenha uma função auxiliadora no sentido que costumamos entender.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Para entender mais especificamente o que disse - https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html. Perceba que através do **helper** URL eu posso obter a base url do meu site, a url atual, além de outras funções como a do redirect.

Comment: Foi o que eu imaginei, então é isto mesmo. Mas note que não é o conteúdo que vai definir se é *helper* ou não, é porque ele existe e como ele é usado.