# O que são libraries?

Tags: terminologia, biblioteca

Tava explorando a pasta do sistema Windows e vi o diretório `/lib/` queria saber o que ela é e se de fato ela é um diretório *library* e mais eu queria saber o que são *libraries* e qual sua aplicação?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e ajudar a todos entender isso. Também pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Não dá para saber, até porque no meu Windows não tem nenhuma óbvia. Também tem pouca ou nenhuma importância saber exatamente o que está sendo perguntado.

Dependendo do contexto pode ser uma coisa diferente. Pode ser só um arquivo com uma apanhado de códigos ou pode ser uma coleção de algoritmos disponíveis para uso. Ainda que ambos acabem se confundindo. Pode ser outras coisas, pode ser uma biblioteca de conteúdo de vídeo ou outras mídias.

O que ajudará entender os dois contextos principais que envolvem programação:

- [Qual a diferença de DLL e lib?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44269/101)
- [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101)
- [Diferença entre Biblioteca e Helper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54884/101) (contexto diferente)

Comment: Valeu pelos links , a do meio me ajudou bastante ...