# O que são classes DAO, MB, TO, SERVICE, MODELO, CONVERTER e HELPER?

Tags: java, classes

Nos projetos da empresa em que trabalho vejo diversas classes com essas nomeações, como sou iniciante na programação não sei ao certo o que elas significam.
Poderiam me tirar essa duvida ?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Como funciona o Padrão DAO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113840/91) e [Diferença entre Biblioteca, Helper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54884/91) e [O que é um DTO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31362/91)

Comment: Você quer saber o significado de cada um ou quer saber no geral porque algumas classes possuem esses pre/sufixos?

Answer (score 1):

Minha resposta não está completa, mas acredito que já vá ajudar. Tem nomenclaturas ai que provavelmente sejam usadas só pela sua empresa, as que eu conheço são:
DAO - Data Access Object. Basicamente é o ojeto que abstrai tudo que for referente ao acesso a dados da aplicação.
MODEL - Provavelmente seja relacionado ao MVC, Model View Controller, Model ou Modelo no seu caso é o objeto e suas caracteristicas, um modelo de formulário de registro tem:
`string Email{get;set;}` 
`string ConfirmaçãoEmail{get;set;}` 
`string Nome{get;set;}` 
`string Senha{get;set;}`