# Como criar um programa em C e usar interface gráfica do Java/C#?

Tags: java, c#, c, gui

Estou estudando interface gráficas em C, e percebi que é muito complexa e cansativa.

Então queria saber se há como eu criar um programa em C e usar interface gráfica do Java ou C#. Com uso de *frameworks* ou não...

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 10):

Até há como, mas não costuma compensar.

O que normalmente se faz é criar a aplicação em uma linguagem de um nível mais alto, como Java e C#, e com acesso à *frameworks* mais "fáceis" e só recorrer ao C quando precisa do máximo de performance ou acessar algum recurso que não está disponível nestas linguagens. Só que é comum a pessoa perceber que ela não precisa do C para nada em quase todas as aplicações.

Você pode tentar ir para o caminho de fazer a aplicação em C e chamar o Java ou C# quando precisar, mas é bem complicado e não compensa. Até onde eu sei ninguém tentou, até porque não há vantagem nisto.

Estas linguagens rodam em um ambiente controlado que traz dificuldades para ser invocado. Estes ambientes tomam conta da execução, que é o oposto do que se faz em C. Em geral uma aplicação com GUI tem como sua base o laço interação com o usuário. Ele é um [*framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) que se apropria da execução, não tem a opção de não usar o *framework*. Vai usar o C pra chamar isto? Pra que? Acho que imagina que as funções do C e do C# (por exemplo) vão conversar naturalmente como se fosse a mesma coisa. Isto não acontece. Os modelos de memória, organização das estruturas de dados e forma de chamada dos algoritmos são absurdamente diferentes com enormes complicações para o C chamar. A aplicação não transitará ente um e outro facilmente. Só será mais ou (bem) menos fácil chamar funções simples do C a partir do C# que é uma linguagem que foi pensada para interagir bem com C neste sentido (chamar algo externo ao C#).

Mesmo quando se faz algo em Java ou C# e vai chamar uma função em C não é algo tão simples, principalmente em Java. Então evita-se até que realmente seja necessário.

Outra forma seria fazer uma arquitetura cliente-servidor usando um executável para GUI na linguagem que quiser e o servidor escrito em C. Quase sempre isto é desnecessário, precisa ter um real motivo para que o servidor seja escrito em C. C tem algumas vantagens únicas mas também tem várias desvantagens, para qualquer aplicação. Só use se precisa destas vantagens únicas e pode arcar com as desvantagens, o que não parece ser o caso.

Se a comparação fosse com outras linguagens até poderia começar ver alguma vantagem. A diferença de Python por exemplo e C é brutal. Mesmo aí, o esquema de fazer a GUI na linguagem de mais alto nível e só delegar algumas poucas funções críticas para a performance prevalece.

De qualquer forma eu considero errada a afirmação que fazer GUI em C é complexo e cansativo. Mas não vou entrar em detalhes porque é opinião. Claro que é um pouco mais complexo, mas em C tudo é mais complexo. Não quer complexidade use outra linguagem.

E ainda existe o meio-termo de usar o C++, provavelmente com Qt. Alguns vão dizer que é o melhor dos dois mundos. Outros dirão que é o pior dos dois mundos.

C raramente é usada para aplicações "comuns". Mesmo C++ é adotada com parcimônia. Precisa ter um motivo que justifique sua adoção. O uso de Java ou C# tem lá suas desvantagens, mas se pode usar no projeto, dificilmente seria melhor usar C em conjunto, a não ser em algo muito pontual, e olhe lá.

Como diz o Luiz Vieira no comentário abaixo, em geral é melhor escrever tudo em uma só linguagem, mesmo se já existe um legado. Tentar fazer a GUI em outra linguagem e tentar integrar com o código legado em C só funcionará se ele foi bem escrito, pensado para funcionar de forma bem modular. O que confirme a dificuldade de fazer o oposto. As bibliotecas de Java e C# não foram feitas de forma modular, há uma dependência entre as partes que beira o insano.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu concordo com quase tudo na sua resposta, menos com "Ninguém tentou, até porque não há vantagem nisto.". Afirmar que ninguém tentou é (bem) difícil, e a discussão mais útil deveria estar na segunda parte dessa frase. De fato, pode ser útil no caso de sistemas legados em C, que o desenvolvedor deseja apenas portar a interação. Mas concordo novamente contigo que, nesse caso, provavelmente seria mais vantajoso re-escrever todo o código principal em C# ou Java e acessar algoritmos importantes legados mantidos em C (claro, supondo que estivesse originalmente bem organizado e separado rs).

Comment: É, vou dar uma melhorada.

Comment: Valeu! Mas, mesmo assim, já ganhou o meu +1. Boa resposta. :)

Answer (score 5):

Se a aplicação vai ser somente para Windows é mais fácil fazer em Visual Basic, por exemplo, até porque o .NET Framework é bem completo vai fornecer tudo o que você precisa para fazer uma aplicação comercial.
É um exemplo, mas não sei se é o seu caso.

De qualquer forma, concordo com o Maniero, porque eu mesmo tinha começado a programar em C, mas agora que comecei a entrar de verdade na área e a conhecer pessoas que programam profissionalmente, descobri que só mesmo quem sabe programar em C usa ele somente em casos bem específicos, tanto é que meu professor recomendou que pelo menos no começo eu aprendesse alguma linguagem .NET pois aqui na minha região não existe mercado para programador C.

Comment: Também sei programar em java e c# mais queria aprender linguagens estruturadas por isto estou aprendendo C
Mas obrigado Pela ajuda...

Comment: `C` é uma linguagem muito próxima das linguagens low-level como `assembly` acabando por o trabalho ser muito mais.

Comment: Essa afirmação é bem forte: "descobri que raramente alguém usa C para algum tipo de coisa." No contexto da maioria das aplicações comerciais isso é verdade, mas C (e C++) são linguagens amplamente utilizadas. Lembre-se que em computação deve-se sempre contextualizar. Não existe a pior ou a melhor linguagem. Existe a linguagem (ou conjunto de lingugagens) que se adequam melhor a determinado problema.

Comment: @cantoni, sim, concordo com você, talvez eu não tenha fraseado muito bem o que quis dizer, que na verdade é que agora que convivo e conheço vários programadores, descobri que mesmo os que sabem programar em C dão preferência à linguagens de alto nível e sob a influência deles decidi a aprender o C#, e confesso que estou gostando muito mais, o C# é bem mais objetivo e fácil de se programar...

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa, mas permanece o fato de que você está colocando o C em um contexto específico de aplicações comerciais (sistemas de informação). Para esses casos, linguagens como C#, Java, VB.NET, Python são sem sombra de dúvidas mais adequadas do que C. Em outras palavras, creio que essa comparação não deveria existir. Sobre aprender Java ou .NET muito cedo, eu tenho minhas ressalavas. Cursos de Computação deveriam expor o aluno nos primeiros períodos a apenas C e C++, já que as mesmas dão o embasamento necessário para compreender conceitos como ponteiros, gerenciamento de memória, etc.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa, já ouviu falar de Qt Framework, ele é otimo para criar sistemas gráficos usando C++