# Como é desenvolvido um Framework?

Tags: java, framework, biblioteca

Já usei alguns **frameworks** eles realmente dinamizaram o desenvolvimento do meu projeto, me ajudaram, não tive que perder tempo construindo a parte comum do meu problema  que outras pessoas já tinham implementado, tive que fazer apenas  o código que diferencia o meu projeto dos demais.

Tenho uma questão:

a) O que é necessário para o desenvolvimento de um **Framework?**

Comment: Precisa saber desenvolver software em todos os aspectos, com profissionalismo e ter experiência. Não é possível fazer algo deste tipo sem ter um grande domínio de todas as técnicas de desenvolvimento e entender a real necessidade do que quer resolver. Pouquíssimas pessoas possuem essas características. O esmagadora maioria só será consumidora deles. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101

Comment: Não é tão ampla. Já que suspenderam, vou resumir num comment: **a)** É necessário um problema que possa ser resolvido por um framework, e um profundo conhecimento deste problema. ***É mais importante conhecer bem o problema do que conhecer previamente as técnicas de solução***. **b)** Tenha certeza de que ainda não existe a solução ótima para o problema; faça uma solução flexível pois vc não pode prever 100% do uso que farão dela; aceite ajuda. **c)** Use as bibliotecas que resolvam subsets do problema geral que o seu framework visa resolver, se elas forem boas o bastante para o seu propósito.

Comment: @Caffé muito obrigado cara!! Ajudou muito !!

Answer (score 5):

Depende do que você quer fazer.

Um ***framework***, ao contrário de uma **biblioteca**, é uma espécie de ambiente que chama ou usa o seu código. Isso significa que ele é um programa (ou um conjunto de programas) que usa o seu programa como entrada.

Por exemplo: Digamos que você esteja desenvolvendo um *framework* que te permite escrever código Python dentro de arquivos HTML com tags específicas (em vez de Javascript). Para que seu código Python funcione nos navegadores, ele deve ser transformado em Javascript no final do processo. O *framework* precisaria conter um *parser* desse HTML extendido. Isso poderia ser feito usando uma biblioteca de HTML que já existe e tenha essa capacidade. O seu *framework* também precisaria de um conversor de Python para Javascript. Portanto, poderia usar um que já existe. Por fim, ele precisaria subir sua aplicação convertida para o servidor de aplicação. Para isso, precisaria de integração com esse servidor. Isso pode ser feito através de um driver que faça essa ponte.

Em resumo: *frameworks* são programas. Seu código entra e um outro código sai. O que exatamente ele vai usar ou precisar depende do que você quer que ele faça. Espero que tenha dado pra ter uma ideia e nos conte sobre seu *framework* no futuro. :)

Comment: obrigado pela atenção cara

Answer (score 5):

O processo de desenvolvimento de framework.

Há algumas metodologias documentadas para o desenvolvimento de um framework. A maioria delas, porém, admitem o fato de que o objetivo é identificar abstrações com uma abordagem de baixo para cima: começar por analisar as soluções existentes e ser capaz de generalizar a partir delas. Quanto a adoção de um processo de desenvolvimento framework
 é importante ter em conta que qualquer framework geralmente começa como um framework de caixa-branca e, idealmente, evolui para uma caixa-preta . Também é importante compreender que o desenvolvimento de um framework é mais difícil do que o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação porque os usuários devem ser capazes de entender muitas decisões de design. 
Por esta razão, é ainda mais importante seguir boas práticas de projeto e princípios.

Em [Johnson, 1993], o autor explica a diferença entre o "ideal '' e a  "boa '' maneira de desenvolver frameworks e software em geral. 
O ideal consiste em três fases básicas. Primeiro analisar o domínio do problema, aprendendo abstrações e recolhendo exemplos de programas a ser construído. Em seguida, projetar abstrações que podem ser especializados para cobrir todos os exemplos e derivar uma teoria para explicar estas aplicações. E, finalmente, testar o framework, usando-o para resolver os exemplos. 
Este ideal é impossível de seguir completamente por duas razões principais: é muito difícil e demorado para fazer uma análise exaustiva de domínio, analisando todas os possíveis exemplos existentes; e aplicativos antigos trabalham para que não haja incentivo financeiro para convertê-los para usar o novo software. Assim, uma menos-que-ideal-mas-boa maneira de desenvolver um framework é a primeira a pegar duas aplicações no domínio que é suposto ser resolvido usando o framework; certifique-se de que, pelo menos, alguns dos desenvolvedores na equipe têm desenvolvido aplicações para esse domínio  particular; e  divide-se o projeto em três grupos: um grupo-framework, que tanto dá e tira software, considera como outras aplicações iria reutilizar o framework e desenvolve-se documentação e treinamento; e dois grupos de aplicativos que tentam reutilizar o  máximo de software no âmbito do possível e reclamar sobre o quão difícil é a reutilização.

Em [Bosch et al., 1999] os autores dão uma (embora complementares) Visão diferente do processo de desenvolvimento do framework. Primeiro eles distinguiram duas atividades diferentes no desenvolvimento do framework: projeto núcleo do framework e incrementos internos do framework. O desenho do núcleo do framework compreende ambas as classes abstratas e concretas no domínio. As classes concretas se destinam a ser invisível e transparente para o utilizador final (por exemplo, uma utilidade básica armazenamento) enquanto as classes abstratas são ou destinam-se a ser invisível, ou para ser usado através de subclasses. Por outro lado no framework os incrementos internos constroem classes adicionais que formam uma série de bibliotecas de classes. Eles capturam implementações comuns do desenho do  núcleo do framework e eles podem ser tanto subclasses que representam realizações comuns dos conceitos capturados pelos superclasses ou uma coleção de classes que representam a especificação para a instanciação completa do framework em um contexto particular. A aplicação final construída a partir do framework consiste de alguns desenhos do núcleo do framework, dos incrementos internos do framework e um “ incremento específico do aplicativo “.

Neste modelo, as principais fases do desenvolvimento são:
(1) a fase de desenvolvimento do framework é geralmente a fase de mais consumo de esforço e se destina a produzir um design reutilizável num domínio particular;
(2) o uso do framework ou fase de instanciação onde as aplicações são desenvolvidas;
(3) a evolução do framework e fase de manutenção.

Uma série de atividades podem ser identificadas na primeira fase de desenvolvimento, ou seja, análise de domínio, projeto arquitetônico, design de framework, a execução framework, testar o framework com um teste de aplicativos. Ao determinar o âmbito de domínio há um problema de escolha do tamanho correto: Se a estrutura é demasiada grande, muitos especialistas talvez  sejam necessários na equipe e o processo pode tornar-se caro e longo; se o framework é muito estreito, pode ter de ser adaptado para cada novo aplicativo que vem à tona. Uma vez que o framework pode ser utilizado de muitas formas, por vezes, desconhecidas, pode simplesmente não ser viável para testar todos os aspectos do framework. Uma vez que o framework se baseia em algumas partes implementadas pelo usuário pode ser impossível para testar completamente antes de seu lançamento.

Na fase de utilização do framework, as principais atividades envolvidas são: análise de domínio, projeto arquitetônico, design do framework, a execução do framework, testar o framework com um teste de aplicativos. Nesta fase há uma questão importante a ser enfrentada. Se um erro no framework é encontrado ao desenvolver uma aplicação: quem é que vai corrigir o erro no framework? e, se as aplicações que estão trabalhando e não são aparentemente afetadas por este erro atualizarem para a versão mais recente do framework?

Também é interessante dar uma olhada em como uma empresa, tais como os modelos suíços de framework da Ericsson no processo de desenvolvimento. A Ericsson Software Technology Frameworks tem uma metodologia modelo que é instanciado com cada projeto novo framework e que podem ser resumidos nas seguintes diretrizes (ver [Landis e Niklasson, 1995]): Uma lista de requisitos em pelo menos duas aplicações devem ser fornecidos em conjunto com uma lista de requisitos sobre o framework. Deve também ser fornecida uma lista de exigências futuras. A equipe do projeto deve incluir membros com conhecimento de cada aplicativo e um membro com conhecimentos do design do framework. As informações devem ser recolhidas a partir de tantas fontes quanto possível. Requisitos e casos de uso devem ser separados em específico-do-framework e específico-do-aplicativo e eles também devem ser divididos em funcionais e não-funcionais. Abstrações de alto nível devem ser identificadas, se preparando para a identificação do framework. Mas apenas abstrações que estão no domínio do framework devem ser introduzidos e depois eles devem ter o mesmo nome no modelo estático. As soluções existentes devem ser examinados e grandes frameworks devem ser estruturados em sub-frameworks. Um modelo estático para cada aplicação deve ser desenvolvido, em seguida, a introdução de abstrações comuns a várias aplicações para o framework. Usando notações gráficas do projeto devem ser apresentadas de forma clara a todos os membros do projeto. Subsistemas devem ter alta coesão e pouco acoplamento. Finalmente frameworks existentes devem ser estudados tentando reutilizar tanto o design como possível.

E de acordo com o mencionado anteriormente Taligent, o processo de desenvolvimento de frameworks deve observar quatro orientações importantes que podem ser entendidos como um resumo da lista anterior [Adair, 1995]:

•   Derivar frameworks de problemas e soluções existentes.
•   Desenvolver pequenos frameworks, com foco.
•   Construir frameworks que utilizem um processo iterativo impulsionado pela participação do cliente e prototipagem.
•   Tratar frameworks como produtos, fornecendo documentação e suporte, e pelo planejamento para a distribuição e manutenção.

E relacionado com o processo de desenvolvimento de framework é finalmente interessante notar que à medida que Opdyke salienta [Opdyke, 1992, Opdyke e Johnson, 1990] uma das principais características de um framework é que ele é concebido para ser refinado, boas estruturas são geralmente o resultado de muitas iterações de projeto e um monte de trabalho envolvendo mudanças estruturais às vezes.

[**Fonte:** Aqui está o texto original dessa humilde tradução onde você pode encontrar mais informações sobre frameworks.](http://xavier.amatriain.net/Thesis/html/node27.html)

Comment: Leitura obrigatória para quem deseja criar ou entender sobre desenvolvimento de Frameworks, apesar de estar em inglês, o artigo tem uma linguagem bem simples e é muito bem explicado: [Design, implementation and
evolution of object oriented
frameworks: concepts and
guidelines](http://www.jillesvangurp.com/static/spejvg.pdf). Artigo escrito por [Jan Bosch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Bosch) e [Jilles van Gurp](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jillesvangurp)

Answer (score 3):

**O que é necessário para o desenvolvimento de um Framework?**

Depende de para que seja o seu framework.

Existem frameworks para desenvolvimento de diferentes tipos de software, um framework de desenvolvimento de jogos é muito diferente de um framework para desenvolvimento de sistemas web.

Vamos tomar como exemplo o caso do framework para criação de sistemas web:

Imagine que você é um desenvolvedor muito experiente que já desenvolveu dezenas ou até centenas de sistemas e notou que a maioria deles tem as mesmas funcionalidades. Então você faz um sistema genérico, juntando tudo que já havia feito repetido antes, e este sistema genérico se torna base para produzir um novo sistema nos mesmos moldes que os anteriores. Está aí seu framework.

No caso de frameworks web pode ser interessante:

- Que o framework seja orientado a objetos e siga o padrão MVC.
- Tenha um Front Controller.
- Tenha uma estrutura de urls amigáveis analisadas por expressões regulares para chamar os controllers e métodos certos.
- Tenha alguma classe ou coleção de classes para facilitar a utilização de bancos de dados.
- Possua classes para paginação de dados, formatações de data, manuseio de arquivos, exportação de relatórios em csv, excel, pdf, etc.

Para resumir, o necessário para desenvolver um framework é ter o conhecimento de como desenvolver um que sirva para lhe auxiliar na criação dos projetos que você deseja desenvolver.