# O que é Access Token? Pra que serve?

Tags: node.js, api, segurança, autenticação, token

**O que exatamente é um Access Token?**

**Pra que serve um Access Token em uma aplicação que usa API?**

Gostaria de uma resposta voltada a Node.js, mas acredito que criação de API exista em diversas linguagens, logo, não acho necessário ser apenas para JavaScript (Node.js).

Comment: Tokens são usados para a validação de usuários ao acessar determinada API ou sistema para garantir a autenticidade de quem acessou, ou esta acessando.

Comment: Eu respondi sem falar em Node.js, porque não me parece que faça sentido na forma como a pergunta foi feita que tenha alguma relação com essa tecnologia, na verdade nem sei se deveria estar citado isto na pergunta. A não ser que a pergunta fosse outra e desejaria saber como implementar isso em Node.js, mas seria uma pergunta muito diferente.

Comment: @bigown muito obrigado mesmo, você respondeu exatamente o que eu queria saber. Eu só citei Node.js, caso alguém queira dar uma detalhada em como funciona em node, mas não é realmente importante. Eu dei uma editada na pergunta usando o termo Access Token, pra ficar mais específico.  Eu não sabia que esse termo existia, teria facilitado tudo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É muito simples, ele é a sua senha de acesso à API (usando seu termo). Normalmente você compra o direito de uso de um serviço, geralmente web. Ele é necessário tanto quanto precisa de uma senha aqui neste site, no Facebook, em um painel de controle de algum serviço, etc. porque precisa:

- garantir que só a pessoa certa vai usá-la,
- contabilizar o uso para a pessoa certa se tiver limites,
- verificar se essa pessoa está usando o serviço adequadamente,
- permitir que só quem é dono de certos dados possa acessá-los.

Se vai acessar de forma mecânica por um sistema e não interativamente, não tem porque pedir usuário e senha, embora nada impeça que seja assim. Como não será algo que a pessoa terá que ficar lembrando e digitando, pode ser bem grande e bem complexo, daí nem precisa de dois *tokens* de acesso (usuário e senha), sendo que um deles costuma ser um nome mais óbvio e o outro depende de cada pessoa, mas costumam usar coisas fáceis de lembrar. Faz logo um código virtualmente indecifrável.

Há casos que o *token* carrega informações extras que podem ajudar na autorização. O mais importante é que ele seja único. Ele é usado em todas as requisições do serviço. Não confundir com *token* de sessão* ou de segurança.

É óbvio que isso não dá muita segurança, estamos falando de **autenticação** de acesso e não segurança. Esse código é trafegado pela internet, é colocado em sistemas e vira e mexe o programador incauto posta esse *token* publicamente na internet. Aqui acontece com frequência. Cada um deve ser responsável por dar segurança para ele não ser acessado indevidamente.

Ele não garante uso indevido, seja porque o "dono" do *token* passou para outra pessoa usar, seja porque ele não cuidou o suficiente para que ele não fosse roubado.

Não gosto do termo API que todo mundo usa nesse contexto. [API é outra coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101). As pessoas acessam um serviço, em geral externo, em geral usando tecnologias web, para ter acesso à dados, fazer certos processamentos, usar certas tecnologias, etc. É verdade que a pessoa está acessando o serviço via uma API, mas o serviço não é uma API, ainda que as pessoas achem que é.

Não existe aplicação API. Existe API para uma aplicação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).