# O que é um SDK?

Tags: terminologia, sdk

Até pouco tempo atrás, eu sempre via SDK como algo relacionado ao universo do Android. Porém tenho percebido algumas bibliotecas PHP que também usam o nome *SDK*.

Por exemplo:

- [pagseguro-php-sdk](https://github.com/pagseguro/pagseguro-php-sdk)
- [facebook/graph-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk)

Mas afinal, o que seria um SDK?

Por que nos casos acima, não chamar o *SDK* de biblioteca? Teria alguma diferença?

O termo SDK pode variar do Android para outras linguagens, ou vice-versa?

Comment: SDK (como o próprio nome indica ) é um kit de desenvolvimento completo. Pode incluir a IDE, exemplos de código, drives, etc. 
Já biblioteca é conjunto de implementação rotineiras. Uma forma de reaproveitamento de código (dentre muitas)

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff não faz sentido para PHP... No caso, a *biblioteca* do PagSeguro por exemplo não inclui uma IDE :p

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kit_de_desenvolvimento_de_software

Comment: O SDK pode incluir uma IDE. Não significa que vai. SDKs de softhouses incluem até mesmo hardware. É uma definição mais abstrata. Tem mais haver com as ferramentas, do que tipo de ferramentas elas serão.

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho a pobre explicação do Wikipédia não fala nada sobre PHP :\

Comment: SDKs mais completas são mais comuns em sistemas embarcados e linguagens compiladas. Tem muita gente que acha que PHP só faz site.

Comment: Talvez caia aqui => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/91

Comment: @rray de fato tem SDK na resposta

Comment: @rray eu até pensei em não perguntar por conta dessa, mas o que complicou foi o "SDK costuma vir com IDE e afins", sendo que em PHP isso não é verdade :p

Comment: Da uma lida nesse link [*Aqui*](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sdk-for-php/) talvez você encontre oque esta procurando.

Comment: Creio que quase qualquer resposta aqui vai estar correta, creio que um kit de desenvolvimento de software pode ser qualquer coisa que seja usado completamente para desenvolver outras aplicações ou funcionalidades sem depender de quase mais nada, como o Bacco me disse, é um nome genérico.

Comment: pobre, @WallaceMaxters? kkkkkk, é miserável, rerere

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho é que o Wiki costuma ter mais detalhamento. Dessa vez, esse artigo tá pequenininho... E não responderia diretamente a pergunta do PHP :p

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Mas afinal o que seria uma SDK?

Software Development Kits podem assumir a forma de *toolkits* ou de *frameworks* e fornecem tudo o que precisa para programar em cima de uma plataforma (sistema operacional, banco de dados, aplicação, etc.). Estes kits costumam englobar:

- ferramentas adicionais que ajudam certas tarefas além das bibliotecas,
- documentação e exemplos de códigos que ajudam a usar a biblioteca adequadamente.

Referência: [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101)

> Por que nos casos acima, não chamar a SDK de biblioteca? Teria alguma diferença?

No *link* acima tem a diferença do SDK e da biblioteca. A biblioteca é só uma uma coleção de algoritmos, o SDK é um conjunto de ferramentas entre elas a(s) biblioteca(s).

> O termo SDK pode variar do Android para outras linguagens, ou vice-versa?

Android não é uma linguagem, é uma plataforma. SDK é o SDK, como cada um funciona é problema de cada **plataforma**. É possível ter SDKs diferentes para cada linguagem ou o SDK pode conter capacidade de lidar com várias linguagens.

Oficialmente é isso. Claro que sempre é possível alguém inventar um termo novo, usar este mesmo termo para outra coisa. Não podemos olhar para o uso errado para fazer uma definição.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR: Uma biblioteca pode fazer parte de um SDK mas nem todo SDK é apenas uma biblioteca.**

Um SDK é como um baú. Dentro de uma SDK você vai encontrar, no geral, diversos itens. Por exemplo:

- Bibliotecas
- Documentação
- Exemplos de uso de código; e, em alguns casos,
- IDEs

Entre outras coisas, o propósito da SDK (Kit do Desenvolvedor de Software, em tradução livre) é garantir que você já tenha tudo pronto pra desenvolver/implementar/estender a aplicação cujo SDK você baixou.

Por exemplo, o SDK do Android inclui:

- Android Studio
- Documentação
- Emulador do Android
- Exemplos e tutoriais

Alguns outros termos que geralmente são associados:

### **API**

Uma API é uma interface usada para interagir com uma biblioteca ou com um sistema. Quando você faz uso de um SDK, você vai, muito provavelmente, estar também fazendo uso de uma API do sistema em questão.

### **Bibliotecas**

Bibliotecas são conjuntos de funções e/ou classes que estendem a funcionalidade do seu programa.

Answer (score 6):

Creio que todas respostas estão quase inteiramente corretas, isso porque SDK do ponto de vista pode ser quase qualquer coisa, não que basta você dizer "isso é um SDK" para ele se tornar algo assim.

Pelo que andei observando o SDK não necessariamente precisa de um IDE, ou ferramenta completa e pronta, o PHP é uma linguagem voltada para servidor e ocasionalmente para *CLI*, ou seja, pode-se editar seus documentos em qualquer editor e pelo que entendi com os exemplos citados tanto na pergunta quanto nas demais respostas é que SDK deverá ser um ***"kit" completo para desenvolver na plataforma especifica***, então se é possível com estes repositórios "desenvolver" a sua aplicação (independente de qualquer coisa extra) para o PHP especificamente, então sim, estes repositórios são SDKs.

Claro que para poder desenvolver completamente, no caso do *pagseguro-sdk*, me parece que ele contem um simulador do pagseguro junto as bibliotecas, escrito em PHP mesmo (https://github.com/pagseguro/pagseguro-php-sdk/tree/master/public).

Outra coisa que notei no repositório do facebook-sdk é que eles tem a pasta docs (https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/tree/5.4/docs), nela contém a documentação, não vejo como obrigatório para um SDK, creio que isto também deva definir um SDK escrito em PHP, pois o tornará independente de fontes onlines.

### Conclusão

Não quer dizer que são de fato bons SDKs, ou que para estes repositórios o termo SDK vai se encaixar bem, mas é bem provável que para algo ser um SDK na plataforma especificada ele vai precisar de algo no minimo como:

- Biblioteca completa ou software
- Documentação (seria opcional se tiver fontes acessíveis externas)
- Esta biblioteca tem que funcionar quase independente de qualquer coisa (na plataforma especificada, no caso PHP)

Sendo assim, na linguagem PHP o software que o *pagseguro-sdk* e o *facebook-sdk* dependem são unicamente de suas próprias bibliotecas para o desenvolvimento, ou seja as bibliotecas e as coisas adicionais são o seu *Kit de desenvolvimento de software* (SDK), então um SDK pode incluir qualquer coisa, desde que sirva de "ferramenta" para o desenvolvimento na tal plataforma.

### Pontos que gerariam o contra da conclusão

- Pagseguro não tem documentação junto:

  - Eu diria que é uma boa biblioteca, mas não um bom SDK
- Facebook depende de conexão com a internet e usar no minimo o sandbox (creio eu):

  - Talvez simular tudo que o facebook faz não seja tão fácil ainda, não estou certo se tem como simular.
- Ambas dependem do PHP para executar os scripts:

  - No Android SDK é necessário Java para rodar, no Microsoft SDK é necessário o Windows para rodar, tudo tem alguma dependência, por isto eu disse "quase independente".

Answer (score 3):

SDK é a sigla para Software Development Kit (ou Software Developers Kit – pacote de desenvolvimento de software). É esse pacote que permite à programadores elaborarem aplicativos para rodarem em uma plataforma específica como Facebook, Android, IOS, Windows e outras plataforma.

SDK facilitam a integração com os recursos da plataforma escolhida.

Answer (score 1):

SDK, ou "source development kit", é:

- um framework proprietário, que é tornado público
- o propósito é o de que utilizadores externos possam contribuir para o desenvolvimento de uma plataforma.
- permite por norma integrar serviços daquela plataforma especifica

Exemplos de SDK:

- **Android SDK**, (Google -> android)
- UBUNTU SDK, (UBUNTU)