# Capturar informações de Paginas no facebook

Tags: php, facebook

gostaria de uma informação. Existe alguma forma de obter alguns dados de páginas não administradas por mim, tipo *[curtidas, comentários e etc]* de alguma página apenas informando o URL desta página??

Explico: 
é possível obter informações de páginas que não são minhas? Tipo, coloco o endereço da página do Bradesco (https://www.facebook.com/Bradesco/) e essa aplicação me retornaria dados como: curtidas, quantidade de compartilhamentos tudo dentro de um período de tempo... ???

Comment: Utilize cURL + DOM/XPATH, ambos "por padrão" já tem no PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, é possível obter dados de páginas e grupos públicos por meio da API do Facebook, basta entrar no [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/) e registrar um app para obter suas credenciais. Vejo que pretende fazer isso em PHP então pode usar este [SDK](https://packagist.org/packages/facebook/graph-sdk) via composer.

Documentação da API:

- developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview

Sobre páginas:

- developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/
- developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights/

Answer (score 0):

O facebook fornece uma api para desenvolvedores, https://developers.facebook.com/ você pode entrar ai e dar uma lida na documentação, mas a principio você vai consumir uma api rest, se não souber trabalhar com api rest uma rapida pesquisada no google vai te dar um norte.

Comment: Verdade, mas a API dele me permite pegar apenas informações se a página/usuário autorizar... necessitaria fazer isso em umas 100 páginas distintas, onde estas eu não sou ADM e não necessitaria fazer a solicitação de que entrem e permitam a captura dos dados.... compreende?

Answer (score 0):

Assim como já foi informado, você pode utilizar as bibliotecas próprias do `PHP` como [`cURL`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) e [`DOM`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php), porém essa é uma opção exaustiva.

O `Facebook` disponibiliza uma [`SDK`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted) que fornece a facilidade/praticidade para obter informações de sua plataforma. Para o que você precisa, há uma [documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages) específica.

Dica de leitura: [O que é uma SDK?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191584/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-sdk)