# Qual a diferença entre JavaScript e jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Penso no `Jquery` como um [Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework) `JavaScript` com intuito de otimizar a escrita, o `Ajax` é um bom exemplo.

- Além da escrita facilitada, existe diferença entre ambos?
- Quais as vantagens e desvantagens em usar jQuery?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework

Comment: JavaScript vs jQuery - Tudo o Que Você Precisa Saber http://programadorobjetivo.co/jquery-vs-javascript-tudo-o-que-voce-precisa-saber/

Comment: Relacionada: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzawb.gif

Comment: Se você não for fazer um grande framework, ou sistema complexo, ou um site gigante, considere usar Javascript puro.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Gostei muito do arquivo que você postou aqui no comentario. Postei está dúvida, porque algumas pessoas me questionaram sobre o assunto e foi o que eu sabia até o momento sobre.

Comment: `otimizar a escrita` Nem sempre.....

Comment: a resposta foi aceita muito rápido.

Comment: @MarceloBoni tem algum caso em que o `Javascript` é mais simples?

Comment: @Marconi, pelo menos **um bom** [exemplo](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#get_outer_html)

Comment: @MarceloBoni eu vi na resposta do Sergio esse link mesmo. O innerHTML por sinal é o que mais uso.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

jQuery é JavaScript.
Ou seja jQuery é uma biblioteca escrita/construida com a linguagem JavaScript.

Existem duas razões principais para ter uma biblioteca como jQuery:

- poder simplificar a vida ao programador, com menos linhas de código para fazer coisas que em JavaScript nativo seria preciso mais linhas
- ter uma API que é igual em todos os browsers que essa biblioteca suporta

Pensando na biblioteca jQuery como uma ferramenta para facilitar a vida ao programador, a ideia é poupar trabalho, em extensão de código necessário escrever e minimizar possiveis erros.

Por exemplo uma chamada ajax para ir buscar um JSON seria assim em jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('/o/meu/url', function(data) {

});
```

para fazer o mesmo em JavaScript nativo seriam precisas mais linhas:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // tudo correu bem!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    // aqui é o mesmo que o interior do exemplo com jQuery
  } else {
    // este pedaço é corrido se houver algum erro

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // este pedaço é corrido se houver algum erro
};

request.send();
```

Na prática o jQuery tem essas linhas todas escritas na sua biblioteca (no ficheiro JavaScript que temos de carregar com a página) mas mostra ao programador somente os métodos que constrói e simplificam as coisas como mostrei no primeiro exemplo.

jQuery nem sempre é preciso, aliás já não é tão importante como foi em tempos. Um site interessante com funcionalidades comuns que se fazem bem em JavaScript nativo hoje em dia: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Quando programamos uma aplicação, e os utilizadores usam o nosso programa em browsers diferentes corremos o risco de o JavaScript que escrevermos não funcionar em alguns browsers. Isto porque cada um implementa as coisas com ligeiras diferenças, ou porque uns são mais modernos que outros. O papel de bibliotecas como o jQuery é criar uma camada de abstração para só usarmos a sua API, e não JavaScript nativo. Assim, dentro da biblioteca, fazem-se as correções e ajustes necessários para um código jQuery como `$(document).on('click', ...` seja decomposto no JavaScript que um dado browser entende e proporcionar a mesma funcionalidade.

Um exemplo clássico é a maneira de amarrar auscultadores de eventos nas versões antigas do Internet Explorer.

A maneira moderna é `elemento.addEventListener` mas o IE tinha `elemento.attachEvent`. Para evitar escrever uma data de código como este ([fonte](https://gist.github.com/eirikbacker/2864711)):

```js
//addEventListener polyfill 1.0 / Eirik Backer / MIT Licence
(function(win, doc){
 if(win.addEventListener)return;  //No need to polyfill

 function docHijack(p){var old = doc[p];doc[p] = function(v){return addListen(old(v))}}
 function addEvent(on, fn, self){
  return (self = this).attachEvent('on' + on, function(e){
   var e = e || win.event;
   e.preventDefault  = e.preventDefault  || function(){e.returnValue = false}
   e.stopPropagation = e.stopPropagation || function(){e.cancelBubble = true}
   fn.call(self, e);
  });
 }
 function addListen(obj, i){
  if(i = obj.length)while(i--)obj[i].addEventListener = addEvent;
  else obj.addEventListener = addEvent;
  return obj;
 }

 addListen([doc, win]);
 if('Element' in win)win.Element.prototype.addEventListener = addEvent;   //IE8
 else{  //IE < 8
  doc.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function(){addListen(doc.all)});  //Make sure we also init at domReady
  docHijack('getElementsByTagName');
  docHijack('getElementById');
  docHijack('createElement');
  addListen(doc.all); 
 }
})(window, document);
```

usamos jQuery, que tem mais ou menos isso dentro do seu ficheiro `.js` e usamos a sua camada de abstração (API) que fica somente:

```
$(elemento).on('nome-do-evento', ...
```

---

**Mais informação:**

- sobre conceitos como API, Framework, Biblioteca aqui: [(link)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/129)
- a wiki da tag [JavaScript aqui no SO.pt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)
- a wiki da tag [jQuery aqui no SO.pt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)

Comment: Gostei do exemplo do `addEventListener`. Eu achava que a maneira que as empresas de Browsers escrevem seus `js` seguiam um padrão. Então posso dizer que o jQuery é mais do que necessário?

Comment: @Marconi sim, exato. jQuery ou outra biblioteca é importante se precisares de usar muito js em browsers diferentes.

Comment: Como hoje em dia não sabemos qual dispositivo o usuario possa estar, podemos dizer que não usar um biblioteca como jQuery é altamente arriscado seu código não funcionar?

Answer (score 26):

`JavaScript` é uma linguagem, enquanto `jQuery` é uma biblioteca focada na manipulação de elementos do DOM. Bibliotecas são feitas com base em uma linguagem e frameworks são feitos geralmente com base em uma biblioteca.

O que acontece é que o `javascript` é uma linguagem antiga e o desenvolvimento com ela é um pouco trabalhosa e as vezes é necessário escrever muito código. Então o `jQuery` é um framework, ou seja, é o próprio `javascript` redefinido de uma maneira mais moderno, simples de usar e com o uso de menos código.

Uma diferença que deve ser destacada é de que o `JavaScript` roda nativamente no browsers enquanto que para o `jQuery` deve ser adicionada uma referência a sua biblioteca no HTML.Por exemplo:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
```

## *Vantagens de usar jQuery:*

- Acesso direto a qualquer componente do DOM, ou seja, não há
  necessidade de várias linhas de código para acessar determinados
  pontos no DOM.
- O uso de regras de estilo não sofre qualquer tipo de limitação devido
  as inconsistências dos navegadores. Mesmo os seletores CSS3 podem ser
  usados sem qualquer restrição.
- Manipulação de conteúdos, sem limitações, com algumas poucas linhas
  de código. Suporte para toda a gama de eventos de interação com o
  usuário sem limitações impostas pelos navegadores.
- Possibilidade de inserir uma grande variedade de efeitos de animação
  com uma simples linha de código.
- Uso simplificado e sem restrições com AJAX e linguagens de
  programação, como PHP e ASP.
- Simplificação na criação de scripts.
- Emprego cross-browser.
- É possível selecionar elementos com maior facilidade, maior
  compatibilidade, e com menos código. Veja um exemplo de um codigo em `JavaScript` e do mesmo em `jQuery`:

  ***- Em JavaScript:***

```js
var botao = document.getElementById("botao");

if (botao.attachEvent) {
    botao.attachEvent("onclick", function(event) {
        alert("Você clicou no botão, usuário do IE!");
    });
} else if (botao.addEventListener) {
    botao.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        alert("Você clicou no cabeçalho!")
    }, false);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id='botao'>Clique</button>
```

***- Em jQuery:***

```js
$("#botao").click(function (event) {
  alert("Você clicou no botao!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id='botao'>Clique</button>
```

*Note como a sintaxe do jQuery é bem menor.*

## *Desvantagens ao ultilizar jQuery*

- `jQuery` tem perda de performance. Esse tipo de perda é inerente a  quaisquer abstrações, mas é acentuado pela quantidade de recursos extras envolvidos.

  A implementação em si também é menos otimizada quando comparada a
  implementações que já vem do próprio core do Javascript. É bom evitar a 
  utilização de jQuery, pelo menos, em loops muito extensos ou    aninhados 
  onde uma penalidade de performance pode se multiplicar ou    até crescer 
  exponencialmente.
- `jQuery` é uma biblioteca, então possui outros concorrentes. Se você
  estiver usando um framework como o Angular que possui o seu próprio
  jqLite, não haverá necessidade de usar jQuery. Saber JavaScript,
  entretanto, sempre será útil.

Referências:

- [*Introdução à jQuery*](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2068/introducao-a-jquery.aspx)
- [*JavaScript vs jQuery - Tudo o Que Você Precisa Saber*](http://programadorobjetivo.co/jquery-vs-javascript-tudo-o-que-voce-precisa-saber/)
- [jQuery](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-html-css-javascript/jquery/#12-1-jquery-a-funcao)

Comment: Boa resposta, `+1`

Comment: [1º parágrafo](http://programadorobjetivo.co/jquery-vs-javascript-tudo-o-que-voce-precisa-saber/) - [2º parágrafo](http://www.perguntaria.com.br/curso-preparatorio-para-o-enem-e-supletivo.aspx/diferenca-entre-as-tecnologias-ajax-jquery-e-javascript.aspx) - [A lista de vantagens](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2068/introducao-a-jquery.aspx) -
 [A lista de desvantagens](http://programadorobjetivo.co/jquery-vs-javascript-tudo-o-que-voce-precisa-saber/)

Comment: @jbueno Sou novata em programação e a pergunta me chamou a atenção, e como não conhecia do assunto resolvir pesquisar sobre e colocar aqui a resposta para ajudar pessoas futuras que possam vim ter essa mesma duvida. Como vc percebeu não me contentei com apenas uma fonte e pesquisei em uma segunda para elaborar de forma mais clara a resposta. Reconheço a minha falha de n ter colocado as referências, mas como vc tbm pode constadar ja corrigir isso.

Comment: @AlíciaTairini Excelente resposta para uma novata. Espero que responda mais e mais perguntas com essa qualidade :)

Comment: @AlíciaTairini Não precisa se explicar pra mim, eu só coloquei as referências.

Comment: AlíciaTairini: como referi em cima achei a resposta boa. Lendo com mais atênção, e como outros repararam, vejo que o conteúdo não é teu. A resposta como está é plágio de outros artigos. Na verdade não encontrei uma frase na resposta que fosse tua. O @Marconi editou e mudou nome de variáveis (não percebo bem porquê) mas até o código é copiado. Isso não é ok.

Comment: O que é bom é que te deste ao trabalho de procurar e (provavelmente) leste esses artigos. Aí seria interessante escreveres algo teu, com o conhecimento que leste lá. Como está não pode ficar. Deixo um comentário para saberes o que penso. Vou pensar mais sobre isso, [que já tem sido discutido no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5430/129). De resto gosto muito de ver novos programadores como tu a participar no site, e espero que continues com respostas deste nível, que sejam tuas.

Comment: @Sergio eu só deixei como código executável.

Comment: @Marconi o que eu não percebi porquê foi mudar as variáveis de `cabecalho` para `botao`.

Comment: @Sergio é porque tinha eventos de `click` e era pra fazer mais sentido!

Comment: @Marconi ok. Bom ter ficado executável, isso foi bom.

Comment: @Sergio Críticas são sempre bem vindas. Nas minhas próximas resposta farei o possível para colocar com minhas proprias palavras!