# Otimização de código JavaScript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual é a melhor forma de escrever o seguinte código, em JQuery?

```
document.getElementById("jogador").style.top = parseInt(document.getElementById("jogador").style.top) - v;
```

Desde o início do ano venho programando em JavaScript, porém só agora comecei com JQuery.

Comment: Qual é a razão para escrever/fazer isso em jQuery? Esse código em JavaScript nativo não funciona?

Comment: Funciona, mas recomendaram que eu começasse a utilizar somente JQuery...

Comment: Essa recomendação pode ter fundo falso. jQuery é feito em JavaScript e vai fazer o mesmo que esse código faz basicamente. Se não há uma razão específica então JS nativo é preferível. Pode ser que por questões estilísticas não se queira misturar JS com jQuery, mas em geral quanto menos jQuery melhor... dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200809/129

Comment: Mesmo assim, como eu poderia melhorar (encurtar) a linha de código da pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regra geral eu diria que quanto menos jQuery melhor.
Há uma [pergunta interessante com prós e contras aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/200809/129).

Mas para responder à tua pergunta, podes fazer isso assim em jQuery:

```js
var v = 100;
$('#jogador').css('top', function() {
  return parseInt($(this).css('top'), 10) - v;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jogador" style="top: 200px; position: absolute;">Jogador</div>
```

Se precisares de fazer isso muitas vezes podes fazer assim, evitando ler o valor no DOM, e por isso mais rápido:

```js
var moverJogador = (function(jogador) {
  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(jogador)
  var current = {
    left: parseInt(styles.left, 10),
    top: parseInt(styles.top, 10)
  }
  return function(coords) {
    for (var coord in coords) {
      current[coord] += coords[coord];
      jogador.style[coord] = current[coord] + 'px';
    }
  }
})(document.getElementById('jogador'));

moverJogador({
  top: -150,
  left: 200
});
```

```css
#jogador {
  top: 200px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left 3s, top 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jogador">Jogador</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você chama de "melhor" uma forma mais *enxuta*, então seria isto:

```
$("#jogador").css("top",parseInt($("#jogador").css("top"))-v);
```

Ou então você pode atribuir o elemento a uma variável, e ainda fica bastante curto o código:

```
e = $("#jogador");
e.css("top",parseInt(e.css("top"))-v);
```