# Como o jQuery é construído?

Tags: javascript, jquery, biblioteca

Como é sabido, o jQuery é uma biblioteca JavaScript de código aberto cuja intenção é facilitar a manipulação de elementos do DOM abreviando o código a ser usado para realizar operações e procedimentos, onde, muitas vezes, no chamado "JavaScript puro", gastaríamos mais bytes de código e seria mais complicado de fazer.

Como expressa em seu slogan "*write less, do more*", como essa biblioteca consegue abranger toda a complexa linguagem JavaScript (funções, métodos etc.) em "poucos" bytes (versão 3.2 tem cerca de 84,6KB)? Qual a lógica ou sistema usado no código fonte do jQuery que "substitui" o "JavaScript puro" nativo do navegador?

Comment: Você pode ver o código fonte [aqui](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) e [aqui](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js).

Comment: Um pouco mais: [Qual a diferença entre Javascript e jQuery?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200809/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-javascript-e-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *jQuery* tem uma *engine* base de seleção de objetos DOM. Essa *engine* retorna os objetos encapsulados em objetos próprios do jQuery. 
Esses objetos do jQuery que encapsulam os objetos DOM são extensíveis e podem manipular os objetos DOM. Em outras palavras, é possível criar extensões para fazer basicamente qualquer coisa.

Outra grande sacada é trabalhar bem com o dinamismo do javascript, passando objetos inteiros como configuradores e passando funções anonimas como forma de callback de funções. 

A questão do "do more, code less" não tem muito a ver com o tamanho do arquivo tá...(que aliás, só tem esse tamanho pq foi comprimido, a versão descomprimida tem mais de 200) É que eles fizeram um trabalho tão bem feito de encapsulamento e extensibilidade, que com uma única linha vc faz coisas que antes seriam necessárias 20, talvez até 100 linhas de código.

Answer (score 5):

> como essa biblioteca consegue abranger toda a complexa linguagem JavaScript (funções, métodos etc.)

Simples, ela não faz isto.

O texto parece indicar que acha que o jQuery substitui o JavaScript, quando na verdade é só um conjunto de funções como quaisquer outras. No fundo são só funções utilitárias que fazem o grosso do trabalho dentro dela e deixa para você só passar os parâmetros, ou seja, preencher as lacunas, que é exatamente o motivo que criamos funções.

Funções existem como abstrações para algoritmos que serão usados no código. Ele é o mecanismo de *design pattern* mais importante da programação. Você pega uma situação que se repete, ou pelo menos que seja claramente uma responsabilidade caracterizada, e reusa sempre que precisar sem se preocupar com os detalhes, e esta é a melhor forma de reuso que existe (não é OOP como muitos acham).

A função é o melhor mecanismo para se obter o DRY. E o objetivo do jQuery é diminuir a repetição de tarefas que todo mundo faz no JS várias vezes. Você apenas parametriza o que deseja.

Então a biblioteca não faz nada revolucionário, só te entrega alguns padrões prontos.

Na verdade ela é muito simples. Talvez o mecanismo mais sofisticado seja o uso de [funções anônimas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101) para parametrizar ações que devem ser executadas dentro da função do jQuery.

Obviamente que as pessoas que o fizeram sabem programar e conseguem fazer reaproveitamento de código, compor tudo o que precisam de forma eficiente na medida do possível. Hoje é muito comum vermos códigos por aí que são repetições e repetições de coisas já existentes no próprio código que a pessoa escreveu, as vezes no mesmo dia. Isto não é programar, é apenas criar códigos.

É curioso que somando o jQuery e o código da pessoa costuma ficar maior que o JS puro :) E [fica bem mais lento](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20444882/221800).

Comment: Tanto não abrange toda a linguagem como não substitui que existem infinitas bibliotecas "complementares" jQuery para fazer o serviço, como *dataTables*, gráficos, animações, responsividade...

Comment: Por isso coloquei "substitui" entre aspas porque achei essa informação incerta. :)