# Javascript não funciona após atualizar div

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um botão `Atualiza Conteudo` que se alguém clicar realiza um refresh somente na div `content` e não atualiza a pagina toda.

Até aí tudo bem, acontece que a `nova_pagina.php` que estou incluindo após o clique tras um botão de exemplo que ao ser clicado ele desaparece, usei uma função em javascript só que ele não funciona no `index.php`.

Como faço pra corrigir isso e fazer que dentro do `index.php` também funcione?

**index.php**

```
<div id="content">
</div>
<input id="updateContent" type="button" value="Atualizar Conteudo" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var url = 'nova_pagina.php';

var updateContent = document.getElementById("updateContent");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

updateContent.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      content.innerHTML = request.responseText
    }
  });
  request.send();
});
</script>
```

**nova_pagina.php**

```
<div class="mydiv">
<input type="button" class="esconderBotao" value="Esconder Botao" />
</div>

<script>    
$(".mydiv").on("click", ".esconderBotao",function () {
     $(".esconderBotao").css('display','none');  
});
</script>
```

Comment: cara, porque você ta usando jquery e fazendo ajax com js puro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os scripts retornados via AJAX não são executados automaticamente quando são carregados com a propriedade `.innerHTML`. Desta forma, você precisa "forçar" sua execução com o `eval()`:

**index.php:**

```
<div id="content">
</div>
<input id="updateContent" type="button" value="Atualizar Conteudo" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var url = 'nova_pagina.php';

var updateContent = document.getElementById("updateContent");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

updateContent.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      content.innerHTML = request.responseText;
      eval(document.getElementById('scriptAjax').innerHTML);
    }
  });
  request.send();
});
</script>
```

**nova_pagina.php:**

```
<div class="mydiv">
<input type="button" class="esconderBotao" value="Esconder Botao" />
</div>

<script id="scriptAjax">
$(".mydiv").on("click", ".esconderBotao",function () {
     $(".esconderBotao").css('display','none');  
});
</script>
```

Perceba que adicionei um `id="scriptAjax"` no script do arquivo `nova_pagina.php`. Já no `index.php` adicionei esta linha:

```
eval(document.getElementById('scriptAjax').innerHTML);
```

Ela é responsável por executar o JavaScript, selecionando-o pelo `id`.

> Mais detalhes e o mérito estão em [SOen - Calling a JavaScript function returned from AJAX response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response) *(em inglês)*.
>
> Leitura recomendada: [eval() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

---

Considerando que você está carregando a biblioteca do jQuery, uma outra alternativa é utilizar o método `.html()`. Com ele os scripts são executados normalmente quando são definidos no documento.

Basta alterar essa parte do seu script:

```
// ...
  request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      //content.innerHTML = request.responseText
      $('#content').html(request.responseText);
    }
  });
// ...
```

---

É sabido que [utilizar JavaScript puro torna sua aplicação mais rápida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200809/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-javascript-e-jquery). Principalmente caso você esteja utilizando apenas para definir o estilo de um elemento, como está no seu código:

```
<script id="scriptAjax">
    $(".mydiv").on("click", ".esconderBotao",function () {
         $(".esconderBotao").css('display','none');  
    });
</script>
```

Aí o melhor é **não utilizar o jQuery**:

```
<script id="scriptAjax">
    document.querySelector('.esconderBotao').addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.style.display = 'none';
    });
</script>
```