# Selecionar próximos elementos

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma `table` com `inputs`

```
<tr>
    <th>Linha X</th>
    <td><input type="number" name="AAA"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="BBB" onchange="xxx(this)"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="CCC" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="DDD" disabled></td>
</tr>
```

No `input` com `onchange`, executa a função `xxx()`.

O que gostaria na função é pegar os próximos `name` dos inputs, nesse caso "CCC e DDD".

Aproveitando gostaria de saber como pegar o anterior também ("AAA").

Tentei usar o `next()`, `nextAll()`, `find()`, mas não consegui.

```
var a = $(elementothis).next('input');
var a = $(elementothis).nextAll('input');
```

Comment: Na verdade vc precisa pegar o attr name dos siblings... mas tb não sei como fazer :D

Comment: @hugocsl Eu não consigo chegar no elemento rs... acho que se chegar até ele, o resto fica tranquilo. Pelo `find()` consigo buscar todos elementos `input` do form, mas não consegui posicionar o seletor no elemento que vem pelo `this`, se não era só chamar o próximo da lista... mas não deu não... rs

Comment: Vai conseguir com `parents('tr').find('th').eq(3)` depois o input. Vou fazer uns testes aqui.

Comment: @LaércioLopes não tem uma forma mais dinâmica?

Comment: this.parentElement.nextSibling.querySelector('input');

Comment: @rbz, não sei outra...

Comment: @DaviAragao Isso não é jQuery não né!? rs

Comment: É JavaScript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como já foi explicado, o `<input>` de onde parte o código não tem irmãos, e está sozinho no `<td>`, logo tanto `next`, como `nextAll` ou `find` não encontram nada. Precisa de primeiro ir para até ao `<td>` (pai), depois navegar para outro `<td>` e aceder ao seu filho.

Pode fazer isso com `parent`, `next`, `children` e `first`

```js
function xxx(elem){
  $(elem).parent().next().children().first().val("150");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Linha X</th>
      <td><input type="number" name="AAA"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="BBB" onchange="xxx(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="CCC" disabled></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="DDD" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Ou de forma mais dinamica com `closest` e `find`:

```js
function xxx(elem){
  $(elem).closest("tr").find("[name=CCC]").val("150");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Linha X</th>
      <td><input type="number" name="AAA"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="BBB" onchange="xxx(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="CCC" disabled></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="DDD" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Esta forma é mais dinâmica e torna o html mais flexível, para além de ser mais simples também.

O `closest` navega para cima até ao `<tr>`, e o `find` navega para baixo até ao elemento que interessa de acordo com o seletor especificado.

Se precisar de aceder a vários é melhor utilizar um seletor genérico no `find` e obter o array que representa os elementos capturados:

```js
function xxx(elem){
  const inputs = $(elem).closest("tr").find("input");
  
  inputs.eq(0).val("100"); //AAA  
  inputs.eq(2).val("150"); //CCC
  inputs.eq(3).val("200"); //DDD
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Linha X</th>
      <td><input type="number" name="AAA"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="BBB" onchange="xxx(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="CCC" disabled></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="DDD" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

O acesso à posição é dado pelo método `eq`. Lembre-se que com este seletor captura todos os `<input>` incluindo o próprio de onde partiu o evento.

Comment: Isac, o `find` eu estava tentando usar da seguinte maneira: Pego todos elementos `input` do form, gerando uma lista. Então tenho todos input e o elemento do contexto (que veio pelo this). Se eu conseguisse identificar na lista o input do contexto, eu daria um `next` na lista, e conseguiria selecionar o próximo. Da forma que fez não ficou dinâmico porque você travou o atributo name...

Comment: @rbz Mas o find permite achar vários. Dei um exemplo com o name so para ser simples, mas quando acabar de almoçar já meto aqui outro.  basicamente .closest("tr").find("input") acha todos os input da lista e por isso todos os irmãos.

Comment: Sim, ele acha todos.. automaticamente eu teria a lista na sequência... como minha função trás o elemento ( `onchange=xxx(this)` ), eu conseguiria posicionar o cursor na lista... aí só daria next... e colocaria até X valor de quantos inputs pular... não?

Comment: @rbz Sim acha todos, e basta aceder ao elemento correto com `eq` por exemplo. Já editei a minha resposta para dar esse exemplo também.

Comment: Deu certo, mas tive que travar a posição... pois se tenho `tr` com quantidades diferentes de `td`, ele busca errado se travar a posição no `eq`...

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que os `input` estão dentro de `td`.

A [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/next/) de `.next()` diz que o método pega o elemento irmão imediato ao informado no seu seletor.

Uma solução simples para o problema usando JavaScript seria assim:

```
this.parentElement.nextSibling.querySelector('input');
```

Para acessar o `input` na `td` acima fica parecido, precisa mudar pouca coisa:

```
this.parentElement.previousSibling.querySelector('input');
```

[jQuery é JavaScript.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200809/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-javascript-e-jquery)

Comment: DaviAragao, sei que jQuery é JS, mas eu realmente gostaria da solução em jQuery, para não ficar misturando... Se não houver outra saída, aí sim terei que usar o JS...

Comment: É simples @rbz, refatore o seu código todo tirando jQuery :)