# Pegar noticias de um site de automaticamente

Tags: android

Estou criando um aplicativo e nele vai ter a parte de noticias , como faço com que ele pegue de forma automatica as postagens desse site? como no aplicativo a seguir que achei na internet .
 Ele pega a imagem da postagem o titulo e uma prévia da postagem , e ao clicar ele envia para o site , poderiam me ajudar? obrigado !

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então, de maneira automatizada, só se o site tiver um rss ou uma API e você usar um client para consumir. Caso contrário ou você mostra um webview ou usa jSoup para fazer scrap do html e extrair os dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente você vai ter que estudar a API do site e ver como ela retorna os dados (em geral uma String JSON) e se precisa de chave de aplicação para fazer o acesso. Depois é só implementar rotinas para se conectar na API, obter o JSON, fazer o parsing do mesmo para pegar apenas os dados necessários, definir como armazenar esses dados (ArrayList, Banco de Dados) e exibi-los numa lista (RecyclerView).

Todos esses passos não são triviais para detalhar aqui. Te dei uma estratégia mínima macro, mais como um checklist.

Se quiser se aprofundar, esse curso detalha cada item que citei com alguns projetos que fazem exatamente o que você quer:

https://br.udacity.com/course/android-basics-networking--ud843/

Comment: Obrigado , ajudou bastante

Answer (score 3):

Você possui duas alternativas para solucionar este problema:

1. Caso você tenha desenvolvido o site o qual deseja pegar as informações, desenvolva também uma [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework) que te envie estas informações. Para consumir esta API utilizando o Android, você pode utilizar da biblioteca [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley).
2. Caso você não tenha desenvolvido o site o qual deseja pegar as informações, desenvolva um [crawler](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/otimizacao__seo/qual-a-diferenca-entre-robo-spider-e-crawler) que percorra o site e salve as informações em um local que você pode acessar com o seu app (pode ser também uma API online).