# Gravar dados de app desenvolvido com react-native em um banco remoto PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, react-native

Bom estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em react-native.

Nesse aplicativo vai basicamente ter alguns formulários para cadastro de informações, porém estas informações devem ser salvas em um bd PostgreSQL o qual já é utilizado por um sistema.

Pesquisando encontrei o https://node-postgres.com/ acredito que daria para utilizar na aplicação (estou certo?) porém este anuncio https://node-postgres.com/announcements me deixou desconfortável, mas não encontrei outra alternativa, alguém possui alguma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar o React Native junto com o PostgreSQL você precisará de alguma linguagem no back-end que consiga se comunicar com o SGBD em questão, como PHP, Java ou até mesmo o Node.js como o tutorial que você citou.

Uma vez que escolher a linguagem, desenvolva uma [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework) para que o seu aplicativo possa fazer [requests](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) para a API desenvolvida e então consumir ou escrever os dados presentes no seu banco PostgreSQL.