# O que é Stencil JS?

Tags: aplicação-web, web-component

Atualmente, muito se fala sobre os *web components* e *custom elements*, e junto com grandes nomes, como Angular, React, Vue e Polymer, recentemente começou a surgir o nome [Stencil JS](https://stenciljs.com).

- O que é [Stencil JS](https://stenciljs.com)?
- É mais um framework para disputar o mercado de componentes web?
- Se não, qual a relação entre o Stencil JS e outros frameworks?
- Quais são os diferenciais desta ferramenta e quais foram as necessidades que estimularam sua criação que as outras ferramentas não satisfazem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

StencilJS é um *compilador* para *web components*, ou seja, você escreverá seu componente utilizando [jsx](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) e então o Stencil no processo de *build*, gerará um *web component* nativo com algumas funcionalidades a mais como *data binding*, *async redering*, *virtual DOM* que enriquecerá o funcionamento do componente.

Criar componentes utilizando puramente a API de *web components* é bem verboso e geralmente difícil (para componentes mais complexos). Dessa forma StencilJS vem com a proposta de facilitar o desenvolvimento de *web components*, trazendo tecnologias já comuns no mundo *frontend* como tsx para criação de componentes para facilitar o desenvolvimento.

O time do Ionic criou o StencilJS para utilizar na nova versão do Ionic que está sendo desenvolvido utilizando *web components* construídos com StencilJS. Dessa forma será possível utilizar StencilJS para criar aplicativos móveis usando Ionic assim como qualquer outro framework web como Angular, React, Vue, etc.

StencilJS utiliza [*decorators*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) para abstrair as funcionalidades nativas de *web components*, trazendo mais facilidade ao desenvolvedor. Alguns *decorators* úteis para desenvolver um componente:

- `@Prop` controla a atribuição de valores à propriedades do componente.
- `@PropWillChange` e `@PropDidChange` observa as mudanças de estado das propriedades do componente.
- `@Event` emite [*custom events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)
- `@Listen` escuta eventos nativos do DOM e [*custom events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) também.

Todos os componentes construídos com Stencil são carregados de forma *lazy*, ou seja, os componentes podem ser separados em *bundles* diferentes (que serão gerados no processo de *build*). Assim se tivermos o componente **a** em um *bundle* e o componente **b** em outro *bundle*, ao adicionar o componente **a** na sua página será carregado apenas o *bundle* do componente **a** e não o *bundle* do componente **b** também. Isso diminui muito o tempo de carregamento necessário para utilizar os componentes desejados.

StencilJS não é um *framework*, mas sim um *compilador* para *web components* como dito antes.

StencilJS também adiciona *polyfills* de *web components* necessários para que seus componentes funcionem corretamente. Note que os *polyfills* serão adicionados na medida que necessários, conforme o suporte de cada browser a *web components*.

Veja a documentação oficial que pode ser acessada no [site oficial](https://stenciljs.com).

Veja também o [GitHub do projeto](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil).

Comment: Algumas informações que julgaria interessante são quais seriam esses *polyfills* adicionados e como é gerenciado internamente esse "na medida que necessário" acerca destes polyfills. Também cita que o Stencil gera um *web component* com funcionalidades a mais; seria interessante listar quais seriam essas funcionalidades. Qualquer coisa, te convido a entrar no [chat Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), onde podemos conversar melhor.

Comment: Oi @AndersonCarlosWoss, melhorei a explicação e adicionei alguns detalhes a mais também.

Comment: ps: `compiler` é `compilador`, o termo em inglês no sentido da tal tecnologia tem o mesmo sentido. Se discordarem usem o botão/link "Reverter" que fica na tela de edições.

Answer (score -4):

Fonte: https://stenciljs.com/

O que é Stencil JS?
O Stencil combina alguns dos melhores recursos das estruturas tradicionais, mas fornece elementos personalizados compatíveis com padrões 100%, parte da especificação do componente Web.

---

É mais um framework para disputar o mercado de componentes web?

### SIM

Se não, qual a relação entre o Stencil JS e outros frameworks?

### É sim.

Quais são os diferenciais desta ferramenta e quais foram as necessidades que estimularam sua criação que as outras ferramentas não satisfazem?

O Stencil foi criado pela equipe do Ionic Framework para criar aplicativos móveis e web mais rápidos e poderosos. O Stencil é a base para a próxima geração do Ionic Framework, mas é completamente independente da estrutura Ionic ou de qualquer outro interface de usuário.

Comment: Com qual base você afirma que ele é um framework?

Comment: Definição de framework: "Um framework em desenvolvimento de software, é uma abstração que une códigos comuns entre vários projetos de software provendo uma funcionalidade genérica. Um framework pode atingir uma funcionalidade específica, por configuração, durante a programação de uma aplicação"

Comment: Posso estar falando merda, mas acho que ele não é um `Framework`, se não me engano, ele é a forma de desenvolver em IONIC e escolher o seu Framework, seja Angular, Vue, React e etc. Mas como falei, posso estar errado, mas lembro de ter lido algo do tipo. Se estiver errado, desculpem meu comentario.

Comment: Durante a Cúpula de Polímeros de 2017, Max Lynch e Adam Bradley da Ionic (Framework) apresentaram seu novo esforço na Web Components, o compilador Stencil.js.
Usando o Stencil, os desenvolvedores podem desenvolver componentes de estrutura-agnostic (Web). Como tal, podemos esperar que a biblioteca IONIC esteja disponível como Componentes da Web, portanto, livre de dependências Angulares.
Vale ressaltar que o Stencil não é uma estrutura, e sim um compilador que produz componentes web da vanilla.

Comment: Em quase todas as fontes é comentado que o Stencil não é um framework. No site oficial, em nenhum momento é dito que é também. Fora isso, o próprio site oficial traz que ele **não é** uma ferramenta que veio para bater com os frameworks atuais, tanto que uma de suas vantagens é que o Stencil pode ser utilizado sem nenhuma dificuldade em conjunto com esses frameworks. Ao meu entender, sua resposta é insuficiente perante os questionamentos da pergunta.

Comment: Mais sobre _framework_: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/64969

Comment: Pela descrição do @henriquecustodia, lembra muito mais uma parte de _toolchain_ do que com _framework_, a principal característica corroborando para essa conclusão é que ele é usado a nível de complicação

Comment: Nada contra a resposta, mas isso aqui ficou soando uma propaganda *O Stencil combina alguns dos melhores recursos das estruturas tradicionais*, acho que quem define o que é melhor é quem usa, claro que pra eles falarem no site que são os melhores é uma maneira de se promover, mas para um Q&A de programadores isso não tem utilidade alguma técnica e nem dá pra ser afirmativo.