# O que é a linguagem Mint?

Tags: característica-linguagem

Quando tratado de frameworks JavaScript percebemos que existem uma infinidade de opções, com novas surgindo a todo instante. Angular, Vue, React, [Svelte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/396224/5878), [Stencil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245132/5878) e outras que nem sou capaz de lembrar. Alguns autodenominados frameworks, outros dizem claramente que não são framework, apenas um conjunto de ferramentas, outros dizem ser pré-compiladores, etc.

Mais recentemente percebi a existência do [Mint](https://www.mint-lang.com/), que acredito ser o primeiro a se denominar **linguagem de programação**.

> The programming language for writing single page applications.

Nesse contexto, é fácil lembrar da existência do TypeScript, que é um *superset* do próprio JavaScript, porém não parece ser essa a intenção do Mint.

Então o que torna o Mint uma linguagem de programação direcionada ao desenvolvimento de SPA? O que difere ela do TypeScript?

Comment: Criei a tag `mint-lang` devido a existência da [tag:mint] já relacionada ao sistema operacional Mint.

Comment: a resposta não foi suficiente? posso por mais detalhes, só diga o que não está faltando :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual Foi boa, mas como a recompensa é para atrair mais a atenção para a pergunta, estou deixando rolar até o final da recompensa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como citado na pergunta e no link oficial do `Mint`:

> The programming language for writing single page applications

Em tradução livre:

> A linguagem de programação para escrever aplicativos SPA (de uma única
> página)

Isso quer dizer que, diferente do `javascript` e do próprio `typescript`, que tem um escopo, um propósito mais abrangente, o `Mint` é focado em criar uma aplicação *frontend*, e mais especificamente, uma aplicação **SPA** (*Single Page Application*).

O `Javascript` e o `Typescript` (como extensão do `Javascript`) podem ser usados para escrever aplicações *frontend*  que não sejam SPA, assim como aplicações *backend*, o que já diferencia o seu propósito. Isso por si responde no que o `Mint` é diferente: ele é específico para aplicações SPA.

Mas para tal propósito, ele tem o que é necessário para criar uma aplicação **SPA**?

Essa outra pergunta [O que é SPA e no que se diferencia de uma página não SPA?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212952/o-que-%C3%A9-spa-e-no-que-se-diferencia-de-uma-p%C3%A1gina-n%C3%A3o-spa)
 tem uma resposta com uma síntese simples e clara de entender do que é uma **SPA**:

> Uma SPA (Single Page Aplication) é uma aplicação que não recarrega a
> página durante o seu tempo de vida.

Ou seja, é uma aplicação (Web) que não faz aqueles costumeiros "reloads" da página quando se navega ou faz determinadas ações. Por se tratar de uma aplicação Web, uma SPA deve utilizar `HTML` e `CSS`, que são a base para o navegador exibir a página.

Para controlar o seu comportamento, os navegadores dão suporte ao `Javascript`, logo a linguagem deve ou dar total suporte, ou gerar código compatível com `Javascript`, para ao final ser suportada pelos navegadores. Assim como `typescript`, o `Mint` é compilado:

> It is a compiler and a framework combined to provide great developer
> experience while allowing to write safe, readable and maintainable
> code.

Em tradução livre:

> É um compilador e uma estrutura combinados para fornecer uma ótima
> experiência de desenvolvedor, permitindo escrever um código seguro,
> legível e sustentável.

Informação retirada daqui: https://www.mint-lang.com/guide

Ou seja, a linguagem tem o que é preciso para desenvolver uma aplicação SPA, que vai funcionar nos navegadores de mercado.

Se olharmos os exemplos de código, notamos a presença do `HTML`, `CSS` e a lógica da linguagem, para dar suporte ao estados, rotas, etc, elementos essenciais para uma aplicação Web e uma aplicação SPA:

```
component Counter {
  state counter = 0

  fun increment {
    next { counter = counter + 1 }
  }

  fun decrement {
    next { counter = counter - 1 }
  }

  fun render {
    <div>
      <button onClick={decrement}>
        "Decrement"
      </button>

      <span>
        <{ Number.toString(counter) }>
      </span>

      <button onClick={increment}>
        "Increment"
      </button>
    </div>
  }
}

component TodoItem {
  property color = "#333"
  property label = ""
  property done = false

  style base {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
  }

  style label {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #{color};
    flex: 1;

    if (done) {
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }
  }

  fun render {
    <div::base>
      <span::label>
        <{ label }>
      </span>

      <Icon.Checkmark/>
      <Icon.Trash/>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando o que foi dito, Mint tem a pretendencia de ser mais cognitivo para permitir um ambiente de desenvolvimento mais voltado para o produto. Isto pode ser visto nos comentários do próprio autor da linhaguem.

> gdotdesign on Feb 5, 2020 | parent | favorite | on: Mint: A
> programming language for writing single pa...
>
> Author of the language here, I think it is a major advantage for
> several reasons:
>
> - the documentation is in one place instead of several places
> - the dependencies of a Mint project is usually a few megabytes since everything is included instead of hundreds of megabytes (I have a
>   production app that does not have any dependencies at all)
> - only need to learn one (compact) thing, instead of many complex things (complex since there is no compiler to make it simple)
> - only need to update the code once there is a new version of the language not every time there is a new version of a dependency
>
> On top of the libraries mentioned the language also includes a
> formatter, package manager, builder/dev server and testing
> environment, also for which you would need to add dependencies.
>
> All of these add up to less cognitive load so I can focus on building
> the product instead of managing the development environment.

Fonte: [Artigo](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22247506)