# Handler? O que é isso e para que serve em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++

Há tempos que eu vejo muitos código utilizando esse tipo **HANDLER**. O que é e para que serve? Onde encontro tutoriais que ensinam a utilizá-lo.

Comment: Seria bom um exemplo de código. HANDLE != HANDLER, são coisas relacionadas, mas distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HANDLE pode ser qualquer coisa de um índice inteiro para um ponteiro para um recurso no espaço do kernel. A idéia é que eles fornecem uma abstração de um recurso, então você não precisa saber muito sobre o próprio recurso para usá-lo.

Por exemplo, o HWND na API Win32 é um tipo HANDLE  para uma janela. Por si só, é inútil: você não pode recolher nenhuma informação dele. Mas passe para as funções da API corretas, e você pode realizar uma série de truques diferentes com ela. Internamente, você pode pensar no HWND como apenas um índice na tabela de janelas da GUI (o que talvez não seja como é implementado, mas faz com que a magia faça sentido).

Comment: Só uma pequena observação de terminologia HWND é HANDLE e não HANDLER. Handle é a referência (a "maçaneta", por onde você pega o objeto) - Handler é o manipulador. Exemplo de handler: algo que atende um protocolo especifico, como o skype ao lidar com um URL assim: skype://nomedocontato - Exemplo de handle: HWND janela.... file = fopen( .... etc

Answer (score 5):

Não há tutoriais sobre isso e nem é nosso objetivo.

A pergunta fala em HANDLER, que não parece ser o caso. O contexto indica que quer saber sobre o tipo `HANDLE` ou o conceito de *handle*, que é diferente de *handler*.

`HANDLE` não é um tipo do C ou C++, é da [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) Windows. Este tipo é só um ponteiro para `void`, ou seja, pode ser qualquer coisa. Mas isto é detalhe de implementação. Quase todos os tipos que começam com `H` [nessa documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) são *handles*.

Existem vários objetos de manipulação diferentes. Nem todos possuem este nome. Um `FP` padrão do C (para manipular arquivos) não deixa de ser um *handle*. O [`HWND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/relationship-between-a-cpp-window-object-and-an-hwnd?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-170) é um dos mais usados do Windows por cuidar da janela.

O [conceito de *handle* é mais genérico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)). Ele é um objeto que guarda informações relevantes para acesso a um recurso externo. Ele indica qual é o recurso (um identificador do sistema operacional ou serviço ou um ponteiro).

Um *handler* é o agente que usará um objeto, que fará alguma ação requerida, em geral em programação é um código seu escrito com o propósito de executar algo em cima de um *handle*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).