# O que é uma Engine?

Tags: terminologia, razor, engine

Li um artigo sobre o Razor. Esse artigo diz que se trata de uma *engine view*, mas o que vem a ser uma *engine*? De acordo com o artigo o Razor é uma nova sintaxe que trabalha com CSS e HTML para facilitar a vida dos programadores com um código mais limpo e legível.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Engine é como se fosse um motor com suporte a varias funções especificas para cada tipo de uso no caso do Razor como citado é uma engine View que trabalha com modo  gráfico HTML e CSS, as engines são feitas para facilitar a vida em geral de um programador trazendo com ela funções pré-programadas facilitando seu uso no  dia a dia.

Existem  vários tipos de Engines como Game Engine : Uma  muito  conhecida é a Nvidia, Unity entre outras.

As engines são  nada mais nada menos do que bibliotecas que facilitam  sua compilação, e descomplica grandes syntaxs, Imagine só  se você precisasse criar uma função para exibir uma tabela de  produtos ? Poderia ser um pouco  trabalhoso  no caso do Razor você pode utilizar o DataGrid apenas passando os parâmetros necessários, e deixando  que o Razor faça o trabalho por você de buscar e organizar os dados na tabela.

> Bom saber

O termo “game engine” originou-se no meio da década de 1990, especialmente em conexão com jogos 3D, como tiro em primeira pessoa. O primeiro motor 3D a ser usado para criar jogos de computador foi o Freescape Engine, desenvolvido pela Incentive Software em 1986, usado para criar jogos de tiro em primeira pessoa a partir de 1987. Preços de motores de jogos variam muito, desde a gratuidade e valores baixos, como US$ 99,00, até valores exorbitantes como US$ 31.200,00 ou mais caros. O processo de desenvolvimento de jogos é frequentemente agilizado, quando um mesmo motor de jogo é usado para criar diferentes jogos

**Fonte**

[WikiPedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_de_jogo)

Comment: No caso do Razor, por que dizer que é um "motor"? Quando você disse uma biblioteca, eu consigo imaginar várias classes com suas funções, etc. Mas um motor...

Comment: sim, necesse caso é uma classe com varias funções, que agrupadas geram  esse motor; vamos imaginar um motor de um carro  com suas varias peças juntas fazendo ele funcionar, no caso  do  razor creio  que ele é em c#, ele não  deixa se ser uma biblioteca, mas  ganha esse titulo de engine por porssuir  muitas funcionalidade que de ante-mão te facilitando  assim poupando-o tempo e escrevendo menas  linhas de  codigo o conceito de engine pode parecer um pouco complexo mas  tendo  em mente q ela é uma junção de funcionalidades que poderiam ser escritas por vc mas  q por conveniencia já estão prontas

Comment: O Razor é o motor, pois ele faz as coisas funcionarem. Consegue me dar exemplos do que seriam as outras partes do "carro"?

Answer (score 6):

Engine neste contexto pode ser um [*framework*, uma biblioteca, um conjunto de ferramentas, um SDK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101), ou seja, softwares que estão disponíveis para desempenhar uma tarefa específica e que fora desenvolvido, provavelmente, por especialistas.

O desenvolver provavelmente tratará como SDK ou algo semelhante quando está desenvolvendo. Mas quando estiver rodando não terá o conjunto completo, mas só o executável que fará o trabalho que ele precisa, portanto é só a biblioteca que fará o trabalho.

O termo é muito usado em jogos e outras formas de renderização, mas pode ser usado para diversas qualificações. O Google é um *engine* de busca.

O *engine* que costuma ser traduzido como motor, mas eu prefiro mecanismo. Ele é o que faz funcionar algo, é a parte principal de algo maior e sem ele o maior não serviria para nada ou seria muito difícil criá-lo.

O Razor é um renderizador de páginas HTML, assim como o navegador tem um renderizador, mas no navegador o *engine* pega o HTML e outros componentes e desenha na tela o que for preciso, enquanto o Razor pega um código, que pode ter HTML padrão, HTML que só ele entende, e programação mesmo (em geral C#), e cria o código HTML puro padrão que será entregue para o servidor HTTP.

Ele pode ser usado em qualquer aplicação que precise gerar HTML. O primeiro uso dele é renderizar a *view* do ASP.NET MVC. Ainda é muito usado no ASP.NET Core. Mas há gente usando isoladamente, ou seus próprios *engines* de MVC ou outra forma de lidar como interação via HTML.

O Razor permite que misture códigos de linguagens diferentes (HTML/C#), e que partes destes códigos sejam executados no momento da renderização. As primeiras versões dele só o C# podia fazer isto, mas agora é possível até mesmo usar HTML personalizado que ele entende e transforma no que é padrão, desde que tenha um componente que o ensine fazer a transformação de forma adequada, e este componente será escrito em C# em outro local. Então ele é tão poderoso que você pode criar suas próprias *tags* HTML (que os navegadores não entenderão, por isso é feita a transformação para um código padrão W3C.

Neste caso todo o código controle da *view*, o *controller*, o *model*, o tratamento de rotas, todas essas coisas do MVC não as outras "partes do carro". O MVC não deixa de ser um *engine*. Você pode ter motores dentro de motores, ou motores auxiliares trabalhando em conjunto com o principal.

O .NET não deixa de ser um *engine*, embora não seja comum usar esse termo.

Um computador é o dispositivo (*device*), mas raramente se usa este termo. *Engine* é um termo bastante geral que tomou mais forma em algumas áreas da computação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então EngineCode seria um conjunto de códigos? por exemplo um código que faz diversas funçoes?

Comment: @MariaClara desconheço o termo.