# Quais são as variações do ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Quais são as variações existentes dentro de ASP.NET?

As principais características e para que tipo de atividade elas são mais recomendadas?

Ao pesquisar tenho me deparado por exemplo com ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core, ASP.NET Razor.

Cheguei a pesquisar sobre, mas não consegui compreender muito bem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ASP.NET

Inicialmente era o que chamamos hoje de WebForms. O WebForms foi muito usado, mas já caiu em desuso e, aparentemente, caiu no desgosto do pessoal. Não posso dizer com detalhes, mas a ideia do WebForms era construir uma aplicação web que fosse mais parecida com as aplicações desktop, tentando manter estado. Você pode ver algumas informações sobre estado em [O que é um "protocolo sem estado", como o HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/18246).

Hoje em dia o nome representa mais a plataforma em si. Tanto que, no Visual Studio, para criar uma aplicação web é primeiro necessário escolher o tipo ***ASP.NET Application*** e só depois é preciso especificar se é WebForms, MVC, WebAPI, etc.

Cada um destes "tipos" têm uma forma diferente de trabalhar, estas vão desde a filosofia e o padrão do projeto a até como o código é escrito.

### ASP.NET MVC

É um "tipo de projeto" ASP.NET que segue o padrão MVC (Model-View-Controller) — você pode ler mais sobre o padrão MVC em [O que é MVC(Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/18246). Nele é praticamente intrínseco o ASP.NET Razor (falo abaixo sobre ele) como *view engine*, nas versões antigas ainda era possível escolher entre o Razor e se chama de ASPX (que também acabou caindo em desuso).

### ASP.NET WebAPI

É também um tipo de projeto ASP.NET que tem como objetivo atender requisições HTTP (assim como no ASP.NET MVC), mas sem precisar se preocupar com as *views* (ao contrário do ASP.NET MVC).

De qualquer forma, a organização do projeto é muito parecida com a do ASP.NET MVC.

### ASP.NET Core

é o **novo ASP.NET**. Sim, o *framework* foi reprojetado e reescrito (assim como .NET Framework). Este já teve outros nomes como: ASP.NET vNext ou ASP.NET 5, como pode ser [visto aqui](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/12/the-next-generation-of-net-asp-net-vnext/).

### ASP.NET Razor

É a *view engine* por trás das aplicações ASP.NET MVC (e também nas aplicações do Core). Esta ferramenta é responsável por renderizar o código escrito nos arquivos **.cshtml**, **.vbhtml** e similares para código HTML. Para mais detalhes sobre *view engines* você pode ler a pergunta [O que é uma Engine?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/284935/18246), mais especificamente a [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/284935/18246) que fala sobre o Razor em si.

No ASP.NET Core, existe também o ASP.NET Razor Pages. Ele é uma espécie de simplificação do que já existe no ASP.NET Core MVC. É recomendado pra casos mais simples que não precisem de toda a burocracia do MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar as respostas do LINQ

**ASP.Net**

ASP.Net é uma plataforma para criar aplicações Web. É como uma junção das antigas páginas ASP Clássico e o .Net Framework. No ASP clássico escrevíamos o código de servidor em meio ao HTML, então o servidor lia este código e renderizava a página de acordo com as instruções em VBScript (linguagem utilizada nas páginas ASP Clássico juntamente com HTML). O ASP.Net nasceu da junção do melhor que tinha no ASP Clássico com o framework .Net.

**ASP.Net Core**

Há pouco tempo o código do framework .Net começou a ser reescrito para ser mais modular e multiplataforma, sendo assim o .Net Core é a evolução do .Net. Sendo assim, ASP.Net Core é uma evolução do ASP.Net que também foi reescrito.

**ASP.Net MVC e Razor**

MVC é um padrão de arquitetura de software onde a lógica de negócio (domínio do negócio) é separada da apresentação (Página da web ou tela de um programa) e a interação entre as duas camadas é feita através da *Controller*. O ASP.Net MVC é uma plataforma que tem como base o ASP.Net e a arquitetura MVC e implementa funcionalidades para melhor trabalhar com as interações entre o Modelo, a Visão e o Controlador. O Controle e a lógica de negócios (Modelo) são escritos em linguagem de servidor, ou seja, C# ou VB. Para que o servidor possa se comunicar com a camada de Visão (apresentação) é necessário que as páginas HTML tenham códigos de servidor também. É possível escrever HTML + C# em um mesmo arquivo, assim o servidor interpreta o C# e renderiza a página HTML pro usuário com as instruções passadas pela linguagem. Para facilitar ainda mais este processo nasceu o Razor, que é a plataforma de renderização para o ASP.Net MVC. Com o Razor você pode criar páginas com código C# de forma mais produtiva pois facilita muito a interação entre a Visão e o Controle. O código Razor (arquivos *.cshtml que são escritos em HTML, C# e diretivas Razor) é interpretado pelo servidor e renderizado de acordo com as informações e instruções passadas em Razor (pseudo-linguagem) e C#.

**Conclusão**

Uma plataforma é o complemento da outra para realizar um objetivo específico. .Net Core é a base para o ASP.Net, que permite criar páginas da web renderizadas pelo servidor. ASP.Net MVC é o padrão MVC implementado na plataforma ASP.Net, funcionando como plataforma com funcionalidades que facilitam as interações MVC. Razor é uma pseudolinguagem de programação, que funciona na camada de Visão do MVC, que é interpretada pelo servidor e assim gerada a página HTML.