# Qsort ordenando de forma errada

Tags: c, classificação

A minha atividade e ler uma frase e ordenada em ordem alfabeticamente, mas está dando erro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ordena(const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return strcmp((char *)a, (char *)b); 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char **nomes, frase[900], *ponteiro;
  nomes = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3000);
  int indice, cont = 0, i;
  for(indice = 0; indice < 3000; indice++)
  {
    nomes[indice] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  }

  scanf("%[^\n]", frase);

  ponteiro = strtok(frase, " ");
  while(ponteiro != NULL)
  {
     strcpy(nomes[cont], ponteiro);
     cont++;
     ponteiro = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  qsort((void*)nomes, cont, sizeof(nomes[0]), ordena);
  for(i = 0; i < cont; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", nomes[i]);
  }

   return 0;
}
```

Exemplo de entrada carne laranja suco picles laranja picles

Exemplo de saida carne laranja laranja picles picles suco

Comment: Para mim, o seu programa gera como saída `picles picles laranja laranja suco carne`. Não consegui achar onde está o erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu problema é na verdade bem tipico no `qsort`, que é esquecer-se que a função de comparação recebe ponteiros para os valores do array. Logo se tiver um array de `ints` a função de comparação recebe dois `int*`. No seu caso se tem um array de `char*` a função vai receber dois `char**`, o que faz com que isto:

```
int ordena(const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return strcmp((char *)a, (char *)b);
                     ^----------^ 
}
```

Não esteja correto.

Em vez disso tem de interpretar cada parâmetro como um `char**` e aceder ao valor apontado que será o `char*` que pretende:

```
int ordena(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    char **palavra1 = (char**) a; //interpretar como char**
    char **palavra2 = (char**) b; //interpretar como char**
    return strcmp(*palavra1, *palavra2); //comparar o apontado de cada um
}
```

Com essa alteração a saída dá:

```
carne
laranja
laranja
picles
picles
suco
```

[Veja a execução no Ideone](https://ideone.com/XI2w9T)

Como nota, o *cast* para `void*` no `qsort` não é necessário, acabando por ficar mais simples e legível sem ele:

```
qsort((void*)nomes, cont, sizeof(nomes[0]), ordena);
        ^---este
```

Comment: Por que `strcmp(*palavra1, *palavra2)` e não `strcmp(palavra1, palavra2)`?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Porque na minha função de comparação `palavra1` é um `char**` e não um `char*`, logo é preciso buscar valor apontado com `*palavra1`. Mas isso não é diferente do que você fez no seu código com `*(char**)item1` em contraste com `(char**)palavra1`. Se olhar com atenção vai reparar que o seu tem o `*` a mais, que no meu ficou na chamada ao `strcmp`.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Como adenda ao que já disse, não vejo como a sua resposta seja diferente da minha, com a agravante de nem tão pouco explicar o que fez ou deixou de fazer, deixando um mero "Veja se isto resolve..."

Comment: Eu ofereci uma resposta completa. O (meu) programa executa, como deve de se esperar que faça.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Devo lembrar que o objetivo do StackOverflow não é promover o *copy* paste cego de código de resposta. A primeira coisa relevante é que o autor da pergunta **perceba** o que fez mal e porque estava mal, para então conseguir perceber a solução e implementa-la. Oferecer uma resposta apenas com código não é o que nós queremos fazer no SOpt, e isso foi basicamente o que você fez. Se eu faço uma pergunta e me dão duas páginas de código com "Veja se isto resolve", como eu sei o que fiz mal para evitar de o fazer de novo ?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Mas não se deixe influenciar pelas minhas palavras, abra qualquer resposta com boa pontuação nesta rede e veja se elas tem apenas código com um "Veja se isto resolve".

Comment: Faz parte do processo de aprendizagem de um *coder* saber ler código. Um empregador de terceira categoria não se importaria de usar este e outros códigos para testar candidatos.

Comment: Muito obrigado isac

Comment: Muito também Marcelo

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Você está propositadamente a desvirtuar o que está a ser dito. O proposito de uma resposta no SOpt não é forçar o autor da pergunta a saber ler código escrito por outros, nem preparar candidatos para o mercado do trabalho. A ideia é fornecer conteúdo sobre questões de programação que seja direto, acessível e percetivel a tantas pessoas quanto possíveis.

Comment: Então o StackOverflow seria como o pronto-socorro do doente raro? Ou do doente terminal, o que for mais virtuoso?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Essa questão está totalmente desfasada da realidade. Você tem muitas perguntas nesta rede e na rede inglesa do SO apenas nível teórico sobre determinados conceitos de programação. Nesses casos é visível que o autor procura apenas esclarecer o conceito ou aprofundar o seu conhecimento nele. Independentemente disso, não vejo sequer como o que disse se relaciona com o que eu havia dito anteriormente. Mas nada melhor que um exemplo.Diga-me se [esta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework) é um pronto socorro?

Comment: @Isac, é um pronto-socorro de divagações. O(A) questionador(a) pode refletir e achar a conclusão por conta própria, mas como acha que não pode, ou como acha que não **quer**, que é o mais provável, ostenta a pergunta no fórum para que outras pessoas concluam por ele(a).

Comment: @Isac, sinto muito se meu pragmatismo lhe atinge, mas é meu estilo. Não estou aqui para shows, mas, sim, resolver problemas.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Amigo nada do que você está a dizer me "atinge". Eu estou apenas na minha boa fé a tentar mostrar-lhe como a comunidade SOpt funciona, algo que vim percebendo com o tempo todo que já tenho de participação ativa nela. Mas parece me que você não está nem ai, e por isso termino rapidamente aqui o nosso debate.

Answer (score 0):

Preste muita atenção à desalocação de memória RAM após o uso! `free` neles!

Veja se isto resolve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** palavras;

int comparador(const void* item1, const void* item2)
{
    char* elemento1 = *(char**)item1;
    char* elemento2 = *(char**)item2;

    return strcmp(elemento1, elemento2);
}

int main()
{
    char palavra[80];
    int qtdPalavras;
    int tamanhoPalavra;
    int i;

    do
    {
        palavras = NULL;

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite a frase (8 para sair): ");

        qtdPalavras = 0;
        do {
            scanf("%s", palavra);
            tamanhoPalavra = strlen(palavra);
            if (*palavra != '8')
            {
                palavras = (char**)realloc(palavras, (qtdPalavras + 1) * sizeof(char*));
                palavras[qtdPalavras] = (char*)malloc((tamanhoPalavra + 1) * sizeof(char));
                strcpy(palavras[qtdPalavras], palavra);
                ++qtdPalavras;
            }
        } while (*palavra != '8');

        if (qtdPalavras)
        {
            printf("Ordenando a lista de palavras...\n");
            qsort(palavras, qtdPalavras, sizeof(char*), comparador);
            printf("Lista ordenada:\n");
            for (i = 0; i < qtdPalavras; ++i)
            {
                printf("%s ", palavras[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < qtdPalavras; ++i)
        {
            free(palavras[i]);
        }

        free(palavras);
    } while (qtdPalavras);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Embora ache louvável promover o uso do `free`, você transformou o problema do autor da pergunta em uma coisa completamente diferente sem dar uma justificativa razoável para fazer isso. O problema era ler uma frase do usuário e ordenar as palavras, mas você encheu de coisas que nada tinham a ver com a pergunta ao pedir para o usuário digitar uma palavra por vez e complicar bastante o problema com uma lógica complexa de alocação e realocação de memória. Além disso, ele não aceita palavras como `x-salada`, `xenônio`, `xerox` ou `xícara`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, vou mudar o programa, então, para aceitar tais palavras.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, alocar memória não é tarefa fácil mesmo; por isso que, em outras linguagens de programação, existem coletores de lixo e gerenciamento automático de memória.

Comment: Outro detalhe que precisa ser dito é que o programa mostrado aceita qualquer quantidade de palavras, contanto que elas tenham no máximo 80 caracteres.

Comment: E não é necessário entrar "_uma palavra por vez_". Uma entrada do tipo `casa banheiro sala cozinha quarto despensa garagem`, palavras separadas por espaços, é completamente aceitável. Apenas deve-se certificar que o fim da frase seja demarcado com um caracter de escape, que agora, em vez de `X`, é o `8`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, que tal oferecer um exemplo como `8-salada`, `8enonio`, `8erox` ou `8icara` agora? Tente tudo numa frase só, `8-salada 8enonio 8erox 8icara 8`. Caso tenha mais dúvidas, me avise.