# Como fazer a pagina HTML se adaptar ao tamanho da janela

Tags: html, css

Pessoal to com uma dúvida eu vejo em sites como o próprio stackoverflow se adaptar ao tamanho da janela como eu faço isso em um código HTML?

Você redimensiona uma janela do chrome e a página se adapta sem corta os elementos HTML?

Comment: Pesquise por responsividade.

Comment: Isso acontece porque se utiliza o padrão "Responsivo". Site ou layout responsivo, ou também conhecido como site flexível é quando o site automaticamente se encaixa no dispositivo do usuário. Veja neste link [w3schools Design Responsivo](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Comment: Acho que você deve buscar aprender responsividade para construção de [Sites Responsivos](https://www.comersite.com.br/sites-responsivos-o-que-sao-eu-preciso-de-um) (sites responsivos são aqueles que adaptam o tamanho das suas páginas de acordo com a tela no qual o mesmo esteja sendo exibido). Não sei lá muitas coisas de web, no entanto seria um bom começo aprender sobre utilizar o [framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework) Bootstrap e etc. Acredito que seria uma boa ideia fazer um curso de [Bootstrap](https://www.devmedi

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo **básico** e **mínimo**, espero que te ajude na sua busca. Segue também algumas considerações:

> **1**- Este tema é muito amplo para ser discutido em apenas um exemplo. Vc pode obter muito mais informações e exemplos em diversos locais como **google** e **youtube**, ou claro fazer algum tipo de curso a respeito de técnicas de desenvolvimento **responsivo** e **mobile-first**.
>
> **2**- Existem maneiras distintas de se desenvolver uma página responsiva como: **CSS puro (utilizando Media Queries)**, **CSS puro (utilizando Flexbox + Media Queries)**, **Frameworks CSS (Bootstrap, Materialize, Bulma, SemanticUI, Foundation, etc...)**.
>
> **3**- **Na minha humilde opinião**, aconselharia vc primeiro aprender as técnicas com CSS puro, para depois empregar os frameworks e assim saber o que eles fazem por detrás dos panos.
>
> **4**- Se vc quiser ir dando uma olhada em cada maneira vc pode seguir os links a seguir: **MEDIA QUERIES** - [developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries), [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), [chiefofdesign](https://www.chiefofdesign.com.br/media-queries-css-introducao-a-diferentes-resolucoes-de-tela/). **FLEXBOX** - [developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceitos_Basicos_do_Flexbox), [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_flexbox.asp), [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). **FRAMEWORKS** - [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), [materialize](https://materializecss.com/), [bulma](https://bulma.io/), [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/), [foundation.](https://foundation.zurb.com/)

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0; 
}
html {
 font-family: "helvetica neue", sans serif;
}
.nav {
 border-bottom: solid 1px #eaeaeb;
 text-align: right;
 height: 70px;
 line-height: 70px;
}
.menu {
 margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
.menu a {
 clear: right;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: grey;
 padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
 margin: 0 10px;
 line-height: 70px;
}
.menu a:hover {
 background-color: #888;
 color: #fff;
}
label {
 margin: 0 40px 0 0;
 font-size: 26px;
 line-height: 70px;
 display: none;
 width: 26px;
 float: right;
}
#toggle {
 display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
    position: static;
 }
 .menu a {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eaeaeb;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .menu a:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background-color: #888;
 }

 #toggle:checked + .menu {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
 <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
 <div class="menu">
                 <a href="#">Home</a>
   <a href="#">Servi&ccedil;os</a>
   <a href="#">Sobre</a>
   <a href="#">Contato</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

**obs**: Clique em **Página toda** para ver o resultado da media querie.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Tag a seguir no Head das suas páginas.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, max-scale=1.0">
```

Você vai ver a mágica acontecer...
Utilize o Semantic UI para te ajudar com sua estilização de páginas.

[Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com)