# Problemas com filtro na lib API QUERY PARAMS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou utilizando essa lib para aplicar filtros

[api-query-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-query-params)

Preciso realizar o filtro para essa entidade;

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const schema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true

    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    restaurantId: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true
    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Menu', schema);
```

Através da documentação da lib API QUERY PARAMS conseguir criar esse método;

```
exports.list_all_dataProviders = async (req, res) => {
     const { filter, skip, limit, sort, projection } = aqp(req.query);

    Menus
      .find(filter)
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit)
      .sort(sort)
      .select(projection)
      .exec(async (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).jsonp({message:"There was an internal error listing all the providers " + err});
        }
        let count = await Menus.find().count()
        res.status(200).jsonp({
          size: limit,
          page: skip,
          total: count,
          data: result
        });
      });
  };
```

E fiz os seguintes teste no Postman;

`http://localhost:3000/menu?price=14.9`

`http://localhost:3000/menu?price=4.9`

`http://localhost:3000/menu?price=6.9`

E pegou perfeitamente, porém fiz esse teste e não tive sucesso;

Ele não conseguiu realizar nenhum filtro para o campo description
`http://localhost:3000/menu?description=Coberto`

E para o campo name só conseguiu pegar o primeiro registro.

O que está de errado é meu método, preciso corrigir.

Comment: Me parece estranho falar _"lib API ..."_, geralmente se usa um ou outro

Comment: E qual é a lib que é usada para meu caso?

Comment: Não foi isso que eu quis dizer... lib é apelido para library que é, em inglês, biblioteca, que é _"uma implementação real das regras"_, já API, _"É a maneira que o seu código se relaciona com uma biblioteca"_. É incomum usar os dois termos juntos (não necessariamente errado). [Diferença entre os termos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Obrigado por esclarecer, mas no final você tem alguma sugestão para me ajudar no meu problema de acordo com a postagem? por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não apresentou os dados que possui na sua base de dados, porém pelo que ficou subtendido na sua pergunta você quer busca os itens que **contenham** o texto que foi passado, para tanto você deve utilizar uma expressão regular indicando isso. Sua `URL` irá mudar para:

```
http://localhost:3000/menu?description=/coberto/i
```

O modificador `i` determina que a busca irá ignorar o `case` da sua `string`.

Comment: Eu gostaria de tirar mais uma dúvida se não for incomodo, existe possibilidade de  utilizar a URL sem precisar colocar o `i`? 

Será que existe uma forma de alterar meu método para que não precise usar o modificador `i` na URL ?

Comment: @wladyband Veja que esse módulo que você instalou serve justamente pra facilitar. Se você tirar o `i` sua busca irá considerar o case das letras. Então você que tem que decidir na realidade se vale ou não a pena usar um facilitador já que se quiser um compotamento diferente vai ter que defini-lo na lógica do seu serviço.

Comment: Tudo bem, eu entendi, muito obrigado.