# Web API sem acesso ao banco faz sentido?

Tags: api, aplicação-web

Em quais casos faz sentido criar uma Web API sem acesso a banco de dados?

Comment: Quando não existe a necessidade de persistir os dados em um banco de dados.

Comment: @LucasPera Particularmente eu diria que em todos... Nunca uma camada de apresentação, mesmo sendo uma Web Api, deveria ter acesso direto ao banco de dados.

Comment: Em caso de  API dinâmica (algoritmo que não precisar salvar nada ou recuperar nada para tratar as informações recebidas).

Comment: Tudo depende da sua necessidade, por exemplo, você poderia fazer somente um validador, ou seja, por questão de segurança um determinado processo deve passar por um determinado servidor simplesmente para validar sua autenticidade, um captcha por exemplo não precisa ter um banco de dados, mas precisa passar pelo servidor remoto pois validar uma captcha na maquina local seria um tiro no pé.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Banco de dados e Web API são conceitos ortogonais, então faz sentido em todos os casos que não precisa de banco de dados.

É raro, mas é possível, seja porque os dados já estão no código, ou ele só faz cálculos e processamentos. Claro, se fizer assim é improvável que deveria ser Web, a não ser por questões comerciais. Na verdade considero o uso de Web API um abuso em boa parte dos casos e isto ocorreu porque a maioria dos programadores não sabem programar e aí compram algo pronto e o mercado decidiu que assim eles poderiam ganhar mais dinheiro "alugando" a API e evitando a pirataria. As pessoas nem pensam nisso. Não à toa as 5 ou 6 maiores empresas de tecnologia explodiram seus valores de mercado nos últimos anos porque eles criaram este novo mercado e convenceram as pessoas que era mais barato, o que é falso na maioria dos casos.

Na verdade as pessoas não entendem o que é API, e isso [já foi respondido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101).

Em geral a dúvida surge porque as pessoas não aprendem programar. Apenas decoram receitas de bolo, aí um dia perguntam, será que eu posso não por leite condensado. E esta é a diferença entre o cozinheiro e o chef de cozinha. O primeiro acha que está fazendo algo interessante, mas é trivial e no fim é só uma mão de obra que um dia poderá ser substituída, o segundo realmente faz coisas importantes e é imprescindível. Nem precisa dizer qual ganha bem. É necessário aprender os fundamentos, entender o porquê das coisas.

Comment: A duvida surgiu porque me pediram pra fazer uma api para integrar a api bematec one aos sistemas da empresa, porem pelo o q eu li aqui essa api ja ta bem completa e acho q faz mais sentido acessar diretamente ela. se tiver tempo pra ler: http://bematechpartners.com.br/wp01/upload-files/downloads/oneapi/DOCUMENTACAO_GERAL02/APIOne_INTRO/APIOne.html
me de sua opinião por favor. Obrigado!!

Comment: Não entendi o que isso tem a ver com a pergunta.

Comment: Seria pra fazer ela sem acesso ao banco, foi dai onde surgiu minha duvida inicial.

Comment: Eu até imagino que não sua cabeça entenda o que está falando, mas sem descrever direito eu não sei o que está falando.

Comment: A empresa quer usar essa api one da bematec para gerar notas fiscais eletrônicas, e pra isso me pediram pra fazer uma api para servir de intermédio entre os sistemas da empresa e a api bematec one. a questão é q lendo a documentação eu n vejo sentido em criar uma api para acessar a api da bematec, se puder dar uma lida aqui e me dizer sua opinião eu agradeço: http://bematechpartners.com.br/wp01/upload-files/downloads/oneapi/DOCUMENTACAO_GERAL02/APIOne_INTRO/APIOne.html

Comment: @LucasPera apesar de essa aplicação já fornecer uma API que pode ser consumida diretamente do navegador, é necessário enviar os dados, que provavelmente vão vir do banco de dados da empresa, passando pela API de autenticação que já existe, o que devem ter pedido é para que o usuário requisite a nota fiscal para a API que irá fazer, ela irá autenticar o usuário, trazer os dados do banco e devolver, por exemplo, o arquivo pronto. Não que não possa fazer no frontend duas requisições

Comment: Acabei de conversar com o pessoal aqui, a api vai servir apenas para fazer validações, n vai ter acesso ao banco. 
Minha api vai receber um json, vou validar os campos desse json e se tiver algum erro vou enviar de volta antes de mandar para a api da bematec. 
to achando q isso é reinventar a roda.

Answer (score 1):

Uma Web API permite de disponibilizar qualquer serviços a um usuário final conectado na Internet.

Eu não concordo a 100% com @Maniero, no caso de uma API de pagamento online por exemplo, vai ser complicado (impossível) para o programador lambda de criar o sistema de A até Z.

Um sistema de pagamento online (gateway) ! Esse vai precisar de uma base de dados para o gerenciamento dos diferente tipo de cartões e usuário da API e claro que essa base de dados não sera accessível para o usuário final do API e será tratado em interno no servidor.

Uma API que otimize o tamanho de uma imagem ela só precisa da imagem e de um algoritmo de tratamento. Ai vc não vai precisar de base de dados (só no caso que vc tem um plano pago (ai vai ter que guardar os dados do clientes e o uso dele,...).

Más em todos os casos de API profissional vc tem uma base de dados mesmo se e só pra recordar o Numero de acesso e de tratamento, agora e claro que vc nunca vai abrir o acesso dessa base de dados para o usuario final!

Comment: Obrigado por concordar 100% com o que eu disse, mesmo dizendo que não concorda :)

Comment: Opá amigo ! Eu só não concorda com isso => "Em geral a dúvida surge porque as pessoas não aprendem programar" ! No sentido que uma Web API e para simplificar algumas coisas que seria muito dificil ou impossivel a programar. Só ! Fora isso concordo sim ! E vc concorda ? :)

Comment: Então acho que você não leu todo o meu texto. Leia com atenção. Ele tem um contexto bem específico. Se a pessoa usa uma Web API onde deveria fazer local ela não sabe o que está fazendo, não é simplificação, é complicação. E geralmente são essas APIs que não precisam de banco de dados. Pegando o seu exemplo mandar uma imagem para ser manipulada para uma Web API é um fim da picada, e as pessoas estão fazendo isto.

Comment: Se for para guardar apenas quantas vezes a API foi acessada pode ser feito com um arquivo `.txt`, por exemplo, adicionando uma nova linha com a data e hora a cada solicitação

Comment: @Maniero também não concordo com "mandar uma imagem para ser manipulada para uma Web API é um fim da picada", muitas vezes eu apenas quero fazer uma edição simples, como cortar a imagem, procurar fazer o download e instalar um aplicativo pesado, que eu vou usar uma vez lá que outra não é muito interessante. Também pode ser que eu esteja usando um computador antigo e nem abra o aplicativo que fiquei meia hora procurando, fazendo download e instalando. Em geral é preferível uma aplicação nativa, mas nem sempre

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam até você fazer um código, no bloco de notas, estudar a API, compilar, testar, etc. deu para resolver o problemas de outra forma. O que você disse é o que se chama falácia. Você tem um argumento válido para uma situação hipotética não realista com o contexto da pergunta. E eu teria aperto o Paint e resolvido o problema tranquilamente. Ou aberto o Photoshop Online ou algo parecido, mas não teria usado API que é para outra necessidade. Além do que o descrito não compete com API. E se estiver usando um computador tão antigo, se vai usar API ou não é o menos dos seus problemas.

Comment: @Maniero parece que vc consegue fazer e programar tudo ! Então acho que vc não usa o google map, que vc não usa nenhuma API de pagamento, tudo bem e seu ponto de vista ! Agora a pergunta não foi essa ! As API facilita a vida de muita gente até de grande programador, então vamos focar em responder a pergunta sem colocações duvidosa de como um programador (ou não) tem que fazer pra chegar ao resultado desejado ! Tudo mundo não tem tempo pra programar tudo de A até Z !

Comment: @SachaDee e eu acho que precisa fazer um curso de interpretação de texto. E é sério, não é sarcasmo. Ou então entender mais sobre o assunto, você acha que só existem duas formas, fazer tudo na mão , ou usar uma API web.

Comment: Amigo eu acho que minha interpretação não esta errada quando eu ler : "E eu teria aperto o Paint e resolvido o problema tranquilamente" vc afirma que sua visão está unica valida, e só isso que me perturbe no seu comentário ! E pra responder a sua pergunta "você acha que só existem duas formas, fazer tudo na mão , ou usar uma API web", eu acho que  os problemas de interpretação não são só meus ! E exatamente isso que eu queiro dizer tem vários caminho e nenhum e melhor que o outro, dependendo da situação e do conhecimento de cada um.