# O JQuey-ui depende do JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

O jquery-ui depende do jquery em uma aplicação ?, pergunto pois na aplicação que estou trabalhando aparentemente o jquery.min não está sendo utilizado, e a dúvida e se ele tem que estar lá para dar suporte ao jquery-ui.

Desde já agradeço, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, totalmente dependente da jQuery:

> "jQuery UI é um conjunto curado de interações de interface do usuário, efeitos, widgets e temas **construídos sobre a biblioteca JavaScript jQuery**". [fonte](https://jqueryui.com/)

---

> jQuery UI é uma coleção de widgets de GUI , efeitos visuais animados e temas **implementados com jQuery** (uma biblioteca JavaScript ), Cascading Style Sheets e HTML . [fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI)

---

> O jQuery UI é uma ferramenta de interação e construída **em cima do núcleo da jQuery** que permite que você possa animar os diferentes elementos HTML. [fonte](https://www.devmedia.com.br/explorando-o-jquery-ui/30316)

---

> **Totalmente baseada no framework¹ jQuery**, é usada para fornecer uma melhor interação entre o usuário e o cliente (web browser), com recursos ricos como animação, efeitos, componentes estilizáveis, etc. [fonte](https://www.devmedia.com.br/explorando-o-jquery-ui/30316)

---

EXEMPLO: note nas duas linhas **`script`** como primeiro é carregado a jQuery e depois a jQuery UI e que se retirar a linha que importa a jQuery o exemplo não funciona:

```js
$( function() {
   $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable { 
  width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; background-color:blue; color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

**Nota 1:** Apesar de no texto aparacer a palavra `Framework` referindo-se a jQuery, a mesma não é considerada como tal, mas, sim como uma biblioteca. [Saiba a diferença aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-api-biblioteca-e-framework)

**Nota 2:** Estranho seu código não apresentar a dependência da **jQuery**, pois como vimos a **jQuery UI** é totalmente dependente da mesma.

Comment: Andrade muito obrigado pelo retorno. No projeto há referência somente para o datepicker  <h:outputScript name = "js/jqueryui/jquery.ui.datepicker-en-GB.js"/>. A Principio retirei o jquery-3.3.1.min.js e não fez diferença. Por isso minha dúvida. De qualquer forma obrigado pela informação, se houver alguma outra dica agradeço. Um abraço.

Comment: Jóia man, por nada!

Comment: Um link importante seria o link da [página oficial do jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) onde está escrito: "jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects, widgets, and themes **built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library**". PS: é apenas para complementar a resposta já dada, visto que um resposta nova só pra isso não ajudaria em nada :D

Comment: @fernandosavio Boa man, realmente faltou o link da página principal. Posso complementar minha resposta com a sua sugestão?

Comment: Claro que sim, por isso comentei aqui.