# Qual a diferença entre extensão e biblioteca no PHP?

Tags: php, terminologia, característica-linguagem, biblioteca, extensão

No PHP existem algumas extensões dentro da linguagem. Por exemplo, a [SPL](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.spl.php), a [PHAR](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.phar.php) e a [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) são algumas dessas extensões.

Basicamente, as minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Qual a diferença de uma extensão para uma biblioteca?
- Seria ou não correto chamá-las de bibliotecas por serem um conjunto de classes?

PS: Quando me refiro a extensão, quero dizer [extensões da linguagem](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.basic.other.php) e não de formatos de arquivo e coisas do tipo.

Comment: Extensão é aquilo que estende uma funcionalidade da linguagem, no PHP geralmente (se não sempre) são escritas em C. Uma biblioteca é um conjunto de estruturas, não necessariamente classes, que auxiliam na resolução de um problema.

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/28595)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### O que é o PHAR em PHP

Primeiramente quero deixar claro que arquivos PHAR não são extensões, são "pacotes" que podem conter uma aplicação inteira (e geralmente contêm) para facilitar a instalação e distribuição, ou seja, ele agrupa uma série de arquivos em um único arquivo `.phar` que pode ser executado **inteiramente** ou **parcialmente** usando o protocolo `phar://` dentro de outros scripts php, exemplo para acessar um arquivo especifico:

```
include 'phar:///caminho/para/meuarquivo.phar/olamundo.php';
```

Isto não quer dizer que o phar não possa ser tratado com uma biblioteca, ou um Framework, mas de qualquer forma o que basicamente vai definir isto é o seu conteúdo e como um .phar especifico foi projetado para ser usado, ou seja o desenvolvedor define isto.

Resumindo, um `.phar` em si não se caracteriza como uma biblioteca, por padrão ele é um pacote de qualquer coisa com uma série de arquivos compactados, que podem ou não ser executados separadamente (via include) ou como uma aplicação inteira, vagamente assemelhando-se ao `.jar` usado em ambientes Java, que podem funcionar como pacotes de funções ou até como aplicações inteiras.

### O que é uma biblioteca

Sobre bibliotecas você pode já ter a resposta aqui [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/3635), mas para dar um exemplo mais claro e bem simplório em PHP, uma biblioteca poderia ser um conjunto de funções e/ou classes definidos para um ou mais usos que geralmente visa facilitar uma tarefa, ou seja você não precisa ter um conhecimento do funcionamento, só precisa saber como usa-las em sua aplicação final, claro que isso é bem vago da forma que expliquei, mas creio que até aqui seja o suficiente para entender.

### Extensões em PHP

Em php especificamente temos pelo entendimento comum que extensões são as .dll ou .so (em ambientes unix-like) como sendo binários contendo bibliotecas ou até frameworks inteiros que estendem as funcionalidades básicas do PHP que geralmente (depende um pouco de como você vai compilar) a maior parte das APIs internas do PHP são extensões que são ativadas ou desativadas no php.ini através dos parametros:

```
extension=xyz.dll
```

> xyz.dll é apenas um exemplo

Ou até mesmo o caminho completo:

```
extension=C:\foo\bar\xyz.dll
```

Claro que não basta criar um arquivo `.c` e compilar no MingW para conseguir criar uma extensão para o PHP, a .dll tem que ser compilada pelo mesmo tipo de compilador que foi compilado o PHP de sua máquina ou servidor, ou seja não é tão simples, e fora isto precisa entender como fazer a dll se "comunicar com o php" que pode acompanhar aqui:

- http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.structure.php

Agora alguns detalhes:

- Uma extensão para php pode ser uma biblioteca
- Uma extensão para php pode ser um framework
- Uma extensão para php pode não fornecer nenhuma função para o programador mas pode fazer coisas automaticamente, como XCache ou Opcache (duas extensões para PHP), que fazem os scripts .php em um servidor executarem mais rápido devido a uma especie de "compilação" (bytecode, cada um a sua maneira) e que também ajuda a reduzir em muito o consumo de memória

> claro que ambas .dll/.so de cache fornecem algumas funções especificas, mas poderiam não fornecer, o que não faria elas deixarem de ser extensões

Como disse, uma extensão é escrita em [c](/questions/tagged/c) (mas existem meios alternativos não oficiais em C++), um exemplo da estrutura de uma extensão não compilada seria algo como (conforme o link que já mencionei acima):

```
ext/
 └─── foobar/
       ├─── config.m4
       ├─── config.w32
       ├─── foobar_util.h
       ├─── foobar_util.c
       ├─── php_foobar.h
       ├─── foobar.c
       ├─── package.xml
       ├─── CREDITS
       └─── tests/
             ├─── critical_function_001.phpt
             ├─── critical_function_002.phpt
             ├─── optional_function_001.phpt
             └─── optional_function_002.phpt
```

A pasta `tests` são apenas testes que você escreve semelhante aos testes unitários.

- `config.m4` é a configuração do sistema de compilação para UNIX-like (veja o link para mais detalhes https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.configunix.php)
- `config.w32` é a configuração do sistema de compilação para Windows (veja o link para mais detalhes https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.configwin.php)
- `php_foobar.h`

  Ao construir uma extensão como módulo estático no "binário PHP", o sistema de construção espera um arquivo de cabeçalho com `php_` como prefixo do nome da extensão, que inclui uma declaração para um ponteiro para a estrutura do módulo da extensão. Este arquivo geralmente contém macros, protótipos e globais adicionais, assim como qualquer cabeçalho.
- `foobar.c`

  Principal arquivo fonte da extensão. Por convenção, o nome deste arquivo é o nome da extensão, mas isso não é um requisito. Este arquivo contém a declaração da estrutura do módulo, entradas `INI`, funções de gerenciamento, funções de espaço do usuário e outros requisitos de uma extensão.

Os outros arquivos `.h` no exemplo são apenas "separações" que você pode ou não fazer e depois usar com `#include`.

### Termo extensão

Agora só sobre o termo *extensão*, mesmo em PHP, ou falando só sobre isso, extensão poderia facilmente ser um termo usado para diferentes situações, fora as extensões já citadas antes, isto eu me refiro ao nível da linguagem e não ao nivel do "PHP interpretador" (o executável `php.exe` em windows por exemplo).

Por exemplo, você tem uma aplicação php que é um site, então você cria um script PHP que adiciona alguma rotina especifica para o teu site, daria para chamar de extensão, é o termo mais adequado? Creio que não, ainda mais que causaria confusão.

Agora sobre classes em PHP, quando se cria algo assim:

```
class Foo {}

class Bar extends Foo {}
```

A classe `Bar` estende (ou não) os métodos e/ou propriedades da classe `Foo`, então possivelmente `Bar` vai ser uma extensão para `Foo`, mas claro que sair chamando de extensão vai confundir um pouco, creio que seja mais fácil dizer claramente o que é, Bar é uma *"classe estendida"*

---

### Diferença do PHAR e de uma extensão (.dll/.so)

Phar são pacotes e podem ser executados diretamente, até via linha de comando, já as .dlls são executadas a partir do momento que um servidor PHP é iniciado ou no momento que o PHP é executado (startup), ou seja é como se o PHAR fosse a parte do PHP e já as dlls estão sendo executadas a todo momento, claro que ambos podem conter coisas semelhantes, mas basicamente executam em tempos diferentes.

---

### Respondendo ao questionário

> Qual a diferença de uma extensão para uma biblioteca?

Creio que já respondi acima, mas resumidamente extensões do PHP pode ter bibliotecas e/ou funções ou não ter nada além de uma rotina automática (como um sistema para gerar bytecode de scripts PHP para melhorar a performance das aplicações PHP) e a biblioteca pode ir dentro disto, ou não.

> Seria ou não correto chamá-las de bibliotecas por serem um conjunto de classes?

PHAR ou extensões não são bibliotecas, mas podem ser, dependendo do que tiver dentro, podem também não conter nada mesmo e ainda serão um extensões e arquivos `.phar`