# Para que serve as interfaces do HTML?

Tags: html, terminologia

Toda especificação (documentação) que eu vejo de um determinado elemento HTML, sempre especificam o elemento a um tipo de interface como, por exemplo:

- `HTMLTableCaptionElement`
- `HTMLButtonElement`
- `HTMLBRElement`
- `HTMLElement`

Essas interfaces dos elementos se referem ao que? E para que servem?

Comment: Acho que isso deve te interessa tb https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Categorias_de_conteudo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interface nesse contexto indica que é um contrato.

Sabe o que é [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101)? Application Programming **Interface**. É a mesma coisa do termo nesse contexto. É o que define como deve usar algo. É o que permite contato do seu código com o código interno de uma tecnologia que está disponibilizada para você.

Vamos traduzir um desses textos:

> The `HTMLElement` interface represents any HTML element

Ficaria:

> O mecanismo de comunicação com o navegador chamado `HTMLElement` representa qualquer elemento HTML.

Melhor usar o termo que já indica tudo isso aí em uma palavra.

Cada umas delas servem para uma coisa um pouco diferente e tem que ler a documentação de cada, acho que a pergunta não é sobre isso, até porque se fosse seria ampla.

Comment: A documentação é muito vasta. Ele pode começar estudando https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection e destrinchando os links que vão aparecendo. Querer entender o que é uma interface no contexto do HTML não é tão fácil.