# Os módulos Spring Data e Spring Data JPA são frameworks?

Tags: java, spring, framework

Acredito que todo iniciante tenha dificuldades com o entendimento do conceito de um framework. Estou começando a estudar o framework Spring, dentro dele há vários projetos ou módulos, e dentro desses projetos há sub projetos. Posso citar como exemplo o Spring Data, onde dentro dele temos o Spring Data JPA. Está correto eu chamar os módulos Spring Data e Spring Data JPA de frameworks? Ou não, são simplesmente módulos do famoso Spring framework?

Comment: O que caracteriza um framework é a inversão de controle da chamadas a funções customizadas pelo programador. Se a função chama o framework, não é um framework mas uma biblioteca. Se por outro lado o programador implementa uma customização para que esta seja chamada pelo código do framework (ou seja ele implementa os _"hooks"_ do framework), então se trata de um framework propriamente dito.

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/112052)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Spring Data é um projeto guarda-chuva (conjunto de projetos) que agrega vários projetos relacionados ao acesso à dados, conforme descrição do [site oficial](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data):

> Spring Data’s mission is to provide a familiar and consistent, Spring-based programming model for data access while still retaining the special traits of the underlying data store.

> It makes it easy to use data access technologies, relational and non-relational databases, map-reduce frameworks, and cloud-based data services. This is an umbrella project which contains many subprojects that are specific to a given database. The projects are developed by working together with many of the companies and developers that are behind these exciting technologies.

Já o Spring Data JPA é um projeto que visa a facilitar a criação de camadas de acesso à dados baseadas no JPA.

Conforme a explicação fornecida pelo [Piovezan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/357/piovezan), o Spring Data JPA pode ser considerado como sendo um framework. Para utilizá-lo, você cria interfaces que customizam as funcionalidades providas.