# O que é o .NET Core?

Tags: .net, clr, mono, .net-core

A Microsoft [anunciou um novo .NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-open-source/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Que raios é isto?

[image: diagrama .NET Core]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Muito do que está aqui já faz menos ou nenhum sentido sentido, o .NET Core evoluiu e agora faz algumas coisas que digo que ele não faz, por exemplo rodar WinForms, WPF, EF6, ASP.NET MVC normal e outras coisas, e ele substitui outras implementações, inclusive [o .NET Framework agora morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

É uma variação do conhecido .NET Framework (e agora já começa o sobrepor em uso). Ele começou baseado na nova versão 4.6 do *framework* "completo". Ambos são desenvolvidos em conjunto pela Microsoft, mas o Core conta com ajuda da comunidade. Não há grandes diferenças entre eles na parte mais básica. Apesar deles usaram a mesma base de código serão duas linhas de desenvolvimento independentes. O .NET Core não é necessário para o .NET Framework funcionar já que ele possui tudo o que precisa. E claro que o contrário também é verdadeiro.

Não confundir ele como o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) que é outra tecnologia. Nem com versões limitadas por outros fatores como o [.NET Compact Framework](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework). Ele não é apenas uma camada baixo nível. Ele é quase a mesma coisa do .NET Framework que pode ser usado de forma personalizada.

Faltam algumas bibliotecas mais específicas além de toda infraestrutura básica para funcionamento da plataforma, as bibliotecas para realizar todas operações normais com o .NET e mesmo outras tarefas avançadas estão lá, mas não tudo, até porque algumas coisas não fazendo sentido no Core ou já eram consideradas obsoletas. Em 2019 o Core passa ter quase tudo o que era importante, embora algumas delas, até por questões técnicas só funcionem no Windows.

O .NET Framework continuará sendo desenvolvido exclusivamente pela Microsoft em grande parte aproveitando o que existe no .NET Core, apesar de ser totalmente *open source* (sem limitações). O .NET Core está sendo [desenvolvido pela comunidade](https://github.com/dotnet/core) com liderança da Microsoft e com [participação da comunidade do Mono](https://tirania.org/blog/archive/2014/Nov-12.html) já que ele tem como objetivo rodar em todas as plataformas *mainstream*. Ele utiliza [licença MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) para compatibilizar com o Mono. De fato a propriedade dele é da [.NET Foundation](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/) e não da Microsoft.

Seu objetivo primário é funcionar como *backend* em servidores, que é onde a maioria das aplicações são desenvolvidas hoje em dia, *containers*. embarcados, enfim, qualquer lugar onde não precise da infraestrutura do .NET "*full*". Mas agora em 2019 ele começa tomar espaço até em outras frentes.

O .NET Core pode ser usado para aplicações cliente UWP, WPF ou WinForms, mas o código dessas tecnologias não está aberto.

Há as bibliotecas disponibilizadas pelo Xamarin para iOS, MacOS e Android, que têm seus códigos abertos. E claro que GTK# continua aberto. Desta forma o .NET é a plataforma fácil de usar (C++ é mais difícil especialmente em algumas plataformas) mais ubíqua existente para *client side* e *server side*.

Ele é composto por todas as tecnologias necessárias para execução de aplicações voltadas para o [CoreCLR](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-open-source/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) incluindo a própria VM, o GC, o novo RyuJIT, além da BCL (a biblioteca) e as tecnologias tipicamente de servidores como [Entity Framework Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/), [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Home) e o <strike>novo</strike> Kestrel (novo servidor HTTP multiplataforma dedicado ao .NET e que em versões novas foi todo reescrito) que nas versões mais novas é o servidor HTTP em uso real mais rápido do mercado.

Ele usa uma tecnologia modular exigindo apenas o que for realmente usado pela aplicação. Através do NuGet é possível adicionar partes a ele. A Microsoft disponibiliza algumas novas bibliotecas como SIMD e Immutable Collections e outras existentes e que não fazem parte do Core como XML, e isto está se ampliando. É claro que o [.NET Compiler Platform](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) (antigo Roslyn) que é o compilador e serviços de compilação está incluso e totalmente aberto também, recebendo inclusive *pull requests* no GitHub ([dados preliminares](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/one-week-of-open-source/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

A distribuição poderá ocorrer com sua aplicação, ele não terá dependência do .NET instalado na máquina para uma aplicação funcionar. O novo ASP.NET usa-o por padrão. Uma [citação do Miguel de Icaza](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/11/12/release_microsoft_net_from_its_windows_chains_mono_and_xamarin_guy_miguel_de_icaza_on_open_source_net/) mostra bem essa diferença:

> In Core, .NET is no longer going to be a system service. Instead it’s going to be a piece of technology that is bundled with your application in the form of Nugets [packages installed by developers]. When you deploy an app with .NET core, the web site will contain a copy of the virtual machine and a copy of every library that it needs.

Em resumo, ele não é um serviço do sistema operacional, algo que fica impregnado no Windows carregando tudo o que sua aplicação precisa ou não. Ele serve como suporte à sua aplicação e não é uma plataforma como é o .NET tradicional ou o JRE (Java), que também andou mudando sua filosofia.

O [Mono certamente se beneficiará da nova licença e evoluirá em qualidade](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/dotnet-integration/). Em futuro próximo será possível executar aplicações CLR sem dizer que algumas plataformas são de segunda classe. O Mono ainda será necessário em certos cenários embora na maioria dos casos o .NET Core será a melhor escolha. Está em curso uma grande redução do uso do .NET Framework (a versão completa disponível no Windows hoje), embora ele ainda continuará bastante relevante em grande parte dos cenários legados. Na verdade o Mono será "abandonado".

Além de ser uma versão simplificada e flexível, mas com todo o poder necessário para quase todo tipo de aplicação, ele é uma versão mais aberta e menos vinculada à Microsoft, apesar do apoio total dela.

[image: .NET Ecosystem]

Com tudo isto [foi criado o .NET Standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-standard/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para ajudar compatibilizar todas as versões. E já está praticamente morto.

Mais informações podem ser obtidas nesse [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Fonte: [Resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26899740/221800) :P Mais pode ser lido na [postagem da Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-2015-preview-a-new-era-for-net/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E tem uma [FAQ bem interessante aqui](https://news.microsoft.com/2014/11/12/microsoft-takes-net-open-source-and-cross-platform-adds-new-development-capabilities-with-visual-studio-2015-net-2015-and-visual-studio-online/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

E ainda [Por que o .NET Core foi criado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225927/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então o que ocorreu basicamente foi uma divisão do .NET Framework em duas partes, a primeira seria a sua parte mais "baixo nível" (core) onde estaria a implementação de funcionalidades básicas do Framework, e a segunda a parte mais específica que englobaria bibliotecas/APIs/toolkit que fazem uso do "core" e que são importantes comercialmente para a Microsoft. Estou correto?

Comment: @Zignd não chega ser a parte mais baixo nível (as partes que fazem a plataforma funcionar, as partes em C++, por exemplo). As duas versões tem sua parte baixo nível essencialmente iguais. Mas fora isto o seu entendimento está correto. A diferença está mais nas bibliotecas disponíveis. Outra coisa é que o .Net apesar de ser uma plataforma, o .Net Core funciona de uma forma mais próxima ao de uma aplicação nativa. O que aliás, também existe agora um .Net Native. Ainda estou pesquisando algumas coisas e vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: O .Net Core veio para substituir o .Net Framework?

Comment: @gato não, é uma outra implementação do CLR com objetivos um pouco diferentes. Cada projeto pode caber um melhor que o outro. Eu acho que a tendência é o .Net Framework ser usado só quando a aplicação é  WinForms ou WPF, ou ainda se precisa se alguma coisa muito específica do Windows.

Comment: Eu acredito que o netcore veio com o objetivo de melhorar a performance na web, pois agora com o netcore, ele sai na frente em vários benchmarks.

Comment: @GlaucoOliveira https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225927/101

Answer (score 1):

Um resumo bem, mas bem resumido é o seguinte:
.NetFramework: 
- Usa as "dlls" instaladas no servidor.
- Exclusivo para Windows.

.NetCore:
- As "dlls" ja estão "empacotadas" junto ao executável.
- Mais rápido que o .NetFramework.
- Cross-Platform.
- Mais barato.

Comment: Essa resposta está incorreta, a implantação de uma aplicação .NET Core pode ser feita em dois tipos e em só um deles os componentes do .NET Core estão contidos na própria aplcação: [.NET Core application deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/). Também seria interessante citar alguma fonte que comprove essas afirmações, que o .NET Core é mais rápido e mais barato.