# ASP.NET vNext no Apache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, apache, asp.net-core

Tenho ouvido falar bastante que o ASP.NET 5 vai funcionar não só em ambiente Windows mas também Mac e Linux. Queria saber daí se tem como rodar aplicações ASP.NET 5 no servidor Apache. Pesquisei um pouco mas não achei nada recente falando sobre esse servidor específico. Na versão atual de testes já é possível rodar no Apache?

Se for possível, seria possível me indicar um tutorial mostrando como fazer isso? Pesquisando achei uma implementação Mono do ASP.NET 2.0 e do ASP.NET MVC, mas não é isso que estou procurando, é sobre o ASP.NET 5 mesmo.

Comment: Leandro eu sei que tem como rodar o .NET no Apache, usando um modulo chamado [mod_aspdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/) e ambientes linux talvez usando o `mod_mono`, porém eu acredito que não de suporte ao 5. Me diga qual o intuito realmente de desenvolver com o Apache? Se for pela facilidade da instalação e configuração que o Apache proporciona, tenho que lhe dizer que existem alternativas ao Apache e ao IIS que realmente são tão fáceis quanto (só não sei se existe suporte para o 5 ainda).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Microsoft mudou sua postura com toda a plataforma. [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) eu falo sobre o novo .NET Core que não só é código aberto como tem como princípio rodar em qualquer plataforma.

Estamos falando da implementação da Microsoft, o .NET mesmo, não confundir com o Mono que é outra implementação do CLR que sempre foi multiplataforma mas que sempre teve algumas limitações.

Uma das características principais do ASP.NET Core é ter independência do *host*, ou seja, não ter mais vinculação com IIS. O que complicava a implementação quando ele não estava disponível e na verdade colocava outras limitações já que nem sempre é desejável usar o IIS.

O novo ASP.NET vem inclusive um um *host* chamado Kestrel que pode rodar sem um servidor HTTP completo. Ele pode rodar em conjunto com o Nginx segundo [essa página](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETasOpenSourceNETonMacandLinuxandVisualStudioCommunity.aspx) autoritativa. Já li o mesmo em outro lugares. Já há [documentação de como usar o Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/apache-proxy?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Note que o ASP.NET Core apesar de manter sua base é praticamente outro software.

Vale lembrar que faz tempo que o Mono usa, com limitações, o ASP.NET MVC da Microsoft mesmo. Ele não foi reimplementado, no máximo adaptado.

A Microsoft está suportando o Mono oficialmente.

É "certa" é que o .NET Framework *full* não rodará. Mas o .NET Framework está cada vez menos suportado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Até a data desta resposta, ainda não existe implementação do vNext para o Apache.

Possivelmente isso pode ocorrer apenas em 2015, e isso se o time do Apache quiser implementar o vNext para o servidor.