# Como obter informações do computador com C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sistema-operacional

Como informações do computador onde está sendo executado a aplicação C#, como nome do computador, IP, status do *firewall*, se tem antivírus instalado, se o antivírus esta ativo, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pergunta é um pouco ampla. Vou mostrar o caminho que é o mais importante. Se tiver dúvidas específicas você poderá fazer perguntas novas específicas.

Tenha em mente que nem todas informações podem ser obtidas facilmente. Algumas talvez precise ser de uma forma bastante específica e/ou com pouca confiabilidade. Então nestes casos provavelmente nem vale o esforço.

Um dos *namespaces* que fornecem essas informações é o [`System.Management`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). Lá existem diversas classes que fornecem boa parte das informações que você deseja. Tem que pesquisar cada uma das classes e ver quais são úteis. A maioria delas possuem exemplos de uso. Todo *namespace* é limitado no Mono e no [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101). Então considere que só funciona no Windows e na implementação completa do *framework*. Dê uma olhada também no [`System.Management.Instrumentation`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.instrumentation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Algumas classes fornecem as informações como uma consulta SQL, então tem que aprender todas as possibilidades de *queries*. Na documentação vai dando o caminho para aprender tudo. Esta linguagem chama-se [WQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Algumas classes para começar seu estudo: [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). [`ManagementObjectCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectcollection?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Se gosta de usar [LINQ tem uma biblioteca para acessar algumas destas informações](https://missinglinq.codeplex.com/) desta forma. Não sei nada sobre a qualidade dela.

Outra classe bastante útil que fornecem outras informações é a [`Environment`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Há exemplo de uso na documentação. A maioria dos elementos são obtidos de forma simples através de propriedades. Algumas precisam ser enumeradas.

Alguma coisa ainda pode ser obtida com a classe [`SystemInformation`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Algumas informações podem ser obtidas através do registro do Windows. Estuda a classe [`Registry`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) e outras classes relacionadas. Como eu disse, provavelmente teria que saber o que buscar para obter informações relevantes sem muito ruído. É mais fácil quando você quer saber se algo está presente.

Algumas informações só podem ser obtidas com permissão elevada.

Um exemplo de código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;

var consulta = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS");
ManagementObjectCollection bios = consulta.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject obj in bios) {
    var item = new Win32_BIOS();
    item.BiosCharacteristics = (ushort[])obj["BiosCharacteristics"];
    item.BIOSVersion = (string[])obj["BIOSVersion"];
    item.BuildNumber = (string)obj["BuildNumber"];
    item.Caption = (string)obj["Caption"];
    item.CodeSet = (string)obj["CodeSet"];
    item.CurrentLanguage = (string)obj["CurrentLanguage"];
    item.Description = (string)obj["Description"];
    item.IdentificationCode = (string)obj["IdentificationCode"];
    item.InstallableLanguages = (ushort?)obj["InstallableLanguages"];
    item.InstallDate = (DateTime?)obj["InstallDate"];
    item.LanguageEdition = (string)obj["LanguageEdition"];
    item.ListOfLanguages = (string[])obj["ListOfLanguages"];
    item.Manufacturer = (string)obj["Manufacturer"];
    item.Name = (string)obj["Name"];
    item.OtherTargetOS = (string)obj["OtherTargetOS"];
    item.PrimaryBIOS = (bool?)obj["PrimaryBIOS"];
    item.ReleaseDate = (string)obj["ReleaseDate"];
    item.SerialNumber = (string)obj["SerialNumber"];
    item.SMBIOSBIOSVersion = (string)obj["SMBIOSBIOSVersion"];
    item.SMBIOSMajorVersion = (ushort?)obj["SMBIOSMajorVersion"];
    item.SMBIOSMinorVersion = (ushort?)obj["SMBIOSMinorVersion"];
    item.SMBIOSPresent = (bool?)obj["SMBIOSPresent"];
    item.SoftwareElementID = (string)obj["SoftwareElementID"];
    item.SoftwareElementState = (ushort?)obj["SoftwareElementState"];
    item.Status = (string)obj["Status"];
    item.TargetOperatingSystem = (ushort?)obj["TargetOperatingSystem"];
    item.Version = (string)obj["Version"];
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ComputerInfo.cs).