# Arquivos executáveis dependentes disponíveis para o usuário

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, instalador

Estou com um problema com meu *setup* do Visual Studio 2010,

Fiz uma aplicação que o `form` principal possui vários *forms* dependentes e quando gero o *setup* dele e realizo a instalação do mesmo, na pasta da instalação os arquivos executáveis dependentes estão disponíveis para o usuário executar diretamente. Como faço para deixar somente o `exe` principal disponível para acesso do usuário e tornar os demais arquivos `exe` inacessíveis para o usuário final?

Comment: Pode tentar usar o [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) para juntar todos os *EXEs* num só ([tutorial](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/03/merge-multiple-exe-and-dll-into-one-single-file-in-net.html)).

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Você não está com um problema, você quer por alguma razão reduzir o a quantidade de arquivos. Você tem um bom motivo para isto? Se não tiver, não faça.

Se realmente quiser, pode fazer como o Omni disse no comentário e usar o [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para juntar os arquivos em um só. Tem até uma [GUI](https://bitbucket.org/wvd-vegt/ilmergegui) se achar que ajuda. Exemplo de uso:

```
ilmerge /target:winexe /out:Main.exe 
    Program.exe ClassLibrary1.dll ClassLibrary2.dll
```

Não é qualquer arquivo de código que pode ser usado para isto. Como o formato de códigos nativos é diferente, eles não podem ser mesclados.

Ter vários arquivos é o menor dos problemas sobre dependências. Se você realmente não quer ter dependências, use o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101). Com ele você sequer precisa do .NET instalado na máquina. Vai precisar ter alguns arquivos, mas vai realmente evitar as dependências mais significativas e que pode trazer dificuldades reais.

Já existem soluções mais modernas para .NET Core. Isto fica para uso com legado.