# É possível converter aplicativos .NET Framework do Windows para Mac?

Tags: .net, windows, osx, portabilidade

Posso pegar meu projeto pronto, e fazer ele rodar em um Mac OS X? (Ele foi feito em .NET Framework 4.5.2, para Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende do que foi usado no projeto. Depende de como ele foi escrito (esta parte pode exigir um pouco de adaptação se não foi pensado para trabalhar em uma plataforma diferente, mas nada muito difícil). E é claro que algumas coisas podem ser específicas demais para portar. Portar não significa que vai ficar ótimo na outra plataforma. Mas é possível melhorar.

Já era possível fazer isto com [Mono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/mono/info), com algumas limitações. Agora é possível com o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101), também com limitações ([agora só use ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101)). Algumas bibliotecas extras podem ser usadas para ajudar na portabilidade.

Se deseja aproveitar GUI, esquece. Se o projeto é malfeito a chance de reaproveitar na totalidade de forma fácil foi pro espaço. A qualidade da portabilidade tem a ver com a qualidade do projeto como um todo.

Comment: Já ouvi falar muitas vezes do Mono, mas ele é possível converter um projeto **Console** criado num *.vbproj* para a mesma linguagem? Em outras palavras, irá mudar minha linguagem?

Comment: Agora não sei bem o que você está falando. Mas acho que não.