# Acessar estruturas internas código C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net

É possível acessar as estruturas internas de um código do core do C# ou bibliotecas do `System.Core` do .NET? Por exemplo, como é implementado o método `First()`?

```
Alerta alerta = query.First();
```

Queria ver como é feito isso nos bastidores, considerando que muita coisa esta sendo liberada pela MS, os compiladores e tal. Qual o caminho para eu acessar este código de bastidores?

Comment: Você pode usar um descompilador, [aqui](http://ilspy.net/) você pode baixar um bom e free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Microsoft adotou uma política "Open Source" em seus produtos. Com isso, ela liberou em vários meios os códigos de diversos produtos, como o [ASP.NET](https://github.com/aspnet) e o [Entity Framework](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework), por exemplo.

[Neste artigo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/11/12/net-core-is-open-source/) é explicado como aconteceu e o que está Open Source hoje. Vale ressaltar que algo pode ter sido adicionado à lista desde a data do artigo, então vale a pena conferir o [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet) e ver se tem algo novo.

Vale ressaltar nesta resposta o [projeto mono](https://github.com/mono/mono). Pode encontrar mais detalhes sobre ele [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40672/20615).

O código que você pediu, especificamente do método `First()`, pode ser visto abaixo:

```
    public static TSource First<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null)
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        return source.Provider.Execute<TSource>(
            Expression.Call(
                null,
                GetMethodInfo(Queryable.First, source),
                new Expression[] { source.Expression }
                ));
    }

    public static TSource First<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate) {
        if (source == null)
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (predicate == null)
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
        return source.Provider.Execute<TSource>(
            Expression.Call(
                null,
                GetMethodInfo(Queryable.First, source, predicate),
                new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate) }
                ));
    }
```

[Link do código original.](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs)

Comment: Obrigado Randrade. Era essa estrutura mesmo que eu queria ver. Sabia que existia uma maior liberdade neste sentido mas não sabia por onde começar. vlww

Answer (score 4):

A Microsoft disponibiliza um site dedicado para [consulta de código](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) com facilidades para navegação. Uma das diversas implementações do [`First()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,bc8ae402a61dd9d6), por exemplo. No [.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/First.cs,bc8ae402a61dd9d6).

Além disto é possível ver os repositórios oficiais dos diversos projetos já colocados na resposta do Randrade.

Comment: Não conhecia esse site, +1

Comment: Valeu bigow, o site vai me dar um help bacana.