# Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de publicar um serviço Web num servidor ou como servico do Windows?

Tags: web-service, services

A minha empresa costuma criar serviços Windows para publicar serviços `Web`.

Isto quer dizer que o serviço não está hospedado em nenhum servidor (como o IIS). Uma desvantagem óbvia que vejo logo a partida é que o serviço está dependente do Sistema operativo.

Anteriormente apenas tinha criado serviços `Web` hospedados num servidor, mais concretamente no IIS.

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de publicar um serviço Web num servidor ou como serviço do Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma resposta para esse pergunta pode ser bem longa, mas vou tentar resumir alguns pontos:

- **Gerenciamento "Web"**:
  Se você criar um serviço Web, seja um Webservice, `WCF`, ou uma aplicação que responde chamadas `HTTP`, como uma Web Api, faz todo sentido publicar num servidor Web. Um servidor Web, como o `IIS` tem toda uma infra estrutura para tratar as chamadas, suporte ao protocolo HTTP (isso inclui cache, compressão, segurança, ssl, etc), além poder gerenciar um Web Farm se você quiser escalar sua aplicação. Essas coisas também podem ser feitas e implementadas em um Windows Service, mas não de maneira tão prática como no `ISS`.
- **Gerenciamento de memória**:
  O gerenciamento de memória de uma aplicação hosteada no `IIS` é bem mais transparente do que um serviço do `Windows` ou outro hosteamento, como um Windows Application (só como exemplo aqui, um opção usual apenas para testes). Você pode ter um Application Pool com configurações bem específicas atendente a uma determinada aplicação. Além disso, você pode gerenciar coisas como reciclar o Application Pool por limite de memória e CPU, o que é mais difícil de ser controlado em um serviço. Apesar disso, o Windows Service permanece sempre ativo, enquanto o serviço estiver rodando. Em um serviço crítico, isso pode ser uma vantagem, ao contrário do `IIS`, que pode reciclar ou encerrar o seu serviço.
- **Com a aplicação é ativada**
  Embora o `IIS`, a partir da versão 7.5 e da versão 7 com o (descontinuado) AppFabric possa ativar automaticamente um serviço `WCF`, se o seu serviço estiver hosteado como um Windows Service, esse leva vantagem. Um serviço do `Windows` pode ser ativado assim que o Windows iniciar, isso significa que ele não precisa receber uma requisição para ser ativo, diferente de algo hosteado no `IIS`.
- **Protocolos**
  Um serviço hosteado como Windows Service pode servir diversos protocolos, HTTP, net.tcp, net.pipe e net.msmq. O `IIS` também, mas apenas a partir da versão 7.0. Se você tiver um servidor de versão anterior, só poderá usar `HTTP`.

Tentei compara alguns pontos para ajudar em decidir qual a melhor solução pra cada cenário.

Tem um documento bem interessante da do MSDN em inglês que você deveria dar uma olhada, principalmente no quadro de comparação entre as diversas tecnologias e cenários: [Hosting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta. Deu para entender bem porque nomalmente a escolha de hospedagem é num servidor `Web` e quais os momentos que devo escolher o Windows service. A minha empresa tem 20 anos de existencia e tem vários servicos em `TCP` deve ser esse o motivo de terem tantos servicos hospedados como servicos do `Windows`.

Comment: Curiosamente o .Net Core vai por outro caminho e meio que incentiva o uso *stand alone*: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101

Comment: Eu não conheço bem o .Net Core ainda, mas vi que ele tem um gerenciamento de memória bem diferente, pode ter alguma relação. Como ele pretende rodar em todas as plataformas, acho que eles querem "descolar" ele do IIS, acho que a MS quer que ele rode numa arquitetura meio node.js, talvez isso também incentive usar um *self-host* para serviços, bem interessante isso @bigown

Comment: @RicardoPontual até onde eu sei ele não tem um gerenciamento de memória diferente, pleo menos não em relação ao .Net tradicional. Mas realmente a ideia é dar liberdade para fazer o que quiser, onde quiser, do jeito que quiser.