# Alternativas para PHP

Tags: c#, node.js, template

E gosto bastante de C# então dei uma olhada em ASP, mas não gostei muito. Já mexi com NodeJS e gosto bastante.

Eu queria uma linguagem tipo PHP, onde você possa colocar o código dentro do *HTML* e manipulá-lo.

Assim:

```
<div><?php echo "oi" ?></div>
```

Então queria saber se tem outra linguagem que permita que eu faça isso, queria saber se existem e se existem quais são as alternativas para *PHP*

Porém o que eu procuro em uma Template Engine ou uma linguagem, seria a possibilidade de colocar código mesmo dentro do HTML tipo:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) echo ("<div>OI " + i + "</div>);
```

EDIT 1: Como foi dito, existem os templates (Agradeço bastante pela resposta, ajudou, mas ainda não resolve), Se puderem mandar alternativas boas pra NodeJS também.

Comment: Qual o problema com o node?

Comment: As mais comuns usadas no servidor são (nessa ordem) PHP, Java web e node.js, com uma forte tendência para o node. Você ainda pode usar javascript para manipular os dados no cliente e usar requisições ajax para buscar e enviar dados para o servidor. Nesse caso não faz diferença o que você usa no servidor.

Comment: Nenhum problema, só não gostei muito do EJS, queria algo mais parecido com a foma que JSP e PHP funcionam, tipo echo "<div>oi</div>"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É verdade que o PHP tem isso embutido no próprio interpretador, mas poder colocar código dentro de um *tamplate* não é característica de uma linguagem de programação, então qualquer uma pode fazer isto, basta o sistema de *template* conseguir entender aquela linguagem, porque no fundo haverá um código gerado e tudo o que estava no *template* será texto. Se isso será bem-feito ou mal-feito, se será performático ou não, depende da qualidade da ferramenta usada.

Só para C# tem uma lista enorme. Alguns:

- [Razor](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (o que podemos chamar de oficial)
- [NHaml](https://github.com/NHaml/NHaml)
- [Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/)
- [NVelocity](https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail/tree/master/MR2/NVelocity)
- [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)
- [dotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/)
- [SharpTAL](https://github.com/lck/SharpTAL/)
- [HandlesBar.NET](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net)

Tem uma [lista de vários mecanismos para várias linguagens na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines).

Se olhou o ASP clássico, saiba que ele é considerado obsoleto há uns 15 anos. Depois disso veio o ASP.NET que também já pode ser considerado obsoleto, veio o ASP.NET MVC que é o mais usado atualmente e o [ASP.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) que é a última novidade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).