# Hospedagem híbrida com um único domínio é possível?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um cliente que tem um site em PHP, porém o desenvolvedor disse a ele que não tinha como fazer com banco de dados o sistema dele. Ele me pediu para fazer um sistema pra ele que tivesse como fazer um CRUD de cliente. Como ele tem contrato com a empresa que desenvolveu o site dele, não tem como me passar para administrar seu site. Ele utiliza o UolHost para hospedar seu site, sua plataforma está em Linux, mas vi que é possível mudar para Windows, no qual tem suporte a ASP.Net.

Consigo hospedar meu sistema em ASP.Net MVC, junto com o site dele feito em PHP e utilizar o mesmo domínio?

Comment: Provavelmente, mudando a hospedagem para Windows, deve funcionar sem problemas

Comment: Mas isso consigo em um único domínio?

Comment: Não sei se um único domínio seria bem a solução. Aconselharia utilizar um subdomínio para isso, como... **http://www.meusistema.dominiodosite.com**. Caso não seja o caso, o que você pode fazer é criar um caminho a frente, tipo **http://www.dominiodosite.com/meusistema**. Fora esses dois caminhos, você não consegue utilizando o mesmo domínio

Comment: Entendi. Valeu @Randrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Domínios não são vinculados à tecnologias, eles são apenas nomes que levam para um endereço IP. Então de cara já podemos concluir que não há problema.

Daí vem a pergunta sobre pode colocar duas tecnologias diferentes em um mesmo IP.

Um IP só pode estar em um dispositivo, então temos que saber se é possível ter as duas tecnologias no mesmo servidor. E a resposta é sim, pode tanto no Windows como no Linux.

O Windows suporta ASP.NET MVC e PHP rodando no mesmo site, não existe restrição técnica específica em usar ambas. Em geral as pessoas usam IIS para isso, mas nada impede de usar o Apache, embora sua hospedagem provavelmente não oferece isso.

O Linux também é possível rodar ambas. O ASP.NET MVC pode rodar através do [Mono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mono) ou do [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101), o que deve ser mais vantajoso hoje em dia (na verdade o Mono está sendo descontinuado como produto completo), mas não sei o quanto essas duas soluções funcionam na sua hospedagem. É possível que não funcionem.

Então roda, mas sua hospedagem pode não estar preparada. E mais, pode ser que exista conflitos entre as duas partes. Não pela tecnologia, mas como a aplicação foi desenvolvida. Essas coisas não temos como responder.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @bigown eu entrei em contato com o suporte do meu provedor de serviços de hospedagem, o rapaz do suporte me disse que daria pra utilizarmos subdomínios, com apontamento para o servidor que será hospedado o novo sistema. Só teria que ser feito a configuração no provedor, onde está hospedado atualmente o sistema do meu cliente.