# Preciso usar Visual Studio para programar em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

Quero aprender C# para se tornar uma das minhas linguagens principais, mas meu PC atual é meio defasado e acaba não executando bem o Visual Studio, mas com o Visual Studio Code é tudo bem, preciso do Visual Studio para programar em C#? até futuramente caso eu trabalhe com C# e .NET por exemplo, por que também vi que ele só está disponível no Windows, então qual seria a opção para usuários Linux que usam para projetos web em .net core por exemplo?

Comment: Em linux tem o IDE MonoDevelop que lhe permite desenvolver em C# e até utilizar interface gráfica GTK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não precisa do Visual Studio para nada, totalmente opcional. Na verdade, até mesmo o Code não é necessário, embora comece ter um pouco mais complicação. Um IDE ajuda bastante a ter produtividade, e quanto melhor for o IDE mais vantagens tem, por isso o VS *full* é apenas o mais interessante.

O resto da pergunta está muito confuso e não entendi, mas recomendo sempre as pessoas usarem o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: mas sempre que vejo como instalar um interpretador atualizado de c# ou o kit de desenvolvimento sempre é ensinando a baixar o visual studio, por gentileza você tem os componentes necessários para desenvolver em c# separadamente para eu instalar?

Comment: C# tem compilador e não interpretador. Se você tem o .NET na sua máquina não precisa de mais nada.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do Maniero, não é necessário realmente nenhuma IDE pra programar, com .NET Core por exemplo você pode programar com o bloco de notas (indo no exemplo mais "roots"), por exemplo:

```
dotnet new console
```

Abre o seu editor favorito:

```
Notepad Program.cs
```

Agora o código:

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("alterando código pelo Notepad");
        }
    }
}
```

Altere o `WriteLine` para algo de sua preferência.

```
dotnet run
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo um link com comandos do .Net Core CLI

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/?tabs=netcore2x

Agora uma opinião pessoal, e eu fiz em um PC antigo que eu tenho (Core i5/4gb/Hdd normal)
Instalei o Ubuntu Desktop, VS Code e o JetBrains Rider (pago mas gosto muito) rs.
Consegui me virar bem com os dois pra resolver coisa simples em projetos :)