# Nada menos `csc` funciona no Mono

Tags: c#, mono

O Mono é um conjunto de ferramentas de build. Antes e depois da versão 5.0, as ferramentas do Mono nunca funcionaram, exceto `csc`. Para clarificar, embora a versão não esteja relacionada ao problema, desde a versão [5.0](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#msbuild) o Mono integrou ferramentas do .NET, como `msbuild`, `nuget` etc. e obsoletando algumas (`xbuild` e talvez mais). O Mono também tem a ferramenta `mkbundle` que não funciona corretamente ainda hoje... Tudo desde o Windows 8(.1) ao Windows 10, à mim Mono nunca fez nada.

O `mkbundle` exporta aplicativos para executáveis, instaladores etc.. Agora funciona ao invés de dar erro na exportação, mas ele gera executáveis falhadas que printam `Error mapping file: No error` ao invés de `Olá, mundo!`.

`msbuild` falha com:

```
TurboCS.csproj(11,9): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" foi encerrado com o código 1.
```

Log completo:

```
Compilação de 28/10/2018 08:03:33 iniciada.
Projeto "D:\home\hydroper\Sources\CS\MyTools\$Withdrawn-TurboCS\TurboCS.csproj" no nó 1 (destinos padrão).
Build:
  C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /out:targetTurboCS.exe src\Entry.cs
D:\home\hydroper\Sources\CS\MyTools\$Withdrawn-TurboCS\TurboCS.csproj(11,9): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" foi encerrado com
 o código 1.
Projeto de compilação pronto "D:\home\hydroper\Sources\CS\MyTools\$Withdrawn-TurboCS\TurboCS.csproj" (destinos padrão)
-- FALHA.


FALHA da compilação.

"D:\home\hydroper\Sources\CS\MyTools\$Withdrawn-TurboCS\TurboCS.csproj" (destino padrão) (1) ->
(Build destino) ->
  D:\home\hydroper\Sources\CS\MyTools\$Withdrawn-TurboCS\TurboCS.csproj(11,9): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" foi encerrado c
om o código 1.

    0 Aviso(s)
    1 Erro(s)

Tempo Decorrido 00:00:00.98
```

E aqui meu CSProj, de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-msbuild-project-file-from-scratch?view=vs-2017):

```
<Project DefaultTargets='Build' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyName>TurboCS</AssemblyName>
        <OutputPath>target</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include='src/*.cs'/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name='Build'>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')"/>
        <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name='Clean'>
        <Delete Files="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).exe"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name='Rebuild' DependsOnTargets='Clean;Build'/>
</Project>
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 1):

Não, o Mono é o equivalente ao .NET criado originalmente para rodar em outras plataformas, e ter uma implementação alternativa com características diferentes. Hoje ele é menos necessário porque [o .NET tem praticamente tudo o que o Mono tinha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101).

A forma de construir aplicações no Mono é diferente do .NET, não há nenhum compromisso com a compatibilidade eles entre, são ferramentas diferentes que devem ser usados de forma diferente. Algumas coisas podem ser compatíveis. E claro, o código é compatível.

Importante leitura: [O .NET Framework está morto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

Comment: Sim, mas o Mono recentemente trouxe ferramentas do Visual Studio para dentro dele, como MSBuild, e marcou como obsoleto o XBuild, por exemplo. O Mono não tem nada à haver com o .NET, entendo, mas meu projeto não é .NET no caso. :/

Comment: O que não quer dizer que é tudo compatível, tem que entender as diferenças de como operar em cada um. Você perguntou o por quê.

Comment: MSBuild e todas as outras ferramentas que eu citei são ferramentas de build, e não de execução etc.. Porém, desde a versão [5.0.0](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/), o Mono trouxe ferramentas do .NET SDK para sí, e [obsoletou o XBuild mesmo](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#msbuild). O MSBuild no Mono é exatamente a mesma coisa documentada na Microsoft.