# Quando posso usar o .NET Framework 4.x e .NET Core no Windows, Linux e MacOS?

Tags: .net, cross-platform

Aplicação utilizando NET Framework 4.x pode ser executada em Windows, Linux e MacOS?

E aplicação utilizando .NET Core pode ser executada em Windows, Linux e MacOS?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

> Aplicação utilizando NET Framework 4.x pode ser executada em Windows, Linux e MacOS?

Não, só Windows, e ele [pode ser considerado obsoleto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

> E aplicação utilizando .NET Core pode ser executada em Windows, Linux e MacOS?

Depende de como for feita e o que utiliza, pode. Não pode usar nada específico de um dos OSs citados (tem muita coisa que só roda no Windows), a não ser que saiba como fazer para rodar diferente em cada um, tem que fazer pensando para rodar nos 3, se é o que deseja. Veja [O que é o .NET Core?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101).