# Um framework é baseado em uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: jquery, framework, terminologia

Sei que um *framework* é como uma aplicação para ser usado em aplicações, porém é correto dizer que um *framework* é baseado em certa linguagem? Exemplo:

> jQuery é um framework baseado em JavaScript

E qual a diferença de um *framework* para uma biblioteca? Existe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Um *framework* específico é feito para uma linguagem específica. Não sei se pode-se dizer "baseado em uma linguagem", depende da interpretação do que isto quer dizer, mas de uma maneira geral, este não é o termo correto.

Já existe [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) para a segunda parte da pergunta. E baseado nela podemos dizer que um *framework* é só uma biblioteca com uma filosofia específica. E uma biblioteca é apenas uma coleção de algoritmos e estruturas de dados escritos em uma linguagem para executar alguma tarefa. Em alguns casos essa tarefa é facilitar o uso da linguagem, como no caso do jQuery, mas nem sempre é o caso.

Note que de acordo com a [página oficial](http://jquery.com/) e entendimento da maioria dos programadores, jQuery é uma biblioteca e não um *framework*, portanto considero toda a afirmação incorreta.

> jQuery é uma biblioteca escrita em JavaScript (ou para JavaScript)

Aproveito a oportunidade para deixar claro que [jQuery também não é uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101), como muitos acham.

Comment: O link que você vinculou foi muito muito útil, consegui entender bem a diferença. Então o jQuery não é um framework pois você não trabalha em cima dele, você apenas "o utiliza", certo?

Comment: É isto. E de fato os criadores dele deixam isto claro.

Comment: Perfeito, e é até por causa disso que dizem para alguns programadores pararem com a "frescura" de querer que todo JavaScript seja "convertido" para jQuery, pois todo código jQuery é JavaScript. Obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Não é frescura, é o grande e correto ditado de não ter que reinventar a roda quando for fazer um carro. Se na sua aplicação, você for manipular com frequência elementos DOM, o jQuery é quase sempre a melhor opção, uma vez que ele tem uma ampla comunidade, uma documentação bem definida, boa performance e é rico em funcionalidades.

Comment: @LFZiron discordo radicalmente, mas não vou entrar em detalhes pra não provocar um discussão, afinal não é nosso objetivo aqui. Só não quero deixar as pessoas que estão lendo aqui achar que o que você diz é uma verdade absoluta. É só sua opinião, é um direito seu tê-la, mas há quem tem experiência diferente e não concorda com ela.

Comment: @bigown Sim, obrigado pela correção. Eu acho que por resumir, acabei dizendo de uma maneira muito genérica sobre o uso de uma biblioteca, algo que deve ser bem estudado, antes de iniciar o projeto. Me retificando, vou deixar a matéria abaixo que tem um ponto neutro sobre o assunto, para que possa esclarecer aos que lêem:

http://www.revista-programar.info/artigos/jquery-usar-ou-nao-usar/