# O que diferencia um microframework de um framework full stack?

Tags: framework, terminologia

Vejo por aí muitos termos como *framework fullstack* quando se trata de *frameworks* como o Codeigniter, Laravel, Symfony e CakePHP (do PHP) e Django (do Python).

Porém quando se fala de Silex e Lumen (do PHP), ou Flask (do Python), chamam-se `Microframeworks`.

O que não entendo as vezes quanto à utilização desses termos - já que aparentemente o que define o termo é a quantidade de recursos que esse *framework* tem - é que o Symfony em comparação com o Codeigniter tem uma multidão de recursos a mais.

Então, gostaria hoje de descobrir de uma vez por todas:

- Qual é o critério que determina que um *framework* é *full stack* ou não? O número de componentes? O número de problemas que ele resolve?
- Como determinar que um *framework* é, na verdade, um *microframework*?
- A performance também determina essas nomenclaturas?

Comment: Acho que os microframeworks geralmente surgem de uma modificação de um framework existente, tornando mais simples porém com menos recursos. Existe algum microframework que tenha surgido do 0? Sou bem leigo no assunto, mas ao meu ver pode ser apenas isso que difere.

Comment: @RaylanSoares existem frameworks que já nascem pequenos =)

Comment: Sim, @GuilhermeNascimento. E já nasceram **para serem pequenos**. Nesse caso, o usuário que o usa, pode fazê-lo para um pequeno projeto ou para fazer um **self-service de libraries**

Comment: Tem algum contexto? Estou pesquisando sobre isto e só estou lendo bobagens.

Comment: sim, mas independente de surgir pequeno ou não, quis dizer q os "micro" geralmente surgem de algum framework grande que ja estava em evidencia e foi vista a necessidade de uma adaptação para usa-lo em projetos menores que não usariam tantos recursos. Um framework que já nasce e permanece pequeno dificilmente dará motivos para o surgimento de uma versão simplificada.

Comment: @bigown tipo essas [bobagens](https://blog.appdynamics.com/php/php-microframework-vs-full-stack-framework/?)

Comment: @RaylanSoares sim escrevendo o "geralmente" agora muda o contexto da frase, então eu não contrariei nada do que você disse apenas complementei, existem os que surgem de modificações que você citou e os que já nascem pequenos, tendeu?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entenda **self-service** como instalar várias 3rdparty

Comment: Entendido, self-service soa engraçado, kkk

Comment: Entendi sim @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Eu so vejo micro framework quando é para restfull

Comment: "Full stack" é um framework desenvolvido por alguém que fica o dia inteiro no Stackoverlfow :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pesquisando sobre o assunto concluí que não existe uma definição clara e universalmente aceita. No momento, aparentemente, o termo é usado principalmente como marketing de acordo com o critério de quem decidiu usar o termo.

Parece ser intenção dizer que aquilo é mais que uma biblioteca sem o ser, e menos que um *framework*, o que seria, segundo o emissor na mensagem, algo ruim se o fosse.

Claro que há alguma razão técnica para dizer que aquele *framework* é micro, mas não há um critério claro, a escolha é arbitrária.

Se for importante para a computação haverá uma definição em breve. Se não aparecer, é porque não faz diferença.

Eu vi algumas definições que são muito contextuais. Algumas só se encaixam se o *framework* for web. Vi definição que conta o número de linhas do código dele (que coisa terrível a se fazer por várias razões).

Vi definição que indica que não precisa de um *setup* avançado, é copiar e usar. Até gosto deste, mas pode ser inadequado em algumas situações.

Embora não seja técnica e não possa ser usada como algo formal, [uma boa que encontrei foi no SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/141499/389). Diz algo assim:

> Este *framework* não é complexo como os demais concorrentes estabelecidos no mercado

Me parece ser o motivo mais próximo para ter esses nomes. E parece ser o caso quando o *framework* funciona mais como uma biblioteca, que só tem o estritamente necessário. Ou seja, escolheram um nome errado para a ferramenta.

Por ser menos complexo ele tenderá ser mais rápido, mas não necessariamente. Um *framework* que não tem um sistema de cache, por exemplo, ou algum outro mecanismo sofisticado para melhorar a performance, pode dar o resultado oposto.

No contexto da web realmente vi alguma coisa que fala em micro quando o *framework* é mais especializado e não tenta resolver todos os problemas de uma aplicação. Não sei se isso é tecnicamente correto, se não seria [o caso de ser só uma biblioteca que está sendo chamada de *micro framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101). De qualquer forma não gosto desta definição.

Aí o termo *full stack framework* pode até ser adequado. Em outros casos nem estamos falando de pilha de tecnologias. Me parece ser um termo que não é sinônimo de *framework* e não necessariamente oposto de *micro framework*.

Vejo várias bobagens sendo ditas sobre *framework*, API e coisas do tipo. Inclusive [classificações erradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58080/101). Ainda que muitas vezes não faça diferença real quando está usando. Lembrando que um *framework* é um estilo de vida.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bem por aí, pelo que vi aqui é definido como micro quando ele já começa pequeno e vamos adicionando recursos a ele conforme a necessidade, ja o fullstack vem "grande" por padrão e agente se vira se tiver q desabilitar algo que não precise rs

Comment: Odeio especialmente isto: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microframework

Comment: @bigown os microframework será tão *minimalistic* quanto a explicação do  Wikipedia?

Comment: Em geral, os microframeworks de web cuidam do *routing* e acrescentam uma ou outra feramenta básica. Não costumam seguir nenhum padrão MV*.