# Quais são e como se relacionam as tecnologias .NET para se desenvolver sistemas web?

Tags: .net, aplicação-web

Há muitos anos programei um pouco em ASP clássico e não acompanhei a evolução dos produtos.

O ASP clássico basicamente consistia em arquivos `.asp` com código cuja linguagem era uma variação do Basic, hospedados num servidor IIS, interpretados quando alguém acessava a sua respectiva URL, por exemplo `http://localhost/dir/arquivo.asp`.

Atualmente, ouço falar de ASP.NET, WebForms e outras tecnologias para desenvolver conteúdo para a web. Imagino que a plataforma .NET padrão (sem incluir terceiros) tenha um conjunto bem definido e delimitado de tecnologias para resolver os problemas comuns ou não tão comuns do desenvolvimento web.

- Quais são essas tecnologias?
- Quais são as características de cada uma em termos gerais? Qual problema cada uma resolve?
- Sem entrar em muitos detalhes, como elas se relacionam ou se integram? Quais delas são usadas em conjunto?
- Quais delas são complementares ou formas diferentes de resolver os mesmos problemas?

Comment: juro que esperava que esta pergunta viesse acompanhada por uma resposta sua. Mas se quiser acompanhar as novidades sobre o dotNET, você pode seguir o [Blog do Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/). por exemplo, integração do NodeJS com Visual Studio, uso de Grunt com ASP.NET MVC... sempre tem alguma novidade.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque não esta claro dentre os tópicos dito como escopo deste site se a pergunta se enquadra em algum deles conforme abaixo:
 - um problema específico de programação
 - um algorítmo de software
 - ferramentas comuns entre programadores
 - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
 - dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

ou possível ampla demais

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Embora existam diversas opções de *frameworks* no ecossistema do .NET, ao contrário do que ocorre em Java, quase ninguém os usa. A pessoa fica em cima do ASP.NET da Microsoft. Se isso é bom ou ruim fica para o julgamento de cada um. Mas lembre-se que a Microsoft fez muita coisa depois de ver os erros dos outros, então acertou mais facilmente. ASP.NET é um nome guarda-chuva para diversas tecnologias que habilitam o .NET trabalhar com web.

- ASP.NET inicialmente era só [WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é uma tecnologia que tenta reproduzir, na medida do possível, a forma de programar do Windows Forms, mantendo estado, artificialmente, entre as requisições das páginas.

  Essa tecnologia ajudou muita gente, foi boa e ainda serve para alguns propósitos. Mas ela não é muito adequada para a internet real que temos hoje. É uma tecnologia suportada, mas legada. Parou no 4.6 e só receberá atualizações esporádicas absolutamente necessárias (agora nem isso).
- Então foi criado o [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), que é completamente diferente do WebForms. Inicialmente ele tinha várias dependências com o ASP.NET clássico (WebForms). A versão atual ([ASP.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101)) não tem mais. E pode rodar facilmente nas três principais plataformas de servidores (alguém deve usar Mac como servidor :P). A versão clássica dele é considerada obsoleta em favor do ASP.NET Core.
- Poucas pessoas conhecem e menos ainda usam, mas também tem o [ASP.NET WebPages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Que é uma tecnologia mais simples que tem basicamente toda parte de *view* do MVC e algumas facilidades para o desenvolvimento geral, incluindo o principal do *model*, mas não exige o modelo de MVC. É ótimo para sites mais simples que não precisam dessa complicação toda, e muitos não precisam disso tudo, mas o pessoal só ouve falar no MVC e faz até coisa simples nele. O WebPages é parecido com o modo clássico de fazer sites no PHP.
- Outra tecnologia da família é o [ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que foi criado justamente para fazer o contrário, fornecer dados sem uma *view* definida. Ela é usada para criar APIs baseadas em tecnologias web. Aaaaah vá?! :) A versão atual (Core) foi totalmente integrada com o MVC e não existirá mais algo separado.
- Para prover notificações em tempo real aos clientes conectados foi criado o [ASP.NET SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Está incorporado ao Core. Existem clientes para várias tecnologias até mesmo não web.
- ASP.NET [Razor Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é um novo modelo que roda em cima do ASP.NET Core que diminui a burocracia colocando tudo em um arquivo só. É possível manter a *view* separada se desejar. É tudo organizado por página. Tem algumas poucas limitações em relação ao MVC. Há gente importante dentro da Microsoft que diz usar só ele agora. Para quase todos os projetos é o mais interessante. Em casos de extrema complexidade é que usa o MVC.
- [Minimal APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é uma tecnologia criada no mesmo espírito das Razor Pages, mas quando não tem páginas a fornecer. Quase sempre você só precisa dela para criar APIs web, é muito mais produtivo para a maioria dos cenários.
- [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101) foi criado para rodar nos navegadores, mas existe a opção de rodá-lo no servidor e renderizar páginas como se estivesse no navegador.

## Tecnologias "menores"

- Existem ainda algumas tecnologias auxiliares como o [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para prover autenticação e autorização.
- O ASP.NET Razor é o *engine* de *template* dessas tecnologias que precisam de uma forma de montar uma visualização.
- O [ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) são extensões para integrar todo o ASP.NET com tecnologias AJAX no cliente.
- O WebMatrix é usado para integrar tudo isto, mas com a versão nova do ASP.NET parece não fazer tanto sentido.
- Havia o ASP.NET Dynamic Data, mas até onde sei foi substituído pelo Entity Framework (o ORM do .NET) na maioria dos casos. Ele facilitava o acesso aos dados e montagem das páginas. A técnica de [*scaffolding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101) foi integrada ao ASP.NET. [O Core tem sua própria versão do EF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152679/101).

Alguns estão obsoletos agora.

Tem um [site que centraliza tudo isso](http://www.asp.net/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Eu fiz uma [pergunta sobre o novo ASP.NET 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101) que é a tecnologia que "sobreviverá" e englobará estas ferramentas modernas, atualmente ela se chama ASP.NET Core e na versão 2 está integrado ao [.NET Core padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101). Exceto pelo WebForms, que até pode ser integrado com o resto, todas devem trabalhar bastante juntas.

Agora surgiram serviços novos para integração com Azure (a nuvem da Microsoft).

Também vale destacar o [YARP](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é um proxy reverso, ou seja, você pode rodar suas aplicações ASP.NET diretamente nele sem precisar de um servidor HTTP clássico completo.

É tudo [código aberto](https://github.com/aspnet), com liberdade de verdade. Ali dá para ver que tem uma quantidade enorme de "pequenas" extensões úteis para o desenvolvimento web. Tem ferramentas e bibliotecas para *caching*, *logging*, acesso a diversos banco de dados e outras formas de acesso a dados de várias formas, servidor HTTP, controle de sessões, *proxy*, acesso por WebSockets, WebHooks, testes, configurações, localização, instrumentação, diagnósticos, proteções diversas, DI, Node, CORS, exemplos, etc.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Está bem completa. :)

Comment: Gostei da resposta...

Answer (score 0):

Olha o .Net está sendo um framework muito usado como o próprio Delphi incluiu o .NET também, acho que uma das maiores vantagens é o uso do .NET.
Com o ASP.NET você pode desenvolver sistemas web's baseados em "programação orientada a objetos" facilmente, você pode utilizar a padronização MVC que facilita o desenvolvimento ainda mais quando se tem uma equipe desenvolvendo junto.
Em ASP a depuração para encontrar erros é mais difícil, Já em ASP.NET A depuração por busca de erros são bem mais simples pois Erros com páginas são geradas como erros do Compilador ou seja há uma boa chance de que a maioria dos erros serão encontrados em tempo de compilação em vez do tempo de execução.
A maioria dos servidores de hospedagem hoje utilizam o asp.net ao invés de apenas o asp. O desempenho das páginas em asp.net são bem melhores porque Como todos os componentes em ASP.NET são conjuntos, não há degradação de desempenho por meio de código do lado do servidor, Já em ASP os scripts são interpretados na hora em tempo real tendo assim um impacto no desempenho. tô querendo dizer que em termo de velocidade,processamento,desenvolvimento,compilação,busca por erros, e popular o ASP.NET está em melhor lugar, porque ele é a atualização do ASP para uma camada melhor sendo assim as necessidades e melhorias que faltavam no ASP foram aplicadas no ASP.NET. Espero que eu tenha ajudado.

Comment: Olá. Interessante sua resposta, mas ela focou num ponto que não responde diretamente à pergunta. Por exemplo, eu não perguntei sobre as vantagens do .net sobre o ASP clássico, aquilo foi apenas para contextualizar a pergunta. O que eu queria saber é sobre quais as tecnologias disponíveis hoje sob o guarda-chuva .net para desenvolvimento web. Tipo, se eu quiser começar um projeto web amanhã, quais opções eu tenho?