# Entity Framework Core x Entity Framework 7

Tags: entity-framework, orm

Quais as principais diferenças entre Entity Framework Core e Entity Framework 7? Existem cenários em que um é mais indicados que o outro.

É tanta versão e tanta mudança de nome que estou perdido.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## EF7

Já que o EF 7 não existe, tem zero diferenças. O EF 7 é EF Core. Por um lampejo raro a Microsoft nomeou o produto adequadamente (por um tempo o nome não oficial era EF 7). Como a nova versão é um produto novo escrito do zero e não garante compatibilidade com a versão anterior não tinha porque usar o mesmo nome, melhor começar de novo.

## EF6

Se a comparação é com o EF 6, a última criada para o .NET padrão, aí o melhor é olhar a [documentação oficial sobre comparação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e o documento para decidir [se o EF Core é adequado para você](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Em resumo:

O EF 6 é um produto maduro e completo que continuará sendo suportado. Mas não terá grandes evoluções. O futuro é o Core. Mas de todas tecnologias do .NET Core talvez essa seja a mais atrasada na data da escrita desta resposta (4 anos depois e isso ainda é verdade).

O EF Core é muito mais leve em todos os sentidos, é bastante extensível e roda em diversas plataformas. O EF 6 tem uma carga legada grande, inclusive de coisas equivocadas, além de ser centrado no Windows. Outro ponto interessante é que ele abraça outras fontes de dados de forma oficial (memória, NoSQL, serviços de dados, etc.), não só bancos de dados SQL de vários fornecedores (todos os principais do mercado, de SQLite ao Oracle).

A API geral para uso de ambos é a mesma, pelo menos nos principais recursos. O que continua existindo no Core deve ser quase todo compatível. Mas muita coisa existente no EF 6 não existirá no Core, nunca (não estou falando do que ainda não foi desenvolvido por falta de tempo). Algumas funcionalidades poderão ser recriadas por terceiros, mas não terão suporte oficial.

No geral a recomendação é usá-lo em aplicações novas e não portar o que já existe, a não ser que precise de um reestruturação do que existe. Mas se for usar o .NET Core, o EF Core é a única opção (isso não é mais verdade), entre essas duas. Por outro lado ele funciona com o ASP.NET Core, Xamarin e UWP.

## Diferenças

Não vou fazer uma lista de recursos que não estão disponíveis no EF Core já que ela ficará defasada rapidamente, mas ele tem novidades interessantes:

- finalmente há um bom controle para o envio de *statements* em lote;
- melhorias no uso de SQL bruta;
- separação do que deve ser realizado no cliente e o que deve ir para o servidor;
- facilidades para recuperar o modelo do banco de dados (não existe mais *database first*);
- [propriedades sombreadas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397);
- liberdade para usar [chaves alternativas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) incluindo geração em cliente.

A recomendação seria perguntar sobre itens específicos que sejam necessários em algum cenário, ou consultar a documentação.

Ressalto a ideia de que alguns recursos do EF 6 nunca serão suportados no EF Core, mas por uma boa razão, eles eram "errados". Outros você apenas terá que esperar um pouco.

Desde a versão original desta resposta muita coisa mudou, o EF6 agora roda no .NET Core (no Windows) e muita coisa nova foi colocada no EF Core, não considere mais como uma resposta atualizada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 9):

## Nenhuma

[O Entity Framework 7 foi rebatizado como Entity Framework Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144). O objetivo é não causar uma impressão de que o Entity Framework 6 pode ser atualizado para o Core (como poderia sugerir o algarismo 7 como sequência natural da versão 6).

Devido a uma série de decisões de design de *framework*, a mudança segue alinhada à ideia de [não fazer o ASP.NET Core ser compatível com o ASP.NET MVC5 e com o ASP.NET Web API](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx), o que poderia trazer muitos problemas futuros.

Note que o ASP.NET Identity também segue o mesmo princípio, justamente por causa do acoplamento dele com o Entity Framework Core.

Comment: O que me deixou mais confuso é que tem pacotes `Nuget` tanto para `EF7` quanto para `Core`, já que são um só deveriam deixar tudo num só lugar.

Comment: Ah, sim, mas esses pacotes "7" nunca sairão do pré-lançamento. Só são mantidos por questões históricas.