# LINQ to Entities x Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Qual a diferença entre LINQ to Entities x Lambda Expression?

Ainda se utiliza LINQ to Entities no Entity Framework ou existe algo mais novo?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2):

Não dá para comparar as duas coisas já que elas fazem coisas completamente diferentes.

A única relação entre elas é que LINQ em geral, incluindo Entities, usa *lambda* como mecanismo.

Isto já foi respondido em diversas perguntas:

- [Qual a diferença entre "lambda" e LINQ? Como diferenciá-los em uma sentença?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79894/101)
- [Diferenças entre forma declarativa e imperativa do LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)
- [Quais as diferenças entre local functions, delegates e expressões lambdas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181290/101)
- [Nomenclatura ou linguajar no lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22265/101)

Toda vez que está usando LINQ com as entidades do EF está usando [LINQ to Entities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Provavelmente sempre será assim. Só deixa de usá-lo se não usar LINQ no EF, o que é praticamente impossível, ou deixar de usar as entidades, que na prática deixa de usar o EF. O que quase não se usa mais é o LINQ to SQL.

Não existe nada mais novo. O que existe é uma versão nova do EF, o [EF Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152679/101).